# What is the difference between types String and string?

Tags: typescript

Does anyone know the difference between `String` and `string` in TypeScript? Am I correct in assuming that they ought to be the same?

```
var a: String = "test";
var b: string = "another test";
a = b;
b = a; // this gives a compiler error!
```

Current version of the compiler says:

```
Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
     Prefer using 'string' when possible.
```

Is that a bug?

Comment: I think "is that a bug" is really a good philosophical question. It's probably "intended" to be so but it creates confusion and compile errors. I think it's at least a problem.

Comment: Simple distinction would be typeof these [String and string ] is different so one isn't assignable to another. typeof(String) is Object that's why we can use new String('...')  while typeof(string)  not object.

Answer (score 466, accepted):

Here is an example that shows the differences, which will help with the explanation.

```
var s1 = new String("Avoid newing things where possible");
var s2 = "A string, in TypeScript of type 'string'";
var s3: string;
```

`String` is the JavaScript String type, which you *could* use to create new strings. Nobody does this as in JavaScript the literals are considered better, so `s2` in the example above creates a new string without the use of the `new` keyword and without explicitly using the `String` object.

`string` is the TypeScript string type, which you can use to type variables, parameters and return values.

Additional notes...

Currently (Feb 2013) Both `s1` and `s2` are valid JavaScript. `s3` is valid TypeScript.

Use of `String`. You probably never need to use it, string literals are universally accepted as being the correct way to initialise a string. In JavaScript, it is also considered better to use object literals and array literals too:

```
var arr = []; // not var arr = new Array();
var obj = {}; // not var obj = new Object();
```

If you really had a penchant for the string, you could use it in TypeScript in one of two ways...

```
var str: String = new String("Hello world"); // Uses the JavaScript String object
var str: string = String("Hello World"); // Uses the TypeScript string type
```

Comment: Thanx for clearing that out. So it's safe to use the primitve type string to avoid possible type conversion problems when using other libs that work with string values (based on the idea that nobody actually uses String (?)). Shouldnt assignments between string and String and viceversa be treated equally though?

Comment: It is actually safe to use either as the TypeScript types are stripped out to give you 100% compatible JavaScript (in either ES3 or ES5 flavours, and in version 1 ES6 flavour). I would recommend using the `string` type and a literal initialisation: `var s: string = "My String";`.

Comment: for the record, thanks to type-inference, `var s: string = "My String"` is identical to `var s = "My String"` ... also, no matter how many times I read this respond, I'm still not grasping the purpose of the `string` type in TypeScript, since, at the end of the day, `('My String')['constructor'] === String`...

Comment: You would normally add the annotation if you weren't initialising the variable with a value.

Comment: I've added an answer to clarify that "foo" vs new String("foo") isn't a new distinction introduced by TypeScript - I don't think it's helpful to call one a JS type and the other a TS type.

Comment: I feel something important is missing here.  When you're reading json data string values in json can be null.  You'd use the uppercase String variant rather than the primitive for your models so they can also be null, no?

Answer (score 90):

The two types are distinct in JavaScript as well as TypeScript - TypeScript just gives us syntax to annotate and check types as we go along.

`String` refers to an object instance that has `String.prototype` in its prototype chain.  You can get such an instance in various ways e.g. `new String('foo')` and `Object('foo')`.  You can test for an instance of the `String` type with the `instanceof` operator, e.g. `myString instanceof String`.

`string` is one of JavaScript's primitive types, and `string` values are primarily created with literals e.g. `'foo'` and `"bar"`, and as the result type of various functions and operators.  You can test for `string` type using `typeof myString === 'string'`.

The vast majority of the time, `string` is the type you should be using - almost all API interfaces that take or return strings will use it.  All JS primitive types will be wrapped ([boxed](http://www.jisaacks.com/javascript-boxing/)) with their corresponding object types when using them as objects, e.g. accessing properties or calling methods.  Since `String` is currently declared as an interface rather than a class in [TypeScript's core library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.7.5/src/lib/core.d.ts#L263), structural typing means that `string` is considered a subtype of `String` which is why your first line passes compilation type checks.

Answer (score 54):

For quick readers:

> **Don’t ever use the *types* `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Symbol`, or `Object`.** These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code. (emphasis mine)

Source:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Answer (score 16):

In JavaScript strings can be either string primitive type or string objects. The following code shows the distinction:

```
var a: string = 'test'; // string literal
var b: String = new String('another test'); // string wrapper object

console.log(typeof a); // string
console.log(typeof b); // object
```

Your error:

> Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.   'string' is a
>   primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
>        Prefer using 'string' when possible.

Is thrown by the TS compiler because you tried to assign the type `string` to a string object type (created via `new` keyword). The compiler is telling you that you should use the type `string` only for strings primitive types and you can't use this type to describe string object types.

Answer (score 7):

## TypeScript: `String` vs `string`

> Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>
> 'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
>
> Prefer using 'string' when possible.

### demo

> String Object

```
// error
class SVGStorageUtils {
  store: object;
  constructor(store: object) {
    this.store = store;
  }
  setData(key: String = ``, data: object) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  getData(key: String = ``) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
  }
}
```

> string primitive

```
// ok
class SVGStorageUtils {
  store: object;
  constructor(store: object) {
    this.store = store;
  }
  setData(key: string = ``, data: object) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  getData(key: string = ``) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Simple answer:

- `string` => is a type. e.g. console.log(typeof 'foo') // string
- `String` => is an object with some methods to create and manipulate strings.

Answer (score 3):

1. string ==> primitive data type.
2. String ==> non-primitive. it's an object and has access to String class methods and properties

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has 7 primitive types `strings, numbers, booleans, null, undefined, symbol, and bigint`, The first five have been around since the beginning, The symbol primitive was added in ES2015 and bigint is in the process of being finalized.

Primitives are distinguished from objects by being immutable and not having methods. You might object that strings do have methods

```
 console.log('primitive'.charAt(3)) // output is "m"
```

Well, While a string primitive does not have methods, JavaScript also defines a String object type that does. JavaScript **freely converts** between these types. When you access a method like charAt on a string primitive, JavaScript wraps it in a String object, calls the method, and then throws the object away.

TypeScript models this distinction by having distinct types for the primitives and their object wrappers:

- string and String
- number and Number
- boolean and Boolean
- symbol and Symbol
- bigint and BigInt

usually things will work if you use `String` instead of `string`, except that in some cases, the compiler will raise an error
[image]

As you can see, `string` is assignable to `String`, **but** `String` **is not assignable to** `string`.

Follow the advice in the error message and stick with string. All the type declarations that ship with TypeScript use it, as do the typings for almost all other libraries.

Comment: for more similar recipes and advices, I would recommend reading https://effectivetypescript.com/

Answer (score 2):

*Based on my personal reference*

- `string` is a type in JavaScript.
- `String`; in JavaScript, all the strings are represented as an instance of `String class`. [Read this short article to learn a bit more about the String class](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/working-with-string-class-properties-using-javascript1#:%7E:text=A%20string%20is%20a%20sequence,member%20of%20the%20global%20objects.)

**Prefer the `string` over the `String`**

Answer (score 2):

This error message is indicating that you are trying to assign a value of type String to a variable or parameter with type string. In TypeScript, string is a primitive type that represents a sequence of characters, while String is a wrapper object that provides additional methods for working with strings.

The error message is suggesting that you should use the string type instead of String whenever possible, as the string type is more efficient and has fewer associated overhead costs. This is because String is an object, and objects in JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) are stored on the heap and require additional memory allocation when they are created. In contrast, string values are stored directly on the stack, which makes them more efficient to use.

To fix this error, you will need to ensure that you are using the string type instead of String wherever it is expected. You can do this by simply replacing String with string in your code. For example, if you have a variable with type String, you could change it to have type string like this:

```
let myString: String = "hello, world!"; // Incorrect
let myString: string = "hello, world!"; // Correct
```

It is also worth noting that, in general, you should prefer using string over String whenever possible, as it is more efficient and easier to work with.