# String is not string

Tags: typescript

Thinking of string as String works. However thinking of String as string is broken:

```
var str1:String = "asdf"; 
var str2:String = new String("asdf");
var str3:string = "asdf";
var str4:string = new String("asdf"); // Error
```

[Try It](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20str1%3aString%20=%20%22asdf%22;%20%0Avar%20str2%3aString%20=%20new%20String%28%22asdf%22%29;%0Avar%20str3%3astring%20=%20%22asdf%22;%0Avar%20str4%3astring%20=%20new%20String%28%22asdf%22%29;%20//%20Error%20)

Also:

```
var interfaceBased:String = "123";
var keywordBased:string ="123";
interfaceBased=keywordBased;
keywordBased=interfaceBased; // Error
```

[Try It](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20interfaceBased%3aString%20=%20%22123%22;%0Avar%20keywordBased%3astring%20=%22123%22;%0AinterfaceBased=keywordBased;%0AkeywordBased=interfaceBased;%20//%20Error%20%20%0A)

Is this a known compiler bug?

Comment: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/810

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typescript: difference between String and string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` is a Javascript type while `string` is a Typescript type. I don't think it's a bug so much as a quirk. Mainly because there's absolutely no reason to use the `String()` constructor over string literals.

See here: [Typescript: difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)

Answer (score 4):

This stems from a JavaScript quirk: there are primitive strings and object strings. A primitive string is, well, your everyday string:

```
typeof "Hi! I'm a string!"  // => "string"
```

However, any time you use `new`, you create an object rather than a primitive:

```
typeof new String("Hi! I'm a string!")  // => "object"
```

JavaScript also implicitly creates an object string out of a primitive string whenever you access a property, since only objects can have properties:

```
var s = "Hi! I'm a string!";
s.property = 6;  // s implicitly coerced to object string, property added
console.log(s.property);  // => undefined
// property was added to the object string, but then the object string was
// discarded as s still contained the primitive string. then s was coerced again
// and the property was missing as it was only added to an object whose reference
// was immediately dropped.
```

You almost never want an object string because of its quirks (e.g., an empty object string is truthy), so rather than using `new String`, you almost always want `String` instead. `String` without `new` can even convert an object string back into a primitive string:

```
typeof String(new String("Hi! I'm a string!"))  // => "string"
```

I don't know if this issue surfaces in TypeScript, but the primitive/object distinction and especially the truthiness issue becomes very odd with `Boolean`. For example:

```
var condition = new Boolean(false);
if(condition) {  // always true; objects are always truthy
    alert("The world is ending!");
}
```

**In short, it's because of the object/primitive distinction. You almost always want primitives where you have the option.**