# TypeScript in Webstorm: string array indexOf Object error

Tags: typescript

Here are two variables:

```
var stringA : string = "a";
var stringAr : string[] = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
```

I get an error if I try to do the following:

```
stringAr.indexOf(stringA);
```

with the following error (red line under 'stringA'):

`Argument type String is not assignable to parameter Object`

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this? I'm currently using Webstorm 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected in Visual Studio and in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/):

```
var stringA : string = "a";
var stringAr : string[] = [ "a", "b", "c" ];

var idx:number = stringAr.indexOf(stringA);

console.log("Index: " + idx);  // Logs "Index: 0"
```

Have you got the [latest version of TS](http://typescript.codeplex.com/) (0.8.3 at time of writing) and are you sure you haven't got a capitalised `String` in there instead of `string` somewhere (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)) ?

Comment: You're right, I've just checked the code in the playground and it seems fine. It also seems to compile fine to Javascript and my current app works without errors. I'm guessing this may just be an error with WebStorm so I've just filed an error report. Thanks for the check!