# Why does "this" in String.prototype return an object?

Tags: javascript

This might be a duplicate, dumb or off-topic but the actual question is the question's title.

I wanted to make something simple as this:

```
String.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(this);
  return this;
}
```

And when invoked (in Firebug for instance), the result is:

```
String { 0="t",  1="e",  2="s",  more...}
```

For: `"test".log()` and of course the same thing is returned.

Now, the workaround for this was either a `""` concatenation on any side or `this.toString()`.

Why is `this` an object in the `String.prototype` scope and the `instanceof` is both of `Object` and `String`?

Comment: This happens with all primitive types, not just strings. Only functions aren’t converted to an object.

Comment: " JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: What's the `instanceof` `null` ?

Comment: @Duvdevan are you trying in an area where ES6 syntax is supported? I have already answered that in ES6 we have something called `String Exotic Object` which indexes string automatically. Not sure though, but this is my best guess. I tried in node compiler where ES6 is not supported and got `[String: 'test']`. Would ask you to check it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a string you actually create an instance (object) of the string function.

Type `String` in the chrome console.

```
console.log(String);
Output : function String()
```

If you create a string

```
var x = new String("aaa");
```

`x` is actually an instance of the `String` function

```
console.log(x instanceof String); // true
```

**Why x is instance of Object?**

In JavaScript every object has a `__proto__` link.

```
x.__proto__ == String.prototype;
```

It means `x`'s proto link points to the `String` prototype.

Now `String.prototype` has a `__proto__` too.

```
String.prototype.__proto__ == Object.prototype;
```

`instanceof` operator first search for `__proto__` link and follows it.

`x`'s proto link points to `String`'s prototype and `String`'s prototype points to `Object` prototype.

Hence `x` is an instance of `Object` too.

Comment: So does `var x = "test";` create an object?

Comment: I understand that actaully any object is an instance of `Object`, but the `typeof null` is an `"object"` and it's not an `null instanceof Object === true`. Why is that so?

Comment: Yah these typeof and instance are different .instanceof works on proto chaning .
null doesnot have proto link

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but found something that might answer the question:

#### [String(Value)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-objects)

> When `String` is called with argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> If no arguments were passed to this function invocation, let s be "".
>
> Else,
>
> If NewTarget is undefined and Type(value) is Symbol, return SymbolDescriptiveString(value).
>
> Let s be ToString(value).
>
> ReturnIfAbrupt(s).
>
> If NewTarget is undefined, return s.
>
> Return StringCreate(s, GetPrototypeFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%StringPrototype%")).
>
> The length property of the String function is 1.

Now [StringCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-stringcreate) returns a [String exotic object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-exotic-objects).

According to it,

> A String object is an exotic object that encapsulates a String value and exposes virtual integer indexed data properties corresponding to the individual code unit elements of the String value.
>
> Exotic String objects always have a data property named "length" whose value is the number of code unit elements in the encapsulated String value. Both the code unit data properties and the "length" property are non-writable and non-configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can find, pertaining directly to this question, is answered in the ECMAScript specification on which JavaScript is based.

Here's the specification for String...
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4

An excerpt:

> The String type is the set of all finite ordered sequences of zero or
>   more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”). The String type is
>   generally used to represent textual data in a running ECMAScript
>   program, in which case each element in the String is treated as a code
>   unit value (see Clause 6). Each element is regarded as occupying a
>   position within the sequence. These positions are indexed with
>   nonnegative integers. The first element (if any) is at position 0, the
>   next element (if any) at position 1, and so on. The length of a String
>   is the number of elements (i.e., 16-bit values) within it. The empty
>   String has length zero and therefore contains no elements.

Especially this part:

> Each element is regarded as occupying a position within the sequence.
>   These positions are indexed with nonnegative integers.

This explains why the actual truer storage of the String being revealed is array-like in nature. The characters are INDEXED sequentially as is mandated within the specification.

Comment: This doesn't pertain to the question at all.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused about the difference between the literal and the class. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 0):

The primitive string "test" is [boxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) into an object of type `String` before the `log` function is invoked.

Comment: The question is _why_.

Comment: @Xufox This is briefly mentioned in the Wikipedia entry: "for reasons such as runtime efficiency and syntax or semantic issues".