# Different output from prototype function and normal function

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying figure out what's the difference between prototype function and normal function

here's my example:
Task is to create function in 'OOP way' that will check if string is Uppercased.

Why im getting different output?

```js
String.prototype.isUpperCase = function () {
    return this === this.toUpperCase();
}

function check(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}

let str = 'C';


console.log(str.isUpperCase())
console.log(check(str))
```

Comment: @deceze they don't, `str.isUpperCase()` is false. Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206565/why-does-this-in-string-prototype-return-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.toString()` will do the trick for you.

`""` and `new String("")` are different. The `this` inside the prototype function is an instance of the `String` class.

```js
String.prototype.isUpperCase = function () {
    return this.toString() === this.toUpperCase();
}

function check(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}

let str = 'C';


console.log(str.isUpperCase())
console.log(check(str))
```