# typescript - string literal type to type string

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, typeliteral

I have a method with string literal type guard

```
type Status = 'new' | 'update' | 'close';

itemRequest(status: Status) { 
    itemService.subscribeToChanges(status) //third party library method
}
```

Difficulty I have is this third party method accepts string not my custom string type `Status`

```
subscribeToChanges(status: string)
```

How can I make my string literals are actually types of string and when I pass to third party method. It understand it's actually a string?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You're getting compilation error when pass the `status`? What error? I'm unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to cast your value of the `Status` to a string like this:

```
type Status = 'new' | 'update' | 'close';

itemRequest(status: Status) { 
    itemService.subscribeToChanges(status as string)
}
```

Do *not* use `String(status)`. This constructs a new `string` object from `status` and is a wasteful allocation. The cast will be erased at runtime and just corrects TypeScript's knowledge of the type of the `status` variable. Remember that any type checking TypeScript does is done at compile time and has no runtime cost nor presence.

This code will be compiled to the following:

```
itemRequest(status) {
  itemService.subscribeToChanges(status)
}
```

I am however confused as to why this is happening. Your type alias are all of type `string` so casting from `Status` to `string` should be a upcast (i.e, permissible under any reasonable type checker). The other way around would be the main issue. Indeed, your original code works just fine on it's own.

Comment: it should be cast as a lowercase `string`, not uppercase `String`. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 0):

Can you make Status an enum? Then you can use `Status[status]` which will be the string value you expect.
i.e.

```
enum Status { new, update, close }

itemRequest(status: Status) { 
    itemService.subscribeToChanges(Status[status]) //third party library method
}
```

Comment: I think if you don't explicitly give string *values* to your Enum, at runtime the values will be numbers.

See the 2nd paragraph in [the Handbook's page on Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#handbook-content)

Answer (score 0):

It should work. In JavaScript it is a normal string. Check out this sample or visit it [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20let%20itemService%3A%20%7B%20subscribeToChanges%3A%20(status%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20any%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Status%20%3D%20%27new%27%20%7C%20%27update%27%20%7C%20%27close%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20itemRequest(status%3A%20Status)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20itemService.subscribeToChanges(status)%20%2F%2Fthird%20party%20library%20method%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20myStatus%3A%20Status%20%3D%20%27update%27%3B%0D%0AitemRequest(myStatus)%3B).

```
// TypeScript 
type Status = 'new' | 'update' | 'close';

function itemRequest(status: Status) { 
    itemService.subscribeToChanges(status) //third party library method
}
let myStatus: Status = 'update';
itemRequest(myStatus);

// Compiled JavaScript
function itemRequest(status) {
    itemService.subscribeToChanges(status); //third party library method
}
var myStatus = 'update';
itemRequest(myStatus);
```