# Why am I getting "Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type" error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a large amount of JavaScript code that uses a number of associative arrays that allow very fast access to objects. So I tried to port this code and failed. Clearly, I don't understand TypeScript well enough yet.

I have hunted for an answer to this question and found suggestions to create an interface etc., but this seems a bit off the track.

So I tried the seemingly obvious:

```
     class Foo {
       allObjects: MyObject[];
        constructor() {
         this.allObjects = [];
       }
    }
```

where `MyObject` - simplified:

```
     class MyObject {
         _id: String;
         public getId(): String {
            return this._id;
         }
     }
```

And I would believe that:

```
     myObjectInstance: MyObject;
     fooInstance.allObjects[myObjectInstance.getId()] = myObjectInstance;
```

That would be fine... Yet I see the lovely `TS2342 error (An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', or 'any')` which makes no sense to me since `getId()` is a `string`.  It doesn't seem like this should be that hard. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: difference between String and string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: `String` is different from `string`, that is, `_id: string;` should work. You need `String` only when you have to use `new` with it, that is, almost never.

Comment: By the way, the term "associative array" is used in neither JavaScript nor TypeScript.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use lowercase `string` for the type of `MyObject._id`

Comment: Same goes for lowercase `number` in my case.

Comment: When do we use lowercase vs capital?

Comment: Answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string