# Angular 5 Sort by date, text, numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

I have implemented reusable sorting function,sorting by number and text are working fine,But it fails for sort by date.

```
orderBy(array: Array<any>, fieldName: string, direction: string) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    let objectA: number|string = '';
    let objectB: number|string = '';
    [objectA, objectB] = [a[fieldName], b[fieldName]];
    let valueA = isNaN(+objectA) ? objectA.toString().toUpperCase() : +objectA;
    let valueB = isNaN(+objectB) ? objectB.toString().toUpperCase() : +objectB;
    return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (direction == 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
  });
}
```

how to sort by date, text numbers and special char.

Comment: I would suggest use moment.js

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
orderBy(array: Array<any>, fieldName: string, direction: string) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    let objectA: number|string|Date = '';
    let objectB: number|string|Date = '';
    [objectA, objectB] = [a[fieldName], b[fieldName]];

    // I assume that objectA and objectB are of the same type
    return typeof objectA === 'string' ? objectA.localeCompare(objectB) : objectA - objectB;
  });
}
```

if `Date` type is not recognized, you may need to add `es6` entry to your `compilerOptions`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485073/typescript-date-type#45485198) for more details

**UPDATE**

If all your values to be sorted are strings try this:

```
orderBy(array: Array<any>, fieldName: string, direction: string) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    let objectA: number|string|Date = '';
    let objectB: number|string|Date = '';
    // map function here will convert '15/12/2018' into '2018/12/15'
    // so we can compare values as strings, numbers and strings
    // will remain unchanged
    [objectA, objectB] = [a[fieldName], b[fieldName]].map(i => i.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

    return isNaN(+objectA) ? objectA.localeCompare(objectB) : +objectA - +objectB;
  });
}
```

Comment: "objectA.localeCompare(objectB) : objectA - objectB;" gives an error.. not working

Comment: if objectA and objectB are strings, this should work. try `'aaa'.localeCompare('ddd')` in debugger console of your browser. Maybe objectA or objectB are not strings in your case? But it should yield an error because of typescript `Date` type. please create Plunker or stackblitz with your array and code and I will try to help. see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: which error gives you "objectA.localeCompare(objectB) : objectA - objectB;"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be best since the ***localCompare function*** **returns positive for after and negatives for before and 0 for equals** (in this example I'm comparing .name wich is an atribute of objects **a** and **b** that are in this.array)

```
this.array.sort((a, b) => { 
 return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using type script than you can do like this , havent tried but you can tryout

```
public orderby(fieldName : string)
{
    switch (typeof obj[fieldName].constructor.name) {           
            case "String":
                array.sort();
            case "Number":
                  array.sort(function(a,b){
                       return a-b);
                 });
            case "Date"://you can check type and add accordingly 
            //as suggested by @Andriy  its going to be object 
                 array.sort(function(a,b){
                       return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
                 });
            default:
                throw new Error("Type of T is not a valid return type!");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error("Key '" + key + "' does not exist!");
    }
}
```

---

for date sorting i do like this , converting values in date and get value for minus operation which returns zero, plus or negative vlaue

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Comment: this will sort only date column. I need text and numbers too. dynamic columns and values.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan - so you need generic method ??

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan - so you are using typescript ??

Comment: yeah. calling this function as service

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan - you can tryout solution may work for you

Comment: `typeof new Date()` is `object`, not `date`

Comment: @Andriy - got your point , havent tried this but just for suggestion i gave option, but updated my answer as you suggested

Comment: there is no JS type `date` (https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types). But you can always check constructor's name: `switch (obj[fieldName].constructor.name)`, which should return `Number`, `String` or `Date`

Comment: @Pranay Not working. (typeof obj[fieldName].constructor.name) gives string for all columns even number, date column in console.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan - if it gives string value for all than you should convert type accordingly ...like for number you can try `parseint` and string to date by doing parsing of string

Comment: your date field is actually a string, not a date object, all your fields are strings, according to your comment. You should consider using converting to Date or Number prior to sorting,

Comment: `typeof obj[fieldName].constructor.name` will always return 'string', because constructor's name's type is a string. It should be just `switch (obj[fieldName].constructor.name)`