# How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, algebraic-data-types

If I have a collection of types that looks a bit like this:

```
type ValidValues = string | number | null
type ValidTypes = "text" | "time" | "unknown"

type Decorated = {
  name?: string | null
  type?: ValidTypes
  value?: ValidValues
  title: string
  start: number
}

type Injected = {
  extras: object
}

// overriding the types from Decorated
type Text = Decorated & Injected & {
  name: string
  type: "text"
  value: string
}
```

My actual code has more going on, but this shows the core idea. I don't want to have to trust myself to get the relationships between types just right. I want tooling to show me what the type definition for `Text` "evaluates" to, after all the type algebra.

So for the above example, I'm hoping the fields specified in `Text` will override the previous declarations made in the `Decorated` type, and the output of a hypothetical tooltip should show me something like this:

```
{
  name: string
  type: "text"
  value: string
  title: string
  start: number
  extras: object
}
```

Is there any convenient way to get this information?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94679

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The quick info for a type displayed with [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) often leaves something to be desired; you generally get a single representation for any given type, which may turn out to be too terse or even too verbose for your purposes.  There are a few suggestions to make it more flexible (e.g., [microsoft/TypeScript#25784](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25784) and [microsoft/TypeScript#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508)) so that users could expand/collapse type definitions in their IDEs.  But I don't know if they will get acted on in the near or even far future, so let's not wait around for that.

---

Here is a type alias I sometimes use to try to expand a type in the way you're talking about:

```
// expands object types one level deep
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

// expands object types recursively
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;
```

Those use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to "copy" a type `T` into a new type variable `O` and then an identity-like [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which iterates through the copied type's properties.

The conditional type inference is conceptually a no-op, but it's used to [distribute union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and to force the compiler to evaluate the "true" branch of the conditional (if you redefine `Expand<T>` without it, sometimes the compiler will just *output* the mapped type `{[K in keyof RelevantType]: RelevantType[K]}`, which is not what you want to see).

The difference between `Expand` and `ExpandRecursively` is whether it should just spit out the property types as-is (`Expand`), or if it should *expand* the property types (`ExpandRecursively`).  It helps in the recursive case not to try to drill down into primitive types, so that's why `T extends object` condition is included.

---

Okay, let's see what happens when we use it on your type.  We don't need `ExpandRecursively` in your case, but we *could* use it... it gives the same result:

```
type ExpandedText = Expand<Text>;
```

which, when we hover over it in the IDE (The TypeScript Playground and VSCode anyway), is displayed as:

```
/* type ExpandedText = {
  name: string;
  type: "text";
  value: string;
  title: string;
  start: number;
  extras: object;
 } */
```

as you wanted.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAsAKCUgLgJ4zIBqIANgJYAm5FArtEgLxJT4BOVwA5kgB8kwBmABGEToOEMKFANw48REknq0AKsWZsARPggAPfLun6qkU0N0NgAa2AB7AO7Bdi7EoLakAEQjwjpwgBjSsGF54oJAA-ABc7Fw8-EIich54ytrxapSa2lAZmQBulEw56nRl0EXKVPgUEAkc3Hy1iSCc+Aki4pJFAL4eXirIAJLAAFYBoeFYuJlGXCBQCY5i0-D4g8MLAPR7SI7Fktw0yQQAFsijUEgAZpyOYH4BQSEQNCM+Gkvh-oFgrMAGSRJATTYgiILTLCcBNRKtXjtLIkBL6JbuMF4UqMBEtZLtIY4LwHJBGODAGh3daQ7wkGnAZCNE4UJA0CAQGDfVQAUUMlJoAB4NAA+cIacnGCBUu48e6SJAAeSQMQwSAA2gBpJA8JB2CCERz3ZUAXQSSu1pqQAyQPQgJ04uzwZIpIFlRw2M3pzE4AQYnCgVFZhB5yH5JCpACV-YHgxAKIQReK2JKljLqZ7IWC1WnpR75YqVWr0JqdXqDUaTUrzUgIxmY-AA0GQ0LLVrTeLbfbHWCEhpnT66wL3RyaL9jOEI6ORUtRUU9gAqIfTqmfCf4OZg6L4pJtMGjdEGYxYmFIXFMZp75EH+qNK9I9ocTrdGR9J1gpbBVZZma1W2LnsOADDgQA)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I've wanted something like this ever since I started out on Typescript - such a cool hack.

Comment: If you're using this with VS Code and want to see full expanded types via IntelliSense, you might also want to enable `noErrorTruncation` in your `tsconfig.json` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53131824/146044)

Comment: Oh man, your Expand should be built-in utility type Alias<T> or something.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks @jcalz. Is there a way to get it to return a `Date` type without it's [default recursive types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45485198/25197)?

Comment: Never mind... I figured it out like 10 seconds later... change to this `type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends Record<string, unknown>`

Comment: This is neat but it turns functions into empty objects as they extend object but don't have any properties.

Comment: @JanneAnnala `export type ExpandFunction<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: Expand<A>) => Expand<R> : never;` works for me. Might write a general case which works recursively with objects or functions at some point.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but think its fine to continue discussing, wondering if you think it would be possible and how you would extend this to include some maximum expansion depth. Think it would be useful for limiting recursive types so the compiler doesn't complain but also get a bit more information than just one level.

Comment: Like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WPgRYm) maybe?  If you need more or something else, please open a new question post about it.

Answer (score 61):

Just supplementing [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/3554391) with versions which work with functions.

The modified helpers:

```
export type Expand<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: Expand<A>) => Expand<R>
  : T extends infer O
  ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
  : never;

export type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: ExpandRecursively<A>) => ExpandRecursively<R>
  : T extends object
  ? T extends infer O
    ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> }
    : never
  : T;
```

To test, I'm adding a `subobject` key to `Text` type, and adding a function interface:

```
type Text = Decorated &
  Injected & {
    name: string;
    type: "text";
    value: string;
    subobject: Injected;
  };

interface SomeFunction {
  (...args: Text[]): Injected & { error: boolean };
}
```

This gives:

[image]

[image: expanded once type hover]

[image: recursive type hover]

Objects still work fine:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow this works great, maybe there's a way to write an extension that integrates with IntelliSense to implement this.....

Comment: Is there a way to save the expanded structure somehow to clipboard/file? Because when the type structure has many members, the result gets truncated... Or at least is there a way to see the complete expansion without truncation?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik [backus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type/69288824#comment107641913_57683652) had a good solution for you in the comments for jcalz's answer: *If you're using this with VS Code and want to see full expanded types via IntelliSense, you might also want to enable `noErrorTruncation` in your `tsconfig.json` (see stackoverflow.com/a/53131824/146044)*