# Inspect nested TypeScript interfaces & types in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When using `VSCode` with `TypeScript` I find myself constantly hovering over functions or objects to inspect their type.

Often, the types and interfaces for these objects rely on multiple other interfaces and types. So hovering doesn't give much info.

To inspect the type I have to go manually into e.g. node modules to find the type declaration and inspect it there.

Is there a way to inspect nested types easily in `VSCode`?

Here is an example:

[image]

I'd love an easy way to inspect the interface that is `React.FunctionComponent`.

Comment: Does anybody know how to get properties for all inherited interfaces? Say, you have an interface inheriting 5 other interfaces, but no specified properties: `export interface A extends B,C,D,E,F{}`. How could you view the properties of ALL inherited interfaces in one given screen? Currently, I'm inspecting each interface manually to check the properties of each inherited interface.

Comment: @GM Please vote for the issues describing this behaviour: [vscode/issues/157461](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157461) and [TypeScript/issues/10752](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10752).  See also **[→Q1](/q/55269520 "interfaces IntelliSense") [→Q2](/q/61066520 "intellisense doesn't suggest interface") [→Q3](/q/61851075 "interfaces hover hints") [→Q4](/q/61132949 "documentation of types in interfaces") [→Q5](/q/66701574 "interface doesn't show methods")**.

Comment: See also: [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type) for how to see the _actual resolved_ type if you end up getting just an unusable mess of references to other complex types.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for exactly but :

[image]

Press the key `ctrl` to show details when hovering

[image]

Also, `ctrl` + left click will go to the interface declaration, so you could see the full details.

I don't think that there is enough space to display all the nested interfaces details using hovering anyway. Going to the declaration seems the most appropriate way to get your information.

Comment: Hey Gregory! That's already amazing advice. Hovering and pressing CMD (on mac) should be listed everywhere in fat, fat letters for people using VSCode. I didn't know about this until know!

Comment: If I right clicked in the past and clicked on "go to type definition" it never seem to work. But CMD+Left click or hover does the trick!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when hovering over a variable. E.g. hovering over `varX` in statement `const varX = somefunction()` where `function somefunction(): ComplexType {}` only shows `const varX: ComplexType`

Comment: VSCode sucks, why isn't this fixed. I want the same behavior for interface as for type.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could use `ALT` + `F12` shortcut to trigger peeked editor.

For me personally, this is the most convenient way to peek into some component's info without changing the main context.

See more info in docs:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek

Comment: Either the shortcuts have changed, or it's because I'm on linux, but here, they are: When you execute a Go to References search (via Shift+F12), or a Peek Definition (via Ctrl+Shift+F10), we embed the result inline: