# For Typescript intersection type (type C = A & B), how to see resulting type signature instead of components in IDE hints?

Tags: typescript, ide

In Typescript, when inspecting types defined by intersection, I see a hint identical to original definition:

[image]

but I would like to see the resulting shape, something like this:

[image]

what is a quick / efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code in the images as text also, as described in [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to ask your IDE to do this automatically, but you can make a type function that calculates the type you're looking for.  From the answer to [the question is duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type), I would write `Expand`:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

which takes a type (or union of types) and walks through all of its properties, even if they come from multiple intersections, and packages it (or each union member) into a single object type.  Then you could either write `Expand<C>` or you could define `C` to be `Expand<A & B>`:

```
type ExpandedC = Expand<A & B>;
/*
type ExpandedC = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: Date;
}
*/
```

which is what you wanted.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigMwGdhiBLLAcygF8BuAWAChRIoAhBMigBjTAQD2EgDYRUWcgBNMAEVTBo7bt17QAwkLgAyAZy47w0AKIAPMPMUAeACoA+Ic6gQbGrIqpQDABmJFAAqlAA-MIA2gDSgVhQANYQIBJB4QC6mGHxWaxQmFgQAG4kZhZ8tvZ+EIoGiDUOjsYCrmYA9ABUVdZ2DvWNyNxQY2jF+ETEZuMU1LQMjLPjYhRSsvIrY8pQahpmLNzdnVBAA)