# VSCode TypeScript list field names

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

When I define a TypeScript object which is correctly typed, I would like to get the list of all possible fields as IntelliSense suggestions.

However, to get an autocompletion popup, I need to start typing at least one letter, and I will see only fields with a matching name.

In this example, if I put the cursor inside `variables`, I should see "email", "password". Currently, I need to type "e" to see "email" and "p" to see "password".

[image: example]

The use case is listing or even discovering fields in very complex options objects.

Note that I don't want to change the code itself (eg with an intermediate variable).

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I honestly searched Google and StackOverflow for this, and dug into VS Code preferences.

Comment: What would you see if you press Ctrl+Space inside `variables`?

Comment: It seems like it is not possible but have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/9346979 ?

Comment: Ctrl+Space works, that could be the accepted answer