# Deep Pick by Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Assume we have an object

```js
let obj = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    letters: {
        a: 'some a',
        b: 'some b',
    }
}
```

and we want to do a deep pick by a definition:

```js
let projection = {
    foo: 1,
    letters: {
        b: 1
    }
}
```

and it would produce:

```js
let result = {
    foo: 'foo',
    letters: {
        b: 'some b'
    }
}
```

The question is not how to do this in javascript - it is quite straightforward. But how the TypeScript definition would look like.

```js
type TProjection<T extends object, U extends keyof T> = {
    [key in U]?: T[key] extends object ? TProjection<T[key], keyof T[key]> : number;
}
function pick<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    projection: TProjection<T, U>
): Pick<T, U> {
    return null;
}
```

This results to top-level pick only, the `letter` field includes both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer - this can only confuse readers about what the question is. People can already find the answer below. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @kaya3 but my edits where not the copy past, I have added additional support for various cases - those were definitely useful for people, who finds the answere below, as the answer below has some limitations.

Comment: Then post your own answer as an answer. It is not part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of your `pick()` function *might* matter a bit, since there are probably edge cases in the typing I will propose here that you'll need to test.  Hopefully you can use this as a starting point and tweak to get edge cases.

First it's useful to describe a `Projection<T>` which is the acceptable type of `projection` values for an `obj` of type `T`:

```
type Projection<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? Projection<T[K]> : number
};
```

(We could say that `number` should be `1` but then you'll need something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) for your `projection` variable.)

Given an object type `T` and a projection type `P` that extends `Projection<T>`, we can now represent `DeepPickByProjection<T, P>`:

```
type DeepPickByProjection<T extends object, P extends Projection<T>> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, keyof P>]: (
    P[K] extends number ? T[K] :
    T[K] extends object ? DeepPickByProjection<T[K], P[K]> :
    never
  ) } extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Basically we are walking through the common keys of `T` and `P`.  If the property in `P` is a `number`, we output the property from `T`.  If it is an `object`, then we recurse down into `T[K]` and `P[K]` and repeat.  The only part that might look weird is the `extends infer O...` bit at the end.  This is a trick to force the compiler to eagerly evaluate the output type instead of deferring it.  If you want an output type like `{foo: string; letters: {b: string}}` instead of `DeepPickByProjection<UglyTypeOne, UglyTypeTwo>`, you need something like this trick.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type) for details about how it works.

Okay, let's see if the typing works:

```
function pick<T extends object, P extends Projection<T>>(
  obj: T,
  projection: P
): DeepPickByProjection<T, P> {
  return null!;
}

const result = pick(obj, projection);
/* const result: {
    foo: string;
    letters: {
        b: string;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.  The output type of `result` is the same as the input type of `obj` filtered by the projection.  So hooray.

Remember though there might be *lots* of edge cases.  I'd be concerned about optional properties, union properties, and array-valued properties for starters, as well as making sure someone wouldn't want to pass in something like `{letters: 1}` meaning "copy the whole subtree here", since the above typing prohibits that, I think.  As I said, this should be thought of as a launching point and not as a production-ready drop-in for your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Amazing, your help is so much appreciated. I have added `(TProjection<T[K]> | number)` to allow `{letters: 1}`, and array support, now all our mongodb projections are type safe - [class-mongo/FindOptions.ts](https://github.com/atmajs/class-mongo/blob/9abcd23628fb1c149bff4abbb8517f6b2feb2eb9/src/types/FindOptions.ts#L20)