# How to write a function signature of function that generates a bijection in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function which takes a map and generates the bijection of the map:

```
 export function keyTextBijection(map) {
  const bijection = {};
  Object.keys(map).forEach(key => {
    bijection[key] = map[key];
    bijection[map[key]] = key;
  });
  return bijection;
}
```

How to signature the function elegantly in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

It helps to write a type function to turns a type like `{a: "A", b: "B"}` to its inverse, `{A: "a", B: "b"}`.  TypeScript 4.1 will make this easy with *mapped type `as` clauses* as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336):

```
// TS4.1+
type Invert<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>> = { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K };
```

But for TypeScript 4.0 and below you can get something reasonably equivalent in most cases by using mapped conditional types:

```
// TS4.0-
type Invert<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>> =
    { [K in T[keyof T]]: { [P in keyof T]: K extends T[P] ? P : never }[keyof T] }
```

In either case, you want `keyTextBijection` to take an object of type `T` and return an object of type `T & Invert<T>`. Since such an intersection looks ugly, I usually define a no-op mapped type called `Id` which has the effect of merging the intersection into a single type object.  (This `Id` is also called `Expand` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type)):

```
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : any;
```

So now we can give a call signature to `keyTextBijection`:

```
function keyTextBijection<T extends Record<keyof T, S>, S extends PropertyKey>(
  map: T
): Id<T & Invert<T>>;
function keyTextBijection(map: any) {
    const bijection: any = {};
    Object.keys(map).forEach(key => {
        bijection[key] = map[key];
        bijection[map[key]] = key;
    });
    return bijection;
}
```

In the above, `S` doesn't really do anything for inference purposes; it's mostly just a way to give the compiler a hint that it should try to infer the `T` type as a mapping from literals to literals.  When you enter `{a: "A"}` as the `map` argument, you want the compiler to see the type as `{a: "A"}` and not as `{a: string}`, since the latter will not invert properly.

And the function uses a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) call signature to allow the implementation to be lax with type safety and use `any`.  (If you don't do this, you'll find yourself having to use a bunch of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) because the compiler won't be able to verify the type safety of the assignment statements).

---

Let's test it:

```
const bij = keyTextBijection({ a: "A", b: "B", c: "C" });
/* const bij: {
    a: "A";
    b: "B";
    c: "C";
    A: "a";
    B: "b";
    C: "c";
} */
console.log(bij);
/* {
  "a": "A",
  "A": "a",
  "b": "B",
  "B": "b",
  "c": "C",
  "C": "c"
}  */
```

The type and the value of `bij` look correct to me.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201029#code/PTAEBUGUBYDoEYDUBYAUCALgTwA4FNQBJAOwDc8AnDAHnFDwA8M9iATAZ1ACU8BjAewqtqAazxZ+AMwgAaUAAUK-fFSwBpcQD5NoALygA3qADaa0AEtioMROl0Ahp3CmAui4BcoMwF8A3GhAIGFgABgBaNGx8IjJKGjpGZjZOHgEhUXEpWQUlFWwNLG09NFBSwxMzSwhjGyzwN08jY3kLK1q7Dy96JhYOavkXUAB+BVBPYjxyClBvGsyOmbRI3AJCYXAdfQSe5NbJSlAAVWHy01breaPOw9cZsdB7Yix-VDRJAFdiXgxzfjbxcCJABC5gAVnwfn9aN0kn1UoJhO1spBNHJIDDepxFMo4uotAAKAC29hwnnAAEpPGtoQAyGJTeLaF4fL6Q-5YQFMEHg76-YhEkmeR5YcmGEplATEdgYUAAIzBEL5QqeekMfnFpQA8rKeRhYDZ2AKcOTYJJBABRey8AAW+Jseh0Bg1ZVK8t1fLmWEG+mJOE9LheLpdbsVf2Mvv93ouz2d3nJgbKFDwGHeFCsId5fxe3iWqEl0rlYNVNk5GG5of5RnsngARABBGtyWW1oGN0C8WsAYRrM3jAQAVO2-gW3Y1ndXQPWawnXS3p86O5PuzPQHXa-Z56gXUDa7Lp6BnZ3a7xN95QP3gGh8-wADZ4WA3-gAc3xbr76EHTq3k43tYbMnFKd10bQC9znADvxrVtdxAyCTy7WDShrbtjxrNAz3PYAgA)