# Typescript: Can you create a type based on a hierarchy?

Tags: typescript

There is probably a much better way of titling this question. If you think of a better name, let me know and I'll change the title. My question is kind of complex, but I have [a code sample that demonstrates what I'm looking for well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFARAMRRQEEA7AEwCE41coAfPAKQFcBnYagLzsd2IA2A3ACgREAB5h0wKAGMUpDlADuAS3JIIwNtigBtEVCgBvI8aik4AWwgAuKAHJCKRwBpzxuQmTo1ENgd9AiIyKhpcNzxBYQBdcwBfD2MzC0sbeydqNHdPeR9UNH9AgxCSCmzI6KFceOMk81SLK1sHR25ctO9EQuKg3FYObir%20GrqoBtioOF0FJWAAbjFJaTRZUEgoAHUNLWAAOQy9DYgUADNVXe02fVIWawAjCDRY-UcWiEdYpfEpGSg1KREGgznA5NAdpptKZzB8HJC9odbEsvAU-AEHPAeugQPp4glln81gCgc9QeDtldgAAFIrg3RNAQobpqRQODhFUhIFFQAD0vKgbBQtigZ38AnIUAAFs9oMApQgoGgIABHFhqZW6EAoFhQYAoeQoABuzygEBNGD14Gg50uUOA5n5qhl8tNalkT1FaGF%20WxRQCUHQgsgcjUYrk6VsbBEBJEToAErLHLopSgVFAAJKqHUS1RwIGU%2020tT0vUGlToADWdjEc2URrgAg0ekZzIQrNIDlwKrgXAE%20fIajgkXMLgcAEZklBsg4AExT7gOADMHljddkDab5FnLfMTJZbLwPb7A6HI%20MLjCM6gK-Mi5vq9rinrjY0S93xn37cP3d7-YoZ5TjEE4AAyPiI65QJuGgACwflAX7AB2XbHv%20g7DlOl4VDQy4LjhUAAKxRE6gKGuQEBRFmFYsLmYDeg8cAPAImBIGoJrTMGEChuGkbQHRXEQORpAUsappwL6vgYFEDwsLILjZjRkqgkIDFyJWZYAjoEmFCAd69rhMZPvMUGvuQBHwYhyFHn%20p4YaOoTYWgBnGMBhHEQKpEKORlEKbR9GMcxUCsex4lsCGYYltpOJQPx4JCSJFocQ83pwORaBRRghkQc%20G6mQAbBZbZIT%20qG2eeUBYeETkPuYgycPpblZZBzzeulOCtgenbWSeAF2ReRATlOTotegDjWGobBsICSBQAxaB6VwBlrjlZpoK1O7tXuRVWb%20PXoeVlXXrexjDWt6BRONk3TbNvYxkAA):

```
type Category = "FooAndBar" | "JustBaz" | "All"

export const widgets = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    categories: ["FooAndBar", "All"]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    categories: ["FooAndBar", "All"]
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    categories: ["JustBaz", "All"]
  },
] as const;

export type WidgetName = typeof widgets[number]['name'];

export interface Widget {
  name: WidgetName;
  categories: Category[]
}

export interface WidgetPrices {
  location: string;
  // some field here that requires you to cover every type of widget,
  // whether it be from categories or specific names
}

// Here's how I would want WidgetPrices to work:

const valid = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  Foo: 1,
  Bar: 2,
  Baz: 3,
}

const valid2 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
  Baz: 3,
}

const valid3 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  All: 10,
}

const valid4 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
  Bar: 5, // in code, I would probably give a specific name precedence over a category, but Foo would fallback to its category
  Baz: 3,
}

const valid5 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
  All: 5, // in code, I would probably give a specific category precedence over a broader category
}

const valid6 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
  JustBaz: 5,
}

const error = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  Foo: 1,
  // error: missing bar
  Baz: 3,
}

const error2 = {
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
  // error, missing baz
}
```

The question is, can something be defined like this with typescript's type system? **What would `WidgetPrices`' declaration look like?**

I'm flexible on `WidgetPrices`' declaration in certain ways, e.g., I'd *prefer* the implementations to look the way I presented, but I'd be ok with separate `Names` and `Category` properties, if that's the only way to pull this off.  The most important thing to me is that the compiler errors when I'm missing coverage.

Comment: Hi, do you have an arbitrary number of fields to add to widget Prices? In this case I would add a generic optional param, like [_: string] :? Any. If you have a imited number of price types that you can add, I'd  extend them from widget Prices. Finally, you could consider  having a typed wodgetPrices with a params attribute of type T

Comment: Every time I add a new element to `widgets`, `WidgetPrices` would get a new field.  I don't know if that's what you're asking, @CarlosMoura

Comment: This is the type of question I live for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something that works *for your example* where `WidgetPrices` is a specific [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of valid selections for the keys of the `number`-valued properties.  This union has a number of members that grows *exponentially* as the number of Widget names or categories grows linearly.  That means you will likely hit compiler performance problems or other limits if your hierarchy is some amount larger than what is shown in your example, and if so, you might need to retreat from a specific type to a [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type.  For now I will only worry about the union version, and possibly come back later to work on a generic version if the use case requires it:

```
type Widgets = typeof widgets[number]
type Price<K extends PropertyKey> = K extends PropertyKey ? { [P in K]: number } : never;
type _WidgetPrices<W extends Widgets = Widgets> =
  (W extends any ? (x: Price<W["name"] | W["categories"][number]>) => void : never) extends
  ((x: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
type WidgetPrices = Id<{ location: string } & _WidgetPrices>;
```

Before I get into explaining any of that, let's just see if `WidgetPrices` looks right.  If you inspect with IntelliSense, you are shown:

```
/* type WidgetPrices = {
    location: string;
    All: number;
} | {
    location: string;
    Foo: number;
    FooAndBar: number;
    All: number;
} | {
    location: string;
    Foo: number;
    FooAndBar: number;
    Baz: number;
} | {
    location: string;
    Foo: number;
    FooAndBar: number;
    JustBaz: number;
} | ... 21 more ... | {
    ...;
} */
```

Each of the union members shown corresponds to a valid selection of prices.  They all have a `location` property, and their other fields cover the full set of widgets.  The first one has only `All`, which is enough.  The others have a different choice that works.  And you can verify that all of your `valid…` values work:

```
const valid: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia",  Foo: 1,  Bar: 2,  Baz: 3,
}

const valid2: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia",  FooAndBar: 3,  Baz: 3,
}

const valid3: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia",  All: 10,
}

const valid4: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia", FooAndBar: 3, Bar: 5, Baz: 3,
}

const valid5: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia", FooAndBar: 3, All: 5,
}

const valid6: WidgetPrices = {
  location: "qazlandia",  FooAndBar: 3,  JustBaz: 5,
}
```

while the `error…` ones fail:

```
const error: WidgetPrices = { // error!
  //  ~~~~~
  // Property 'Bar' is missing in type '{ location: string; Foo: number; Baz: number; }' 
  // but required in type '{ location: string; Foo: number; Bar: number; Baz: number; }'
  location: "qazlandia",
  Foo: 1,
  Baz: 3,
}

const error2: WidgetPrices = { // error!
  //  ~~~~~~
  // Type '{ location: string; FooAndBar: number; }' is missing the following 
  // properties from type '{ location: string; All: number; FooAndBar: number; JustBaz: number; }': 
  // All, JustBaz
  location: "qazlandia",
  FooAndBar: 3,
}
```

---

Okay, now for a sketch of the explanation:

- The `Widgets` type is just the union of element types in the `widgets` array.
- `Price<K>` turns a union of keys `K` into a union of single-keyed objects with a `number`-valued property, for each key in the `K` union.  So `Price<"a" | "b">` becomes `{a: number} | {b: number}`.
- The heavy lifting is in `_WidgetPrices<W>`.  We give it a union of widgets `W` and [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over that union. For each element in `W` we calculate `Price<W["name"] | W["categories"][number]>`.  So, for example, the `Foo` element becomes `Price<"Foo" | "FooAndBar" | "All">`, or `{Foo: number} | {FooAndBar: number} | {All: number}`.  These are all the object types that would cover just the `Foo` widget; let's just name this `CoverageForFoo`.  What I then do is to get the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of the unions-of-coverage-objects, via a [technique for getting the compiler to calculate arbitrary-size intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).    If `W` is `Widgets`, then this is essentially the thing we're looking for.  That is, you want `CoverageForFoo & CoverageForBar & CoverageForBaz`. Such an object type would definitely cover `Foo` *and* `Bar` *and* `Baz`.
- A big old intersection of unions is *uuuugly*, so I use another [technique to eliminate some of those intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type).  The `Id<T>` type more or less just produces an equivalent object type to `T`, but something like `Id<{a: number} & {b: string}>` would become `{a: number, b: string}`.
- Finally, `WidgetPrices` is `Id<{location: string} & _WidgetPrices<Widgets>>`: a vaguely non-ugly union of things with a `string`-valued `location` property and `number`-valued properties that cover all the widgets.

---

So, hooray!  As I said, this will probably blow up if you add too many things in there.  The approach to turn this generic would involve a helper function that checks if a value is a `WidgetPrices<W>` for some suitable generic type parameter `W`, but then you'd have to carry around generics whenever you wanted to talk about widget prices.  And since I don't know if the use case requires it and I've already spent a bunch of time on this, I'll stop here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFARAMRRQEEA7AEwCE41coAfPAKQFcBnYagLzsd2IA2A3ACgIADzDpgUUJCgB1AJbkkEYADk4AW2g45EFADMoAdxVrgbANqkW2gEYQ0AXWsByUjojuXAbjFJaSglUkQ0IzgAY2hlVXUoAG8RKCgvXQAuRQt1LV0A1KiEZHQlCDYs+ERUDGsXEQBfEUCpNBkolFIOMxyrbChrFKSh1PSILPdCFHcAGhGoIurS8qzrAiIyKhpcGbxBYXrUhrnU5NTR7wnqNFn5xZK0MoqB9ZIKa529oVxDqGOhs7nMZXOBcW7nBbFGpPVa4VgcbiffjfX7-FxQOBsBadDgBZoGbLxPr6cCGEzmIk2OyOZz1AkABUeMQAPABpKASRAULGMlCQNogVkQEAAPn67M5EG5UF5-NAQswAH4kgN6SFSFBWS4stSnGg-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-O6IKQvIGywv-CL+kBVS4sSrhkooNKMoYyStjQLISqGQqBrKirAuClQirqokAMaoZmtIvBWva1L0pyji7IABlKvycTG6qABYpugu1YJVOaYoElqkpSzqcsYqS+uKgr9IAVmerh+u28rdqgKqVBeo71BmuDzqQhaEuujrVsynq8oG1IOLexodoC37xvIAA2QHgGBqLCIutSIbam7oe6t5es+oZjMKpGRp+5w0HQbHcdXYDgI5NBGbQABCIY2dSAA-IWhb59nZWcUAoHca53BCLFtCUNg2DQ9UIPkdx7wJ5DUI-PwoFE3UzVy0yDKNhpZdFqAHBYGQ0AgeKWCUO3yFVgkNfxsGhM0-WiB043HsNujjY+02g-N0HYvBpaSa6n3tKgbLBpN4aUe6Bn0FqqCgYauCoH59OectqBheFy2x0g935q93W470gOuL1825ccxXlY-WQAAtoCMFAhBQcx28tsBGblJ4oCMRntDV6BK61hadfQ9ihD9+6KdDvXqZNwPG-cLJLf2XZN64CPLqjyGVtj1e4dKoA)

Comment: Is it still possible to have `WidgetName`? Does its type change?

Comment: I didn't touch `WidgetName` but there's no reason you can't use it; it's equivalent to `Widgets["name"]`