# Typescript typecast object so specific required keys are no longer optional in the type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say you have an object type:

```
type Person = {
  name?: string;
  color?: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

However you want to change that type into the following, where you know name and color will exist.

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

Therefore, there is the function

```
const throwIfUndefined = (
  object: {[key: string]: any},
  requiredKeys: string[]
): ReturnTypeHere => {
  for (const key of requiredKeys) {
    if (!object[key]) throw new Error("missing required key");
  }

  return object;
};
```

What is the proper way to type the params of the function as well as the return type (`ReturnTypeHere`)? Written correctly, the below will either 1) throw error 2) console log the name. It will never console log undefined.

```
const person = {...}

const requiredKeys = ["name", "color"];
const verifiedPerson = throwIfUndefined(person, requiredKeys);
console.log(verifiedPerson.name)
```

Comment: Hmm, I really wish this code were a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE without typos or other issues.

Comment: If you're looking for a generic solution here, you shouldn't be testing for `undefined` with `if (!object[key])...` because this will give false positive for some numbers, some boolean values, empty strings and so on... `typeof(object[key]) === "undefined"` would be a more robust test.

Comment: @jcalz looks like plenty of others managed. Sorry for your struggles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an object type `T` and a union of its keys `K` that you'd like to have required, you can write `RequireKeys<T, K>` like this:

```
type RequireKeys<T extends object, K extends keyof T> =
  Required<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>;
```

Here we are using the [`Required<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), and [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility types.  There are probable edge cases here, such as if `T` has a string index signature and `string` appears inside `K`, but to a first approximation it should work.

It's also a little difficult to understand what `RequiredKeys<Person, "name" | "color">` is from how it's displayed in your IDE:

```
type VerifiedPerson = RequireKeys<Person, "name" | "color">;
// type VerifiedPerson = Required<Pick<Person, "name" | "color">> & 
//   Omit<Person, "name" | "color">
```

If you want the compiler to be a little more explicit, you can do something like the following to [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type) the type into its properties:

```
type RequireKeys<T extends object, K extends keyof T> =
  (Required<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>) extends
  infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

which results in

```
/* type VerifiedPerson = {
    name: string;
    color: string;
    address?: string | undefined;
} */
```

which is easier to see.

--

You then need to make `throwIfUndefined()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so the compiler can keep track of the relationship between the `object` and `requiredKeys` passed in:

```
const throwIfUndefined = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T,
  requiredKeys: readonly K[]
) => {
  for (const key of requiredKeys) {
    if (!object[key]) throw new Error("missing required key");
  }
  return object as unknown as RequireKeys<T, K> // need to assert this
};
```

And to test:

```
const person: Person = {
  ...Math.random() < 0.8 ? { name: "Alice" } : {},
  ...Math.random() < 0.8 ? { color: "Color for a person is problematic" } : {}
};
const requiredKeys = ["name", "color"] as const;
const verifiedPerson = throwIfUndefined(person, 
  requiredKeys); // possible runtime error here
// const verifiedPerson: RequireKeys<Person, "name" | "color">
```

If you want the compiler to remember that the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"name"` and `"color"` are members of `requiredKeys` then you need to do something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (i.e., `as const`) to tell it so.  Otherwise `requiredKeys` would just be `string[]` and you'd get weird/wrong results (we could guard against these but it would be possibly out of scope here).

And now, the compiler understands that `name` and `color` are defined, whereas `address` is still optional:

```
console.log(verifiedPerson.name.toUpperCase() + ": " +
  verifiedPerson.color.toUpperCase()); // no compile error
// [LOG]: "ALICE: COLOR FOR A PERSON IS PROBLEMATIC"

verifiedPerson.address // (property) address?: string | undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCAfgC4pFh4BLVAcwG58oBjZAG2Xipp1GrdkQAmY+BESIBtBszYBfXLlCQoAJQgBHAK70pAaQghEAHgAqUCAA9gEVGMRRkAIwBWEDsAA0UIxt7R2coAGtTZAAzKEsAPkx2AAptfUMIMXMYeg4wq38jOISAMigAeRJ6YHyAuIBKIIcnRHZGKIRyqHIcKABtGChGcMiYsoBdajL+saglKGpUCAA3BDY1cGgANQR6KPoMuCQ0TC1dA2NTC0OUVH8AImIyO6gAHyg7rl54O7i2AHo-lB1FsdnsDggbidUucMlkcnlrmh7o8IM83h8eHwfiVypVqojbu8UWj3p8sXFVH8AFRAjZQbYMMFiAknPAEAgo6jyYRsdmcTHwLlCRTsAjiSTSWRChRMV5QPROCB7RZiZRQKl-VS4LioWhAgAW8GQAHcAJJRACqiuVGROVkaIRc7i8PgKDuawxA0VicSS7Gd3mA1EsvnYUjSUjEJjM1Ck4jQ3BAAV6Y1wDQwCTZUCifCgSR1eoiSe94ZhUcuDSzBF2eYAhAGfL0i2MGsBDSbCBBjVAAKLwI3wJJ3SoyYRQUvpMSeu51XmzMMQYB6eDoBvAKBEFwKsKoE3oTenCMQaMWEO1XBKNYF9eQI6oagsrBZgB0r4AskQ28-4EQnMgSEkDTmFAAAMz4ABxdD0nLvAAgtwOSorM8w4EooYEK+z4fl+P5-gBQGgRBUHYPyXzUHcADCArZrmRBQLekL0C4YBGm43AQCQn45M8czUNgKiXtqaB6hOkYnicvQPKQqL3GS3wzAe15sNeUArIy+zMhCxxYG2Rpmpa1qMBkSQMUi45nJOJ6zlAAL0cgo5sdA8AKsA9BkDY-a5vqCAQLgtkqWpuwaQS1DQukJ5ZFphJSU8coYl8PyqAWPAQM+vBMEkgVMgSz4os+wDIBaYC3hRm4QIBUAANTvORVXsFlwVRc+cn5YVxUIKViDlXU1m2bu-IkGA9DsR5A5+YCvQADJlAA4hMcGTaaFE9tQFFlNNmhQAAYmUm2wbAPaaAAymUAByUCmkdsCaGUABCk09m+sGWEtdyqA14J3s+4pSDINmAiZRq3qADQ-ZKcjCrKbwKmISpGWIqhAA)

Comment: You taught me a new trick today with the type "expansion" using `infer`. :+1:

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following type:

```
type Require<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P]; }
```

to make certain props required. e.g.

```
type P = Require<Person, "name" | "color">
```

So you could now use this to type your function:

```
const throwIfUndefined = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    object: T,
    requiredKeys: K[]
): Require<T, K> => {
    if(requiredKeys.some(key => typeof object[key] === "undefined"))
        throw new Error("missing required key");    
    return object as Require<T, K>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider next example.

I think `typeguards` is the most suitable solution here:

```js
type Person = {
    name?: string;
    color?: string;
    address?: string;
}

const hasProperty=<T,P extends string>(obj:T,prop:P):obj is T & Record<P, unknown>=>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const throwIfUndefined = <T, K extends string>(
    obj: T,
    requiredKeys: K[]
): obj is T & Record<K, unknown> => requiredKeys.every(key => hasProperty(obj,key));

const person = {
    name: 'John',
    color: 'red',
    address: 'Ternopil'
}

const check = (arg: unknown) => {
    if (throwIfUndefined(arg, ['name'])) {
        const x = arg.name // ok
    }

    if (throwIfUndefined(arg, ['name', 'age'])) {
        const x = arg.name // ok
        const y = arg.age // ok
        const z = arg.other // error

    }
}
```

I decided to just return boolean from `throwIfUndefined`, because thats how typeguardss work.
Here you have fully generic solution. `throwIfUndefined(arg, ['name', 'age'])` means that `arg` variable 100% contains `name` and `age` properties

If you still want to throw an errors, you can use `assert` functions.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) you can find the docs.