# Typescript: Return type based on nested keys array

Tags: typescript

I am creating a Typescript SDK for a REST API and am struggling to make it as type-safe as I would like it to be. The SDK exposes a "retrieve" function that takes an argument "include" to expand the response with additional data.  One user might for instance want to retrieve a "cart" entity containing the "items" to avoid making two requests.

Given the following types and "retrieve" function:

```
// Types
type Cart = {
  id: number;
  // ...
  items?: CartItem[]
}

type CartItem = {
  id: number;
  // ...
  product?: Product;
  brand?: Brand;
};

type Product = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};

type Brand = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

// This is the function I want to be as type-safe as possible
const retrieve = ({include: string[]}) => {
   return {
      id: 1,
      // ...
   } as any;
}
```

I would like to achieve the following result. Notice how the inclusion of `items.brand` marks both the `items` property and the `brand` property in `items` as defined (opposed to possibly `undefined`).

```
/* const cart: {
    id: number;
} */
const cart: Cart = retrieve({ })

/* const cart_with_items: {
    id: number;
    items: {
        id: number;
    }[];
} */
const cart_with_items: Cart & { items: CartItem[] } = retrieve({
  include: ["items"]
});

/* const cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand: {
    id: number;
    items: {
        id: number;
        product: {
            id: number;
            title: string;
        };
        brand: {
            id: number;
            title: string;
        };
    }[];
} */
const cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand = retrieve({
  include: ["items.brand", "items.product"]
})

// The following code should throw an error
cart_with_items.items.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.brand.title) // Error: 'item.brand' is possibly 'undefined'
})

// The following code should not throw any error
cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand.items.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.brand.title)
  console.log(item.product.title)
})
```

I tried to crack this for hours without success, is there any generous Typescript wizard willing to help me solve that "challenge" ?

Thank you very much if you try to solve this !

Comment: Can we get a [mre]? The code you provided does not demonstrate the problem: https://tsplay.dev/WJxklN (missing definitions).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include some types in the demo. It is fixed, thanks !

Comment: @jcalz Indeed, the types presented as comment in the first code snippet are what I would like the "retrieve" function to return. I can't really make the example more "reproductible" as I have no idea how to extend the code from the second snippet to obtain the results presented in the first one. Sorry if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Indeed that makes it easier to understand, thanks +1

Comment: Indeed I am not sure that this can even be generalized if the property is an Array as it is the case with ```items```. In this case, including "items.product" would mean that, if items is of type ```T[]```, the property "product" in ```T``` is defined.

Comment: @AxelDS. does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAx1kN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame That is really close ! However, if I include the key "items.brands" the type of ```cart.items``` is now an object and not an Array<Item & { brands: Product }>. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @AxelDS. what about [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3vGbN) then?

Comment: Exciting to see that it comes so close ! However, in your second playground, if I include they key ```items.product``` it should return ```Cart & { items: Array<Item & {product: Product}> }```. For the moment, it returns ```Cart & {product: Product}```. Tell me if I should create a TS playground for a more detailed comment :)

Comment: @AxelDS. is `items` in the `{ items: Array<Item & {product: Product}` fixed key?

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wXrdom) work for your needs?  I'm happy to write up an answer if so; if not, could you [edit] the question code to show example use cases where it fails?

Comment: I think I handled it as well. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wO5dMm). Also will be happy to write an answer :D

Comment: Not yet working but really close! I edited the question to include the "issues" I face with your implementations. Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Could you [edit] that so that it's not a comment-as-part-of-your-question? I was suggesting you edit the question to show the use case: here is the input, here is the output I expect.  It shouldn't read like it has anything to do with comments, especially since these comments might well be obliterated after everything is clarified

Comment: The issue with mine is really interesting. If you do something like this `type Item = Prettify<typeof cart_with_products_and_brands['items'][number]>` both of them are in the resulted type

Comment: I edited the original question to better reflect the expected result.

Comment: ① I hope when this is done you can [edit] to be a single well-posed question post and not a series of updates. ② Your latest example is internally inconsistent; if you actually want `cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand` to be of the type you annotated, then the behavior after that cannot be made to do what you're asking; it's just the way that type behaves.  If you want nested intersected arrays, you get nested intersected arrays. If you want something else, then you need something else.  ③ Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGdQkw) work as you actually want? Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Your latest TS playground implements the end result perfectly, thank you very much ! The error "does not exist on type X" in the second example was indeed not possible. I will re-write my question.

Comment: It wasn't just that error, but the fact that you wanted `Cart & { items: Array<CartItem & { product: Product, brand: Brand }> }` to allow `.forEach(i => i.brand.title)`; nothing I can do to TypeScript will make that possible because intersections of arrays don't act like arrays of intersections.  So when you rewrite the question, please don't say you want that type.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take a type `T` like `Cart` and be able to pass it a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of dotted path-like strings such as `"items.brand" | "items.product"` and produce a new type where the nested properties at paths corresponding to these strings (in some way that is complicated due to array types) are required to be present and not `undefined`.  This sort of looks like a deep key-dependent [`Required<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) type, or like a `RequireKeys<T>` from [Typescript typecast object so specific required keys are no longer optional in the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66679911/2887218) but for dotted paths. Let's call it `DeepRequired<T, K>`.  This will necessarily be a recursively-defined type.

Here's one possible approach:

```
type DeepRequired<T, K extends string> =
  T extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[I], K> } :
  T extends object ?
  (T & {
    [P in K extends `${infer K0}.${string}` ? K0 : K]-?:
    DeepRequired<P extends keyof T ? T[P] : {}, K extends `${P}.${infer KR}` ? KR : never>
  }) :
  T extends undefined ? never : T;
```

First, there's a complication where when an array type exists anywhere alone the path, you want to "skip" it.  After all, a value of type `{x: {y: {z: string}[]}` doesn't have an `"x.y.z"` property; it has a `"x.y[2].z"` or a `"x.y.123.z"` property or something like it.  So `T extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[I], K> } :` just "skips" the current `T` type if it's an array, and instead just [maps over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) the elements with the same path `K`.

Then, if `T` is a non-arraylike object, we want to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with a type depending on `K` that we need to parse.  The parsing is done with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).  `{[P in K extends ⋯]-?: DeepRequired<⋯, K extends ⋯>}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where the key `P` iterates over the parts of `K` before the first dot or the whole thing if there is no dot (so if `K` is `"a.b" | "a.c" | "d.e" | "f"` then the keys we iterate over are `"a" | "d" | "f"`) and where the value involves recursing with `DeepRequired` into the property of `T` at key `P` with the part of `K` after the first dot.

Oh and if `T` is not an object then we preserve it unless it's `undefined`, which is removed.

---

That would be sufficient more or less, except that it produces intersections of arrays like `CartItem[] & (CartItem & { product: Product })[]`, which don't behave the way you want. See [microsoft/TypeScript#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) for information about that.  To circumvent this, let's define a `DeepMerge<T>` which recurses down through a type and turns intersections-of-arrays into arrays-of-intersections, as shown here:

```
type DeepMerge<T> =
  T extends readonly (infer E)[] ? DeepMerge<E>[] :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: DeepMerge<T[K]> } : T;
```

If `T` is an array, then `DeepMerge<T>` becomes an array of the element type of `T`, which resolves any intersection issues.  Otherwise we recurse downward with `DeepMerge`.

---

And so `retrieve()` should look like:

```
  declare const retrieve: <K extends string>(
    { include }: { include: K[] }) => DeepMerge<DeepRequired<Cart, K>>;
```

Let's test it out:

```
type Cart = { id: number; items?: CartItem[] }
type CartItem = { id: number; product?: Product; brand?: Brand; };
type Product = { id: number; title: string; };
type Brand = { id: number; title: string; } // same as Product ‍♂️   

const cart = retrieve({ include: [] });
/* const cart: {
    id: number;
    items?: {
        id: number;
        product?: { id: number; title: string; } | undefined;
        brand?: { id: number; title: string; } | undefined;
    }[] | undefined;
} */
```

That type is equivalent to `Cart`, as desired.  It's not written that way because the compiler needed to recurse down into it to make sure it had no intersections of arrays hiding in there.  Now let's see the behavior we came here for:

```
const cart_with_items = retrieve({
  include: ["items"]
});

/* const cart_with_items: {
    id: number;
    items: {
        id: number;
        product?: { id: number; title: string; } | undefined;
        brand?: { id: number; title: string; } | undefined;
    }[];
} */

cart_with_items.items.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.brand.title) // error, item.brand is possibly undefined
})
```

Also looks good.  Now the `items` property is required.  Let's keep going:

```
const cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand = retrieve({
  include: ["items.brand", "items.product"]
})

/* const cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand: {
    id: number;
    items: {
        id: number;
        product: { id: number; title: string; };
        brand: { id: number; title: string; };
    }[];
} */
    
cart_with_items_and_product_and_brand.items.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.brand.title)
  console.log(item.product.title)
}); // okay
```

And that's good too.  The `items` property is required, as well as the `product` and `brand` properties of the elements of the `items` array.

---

So that's one approach.  Is it perfect?  Almost certainly not.  Deeply recursive types like this tend to have bizarre edge cases.  You might find some situation where it produces a completely unexpected result.  And unfortunately, sometimes fixing those results while keeping the "good" parts working requires a total refactoring, where some key assumption around which the type was designed is shown to be invalid.  All I can suggest is to test thoroughly against the use cases you expect to see, before using any such type in a production code base.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoQI4FcCWAnCATAPACoA0UA0lBAB7AQB2uAzlI8FhnQOYB8UAvACgoUQpRr0mUHAENcAezoAbEFGl0QAbQC6UAPxQA3lA0BJKBygBrCCDkAzEVoC0ugFyx4SVJhwFCprVIyXgBfKFchETFaBmY5ACMAKwgAY2A9SIAKUQAyQ0jhDQAFczpyaIlmAAMAEgMOOwgscgAGEIA6OtZ2LhCqvVbw8mc3Ao8EZHRsPHwS6hjJa1sHUX1-Ip13AxCgitioWoMijrqGpvJEPoGyRCG6CAA3Ju5IkIBKcMjRecqoNAYIHYOHgBvcns13IQANwCASgSDjMAAWSanAgRF4gmE33E+xk8iUKkyZ2aAFE3toBnAECisGj8KTuJSIti9pIEsk0gMjBoKBYlvZHO5qcjUej-GQtKEhtDYSkFKwpBA2BhHtA+FB8BQfvtuhweJkjBwUoo0LhoCEtqUTWaIO4yJT3izEbT6SLJj4ZgBhaRYYBBbiY3gGSI4YBoLBlEPCYQYXDuACMxDGAHoU1B2pnXqpmGoQDCQjC4eBoD6-fxDOZ41A6GgALbxJpQ8y0OuMNxQMvAEytx3FhFdnsQOsVo3V2sNptQMBYOS4NBpDtFWfztLN+JYNS4DsAIU3DGbhf70GXc4X6Q1Y-cE8bWGbwAwwEUdpYKq4h5h8Oge63o6r1-rW970fZ93D1d8oDCNMWGkOtoGkZhT1XdJAD4NwB2XcAWAJACEyQB4P9hAR5ToRUUl9C8lRVNVDWtU1zXcR03hhFMACooEI4jSK2MY4wAyc7y41t204mNhP-GtAKbMZhJnM9FytbixN44CnxfcDOEPKAAB8-gBIF7lwGERJjDctw7K8FKAqAH2UsC3zUyDNO081dLwAyYxCSktP+JzgX0gQwiYlM5QVdISL9AB9AB3R8AAswsfYdmA1MN2Eo6NqNtOiACJ4rbTKtD8hjYWY1jgtY0jIpiuKBKEmN5JvCThJyxgasMurxL4wzhGk5DTNE+q70skCVNs9TPJ0nzXMM4yGF6trFMG6zXx6OywjG7y9MmyDtALKAArlcqouAWKmvaE67DkLBSWkFJosyYlWw+Phg0iNi5GfdpFDkTh7uHdpptwdorOfD5oKaWcsFIHK-v3XBzGYMA5EYRgMHiZRHMBHyCvwtiQoOyqmrCrcwu689CYYML-orZLVSeQ1ImNGiXw0bKBOhrdMtIFmEvaEm0jyrGBGKnGyvCw7joEsncGJldSaJ-6Wr69rNqahXGvHJXJJjXngDk9X5qB4blo-TXhHlys5osg2bKNyDNvcrQdr2or00IaLoHOxRPqirgSvNFhorkNBFFhug5HSI7Zwi1R1EoLBwYIvGjqqhLJelmTgFT-7TtZ87Luu26frrR7nuEV73s+76oazg23hehU3ogD6vsLnmZbSQGhtr94BCAA)