# How do you form a conditional type of optional (or partial) properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

With different combinations of optional/required props of the same object, how do you form a conditional type that will switch based on those props?

In this example, I'm trying to get the type of `config` in the function that is returned to have the "required" props only if they were not set in `defaultConfig`:

```
type Length = `${number}px`
type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>

// Optional props
type Optional = Partial<{
  style: 'italic' | 'normal'
  weight: number
  lineHeight: number
}>

// Required props
type Size = {
  size: Length
}
type Family = {
  family: string
}

type DefaultConfig = EmptyObject | (Size & Family) | Size | Family
type Config<T extends DefaultConfig> = T extends Size & Family
  ? Partial<Size & Family>
  : T extends Size
  ? Partial<Size> & Family
  : T extends Family
  ? Size & Partial<Family>
  : Size & Family

const makeFontShorthandGenerator = <T extends DefaultConfig>(
  defaultConfig: T & Optional
): ((config: Config<T> & Optional) => string) => {
  return (config): string => {
    const cf = { ...defaultConfig, ...config }
    // build and return font string
  }
}

// Examples
const genFont1 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px', family: 'sans-serif' })
genFont1({}) // nothing required

const genFont2 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px' })
genFont2({ family: 'sans-serif' }) // requires 'family', but 'size' is still optional

const genFont3 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({})
genFont3({}) // this is where the problem is
```

Right now, the expected type of the last example is `((Size & Family) | Partial<Size & Family> | (Partial<Size> & Family) | (Size & Partial<Family>)) & Partial<...>`, which allows `genFont({})` which is not what is wanted.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj5r1W) what you're looking for?  I'm not 100% sure if I missed some use case from your example.  If that works for you I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what is lacking.

Comment: Not quite, but I was able to use what you wrote to make what I needed. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6rBN). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can handle it with the following condition:

**Reference:**

- `defaultConfig` is the argument passed to outer function.
- `config` is the argument passed to returned function.

**Pseudo-code:**

- If `defaultConfig` is an empty, `config` must have all required props.
- Else `config` **must contain** at least the required props omitted in  `defaultConfig`.

  `config` can optionally contain any props defined in the initial
  props interface. In this way, properties can be added to `config` that can extend and/or override properties in `defaultConfig`.

**Code:**

Note: I added an additional required prop `color` for a stronger test example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=42&pc=65#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsjsAF4QBcyABgCT4gCuAtgEbQC+WAHrQG5iyeK2AAbAJ40cYKKADmQkggziMUGXMXLSYSeIgB+GgHJgYOOOAJTyAD7JTIDayundAdwjAFACzATZBYOaF1rEAgACR9-QJoQzighLkJCfSwUAFFWLH0AeXYAKwgEMGQAXgJhAG0AaWRQZDgQSQBdBIgANzDCVPTJTOQAEQh4ZnEwAGEMEBhfSrQ4KDBgKwAedGwcAD4hDJQAQXF1bwATGbnfdYAVHcX8sTBNzFwAGmQAawhJDBhkO7IABkIzGcAm01m8yUaQOyEu0Nu9wqwhuyAgvEgIDOeByeUkhRKZWERjQrxwwhox1OEAuUOudzSqhAsmQbm+ADFZmAAMp+DRgPwtM4AcQgkSgcDAGkWt3RmPFONB40mCN8OwAFMIzmCIWqFDQboQAJSVe4a5nQmj6pHGrTyEAKM3VFSzVkIf5VIgkEgAOn9OpVkKuCjewj9-stvmEqRIAHo48h2MwJGdmtjkFAIGBmFAQCJuXoHQphFmc3mnDgMKwULJi6Y+mlCAnkFleHBcoYKczWQpxVzwABGRbsiAD3n8lZC7FiiVSjQa-CkCjUJyDgBsfFMH1EEmklZaOAAtDhoMAYNvkKp1JonFmznYuKaW2j5mA8HDaKMg-raIQ+yA46DouT7IC2LiCoomYQAAjim95Mm65QAeOABMI5wJy3J8gK06iuK0DzlAi7LpQZgbluyCgS+IgWB+gwoF+uqqvSCh-ih3KoSRu5SGYOCHieZ4Xh814aGYADEMBSY+z6JrQ1IYOcNqArQ0FwcA94fJwCDgqeAKNPRQxMT+rF-oQPbIf23IAMwYVh4A4VOwqzoR0rEfg1GJmiwCGYxeIFMUpRgOxVngNZIGyXQWy4KpWbqZpSalLpKDeb5dD+QSgVlEAA)

```js
interface Props {
  size: `${number}px`;
  family: string;
  color: string;
  style?: 'italic' | 'normal';
  weight?: number;
  lineHeight?: number;
}

type EmptyObject = {
  [K in any]: never;
}

type DefaultConfig = Partial<Props>;
type AllowedConfig<T> = Omit<Props, keyof T> & DefaultConfig;

type Config<T> =
  T extends EmptyObject
  ? Props
  : AllowedConfig<T>

const makeFontShorthandGenerator = <T extends DefaultConfig>(
  defaultConfig: T
) => (config: Config<T>): string => {
  const cf = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    ...config
  }
  // build and return font string
  return 'some string'
}


// Examples
const genFont1 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px', family: 'sans-serif', color: 'red' }) // T fits type `DefaultConfig`
genFont1({}) // nothing required

const genFont2 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px' }) // T fits type `DefaultConfig`
genFont2({ family: 'sans-serif', color: '#fff' }) // `AllowedConfig<T> ` required, because T is type `DefaultConfig`

const genFont3 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({}) // T is type `EmptyObject`
genFont3({}) // `Props` required, because T is type `EmptyObject
```

Comment: Do you know why changing lines 17-24 and 41 to [here](https://tsplay.dev/W44YaW) makes example 3 not error anymore?

Comment: Ah I see. I think you need to use [generic param defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to make this work. [Update example](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8M9w) (line 22)

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to have a single type `Config` representing the full configuration object, including the optional properties:

```
interface Config {
  style?: 'italic' | 'normal',
  weight?: number,
  lineHeight?: number,
  size: Length,
  family: string
}

type Length = `${number}px`
```

Then, your `makeFontShorthandGenerator` should accept a `defaultConfig` object containing some subset of the properties from `Config`.  This will have to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function so that the compiler can keep track of which properties have already been set.  If we say that the keys of `defaultConfig` are of some generic type `K extends keyof Config`, and `defaultConfig` should be of type `Pick<Config, K>`, using [the `Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

The return type of `makeFontShorthandGenerator()` is a function which accepts a `config` object which *requires* the part of `Config` not supplied with `defaultConfig` (this type is `Omit<Config, K>`, using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)), and *allow* any property from `Config` at all (this type is `Partial<Config>` using [the `Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)). Since we want both of those, `defaultConfig`'s type is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the relevant types: `Omit<Config, K> & Partial<Config>`::

```
const makeFontShorthandGenerator = <K extends keyof Config>(
  defaultConfig: Pick<Config, K>
): ((config: Omit<Config, K> & Partial<Config>) => string) => {
  return (config): string => {
    const cf = { ...defaultConfig, ...config } as Config;
    return "whatever"; // do the real implementation here
  }
}
```

Inside the implementation, I have used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to say that `cf` is of type `Config`.  Generic object spreads result in intersections, and so the compiler can see that `cf` is of type `Partial<Config> & Pick<Config, K> & Omit<Config, K>`.  Barring edge cases, this should be equivalent to just `Config`.  Unfortunately the compiler is unable to see such equivalence, as it requires some higher order reasoning capabilities the compiler lacks.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) for more information.  The consequence is that, if we want the compiler to treat `cf` as a `Config`, we have to assert this ourselves.

---

Finally, let's make sure it works:

```
const genFont1 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({
  size: '16px',
  family: 'sans-serif',
})
genFont1({}) // okay, nothing required

const genFont2 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px' })
genFont2({ family: 'sans-serif', size: '14px' }) // okay

const genFont3 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({})
genFont3({}) // error!
/* Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of 
    type 'Omit<Config, never> & Partial<Config>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 
    'Omit<Config, never>': size, family */
```

That looks like the behavior you want.

---

Last thing: the error message mentions `Omit<Config, never> & Partial<Config>`.  If you want a more obvious type, you can change `makeFontShorthandGenerator`'s type signature a bit, using a custom `Expand` utility type from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type):

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

const makeFontShorthandGenerator = <K extends keyof Config>(
  defaultConfig: Pick<Config, K>
): ((config: Expand<Omit<Config, K> & Partial<Config>>) => string) => {
  return (config): string => {
    const cf = { ...defaultConfig, ...config } as any as Config;
    return "whatever";
  }
}

const genFont3 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({})
genFont3({}) // error!
/* Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 
  '{ style?: "italic" | "normal" | undefined; weight?: number | undefined; 
   lineHeight?: number | undefined; size: `${number}px`; family: string; }'.
*/
```

Now the error message mentions an anonymous type (that happens to be equivalent to `Config` because `defaultConfig` is `{}`) with spelled-out properties instead of an intersection of utility types.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZZAZzAE8AbCAfgC5kByYMOG4BF5AH1Yh0UALacWAGhJkA7hFwALME2QgAriIBG0KaWRcQEABLycSleq07pFYAC8IzADIQQOMAt1l4I4DSrMlFCgOCQAviQk1AAOKC5uHsgAvMgABgAk+JbaUGHRAB6pkcQImJTIYgDWEABimGAAygrCHnAgACYA4q7QcGDCycgAPADSyBD5kB3kyNVU6DBomNg4AHwAFDbtEPBqNGAYWLjMAArclUOHKxLII6skAJTM6+ulRzjMAPK+YJfLuDc7sgAGTIE5wKBgYCcP7vVYPZKrChgYJuBFJJFEPRQCBgNRQEDIV7-HBPZGovAYgg2MhvcoIRYpfDIAB0bO2u32VwBrLZbxWyDCyDgM25OAA3DTkDi8QTkAAiGQKPoQABu0Hlkr0EWIOpIdLAyBwrjq4AAjIMqrV6k0WsqOt1DFA+sJ1liyOR7I5WGaAGwFSQ2Hx+AKschtcgAWnI0GAMEDuoeJGNIFNYDNbrCCIA9NnVOgPCFpRAAI5qYA49rFA1Gk31ABMlrg1TTtsh9q6PWd-SgbtsDmYLD9AcFSeIKbT9b7wf8g-DICjMeC8ZunoHPoALCOs8hc8WyxWIDMWDOqJJkJo1IaWGuILxgDNKH4aMh0NEoZhONWyoaJ-UAMxNi2NrNO2bSdk6Lq9vgWbJnW4D-pmOZ5tAUDCAAhCQ2YAFTIAAglAOAaK4hoLMgMQoCwMH3jMQiGiKno4CAcCaHQ5HoMg0QQnAIi4tAr6LBRrDfOwsLXKoarQEioLgpC0I0GJuCrCwLI2AAKlQsSsNRyAPhUD6em45EKCgMDoDQNDoDIRbRGhsRyUeyAwGhIjkZplEib8Yo3IY6pQMpgRejcp7INh2bFMUzG8eQXFIMgACqS41MErjtP4ACiUBoVA1LEDYQnpfkXEdEMalIikanjJMqUzKAMD8Z8yD0AQyAANpjKAswQPMiyfAAul87V9YKyDML50BajYNZWq2oGtA6XZQYMoxVVM7QzHMZFihsUocnAewHCSpznIpOCAvcehki8-LHMghXFe0Qyead50gmCEJQjC23woi5IhOimJSjK+KEsS7xkkERZUu6ZCwzWDKDMybIsntB3ebyLI3XgQoisKIBUMKooklqsOw8DcqKsqkB+ZqUo6mQep6DWf7mkB1rgG280Qb0PZulKt6DsO+QJqTp5zhG0axiuNiwXoLPpkhu55nRChFjiB6VsUtI-rWqYNmzs12uBjo866zICz6-rC6ONjy1OzJi2GEtLnG54W0OW7Wzue7q+WOLHqe56Xtet40ciz6vu+wCfjQWvIMz8FgIBKQzSBRsLZBvMwWOZDy4h2dK+MWUYTYOH4YRxHgAJblaVRYRh3RhOMcxrEoP0nHcbxkA5WRQlSlRyK0AwzDyuwnDcPK-AKkIoicJPAhqB0OygBA7TisgciKMoY0aDkU+LxyK9r8gUqwwYximOYO9WDlC9L9ghjHxbGRZLv0B5IU6+O5Dbjr-Xql6DCuEIAA)

Comment: The `Expand` utility is very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With help from @jcalz comment, here is one answer:

**Explanation:**

Because `Pick<RequiredProps, K>` is the type of the props that ARE in `defaultConfig`, then using `Omit` and `Partial` on that type gives `config` the correct type.

```
type Length = `${number}px`

interface OptionalProps {
  style?: 'italic' | 'normal'
  weight?: number
  lineHeight?: number
}

interface RequiredProps {
  family: string
  size: Length
}

const makeFontShorthandGenerator = <K extends keyof RequiredProps>(
  defaultConfig: Pick<RequiredProps, K> & OptionalProps
): ((
  config: Omit<RequiredProps, K> & Partial<Pick<RequiredProps, K>> & OptionalProps
) => string) => {
  return (config): string => {
    const cf = { ...defaultConfig, ...config } as RequiredProps & OptionalProps
    return "whatever"
  }
}

const genFont1 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({
  size: '16px',
  family: 'sans-serif',
})
genFont1({}) // nothing required

const genFont2 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({ size: '16px' })
genFont2({ family: 'sans-serif', size: '14px' }) // requires 'family', but 'size' is still optional

const genFont3 = makeFontShorthandGenerator({})
genFont3({}) // error!
```

Comment: Generally speaking, answers should have explanations in them unless the code is completely self-explanatory.  I am writing up my answer now, but if you decide to accept your own answer, I'd recommend adding an explanation to this.