# Type for key with suffix

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible with typescript to define that keys of `state` should be `lowercase` + `some string`?

```
type HasSufix = `${Lowercase<string>}Required`

interface SomeShape {
  [key: HasSufix]: boolean
}

const state: SomeShape = {
  usersRequired: false,
  ordersRequired: false,
  booksRequired: false,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.8 AND ABOVE

This now works, as-is!!

As of TypeScript 4.8 there is now support for using [the intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) with wide types like `string`.  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47050) but not mentioned in the [TS 4.8 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/).

So now, `Lowercase<string>` only corresponds to lowercase strings (strings which remain unchanged after `.toLowerCase()`), whereas in TypeScript 4.7 and below it could match any `string`:

```
type HasSufix = `${Lowercase<string>}Required`

interface SomeShape {
    [key: HasSufix]: boolean
}

const state: SomeShape = {
    usersRequired: false,
    ordersRequired: false,
    booksRequired: false,
    oopsieDoodleRequired: false // error! 
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwMoFcBmBLAHlAvFAAwBIBvAGQHsB3CAJwGNEIAeBYWjAOwHMA+AXwBKEAI4oMtCABMCAWABQCrsDpo49aEgoBbCEgAWcSFBIKo5qAG0A1hBAAuWIlSYsAXUcAjChQA2EOE4FfgUFegpONig2OBVHLV0DI2h8U3kLKBQEOgRhMQlpRzVfbIAaMwsKWikcvPFJKSK4Eohy9ItvCmtc0XrCqGKyivMfMAQMCAARHyl-OoLGgebsqAB6Vag6WiqAQihggG5Q+SA)

---

### ANSWER FOR TS4.7 AND BELOW

There is currently no specific type in TypeScript that corresponds to your desired `SomeShape` type.  `Lowercase<string>` evaluates to just `string`; even if this were not true, [pattern template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) like `` `${string}Required` `` cannot currently be used as key types of an object; see [microsoft/TypeScript#42192](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42192) for more information.

Instead, you could represent `SomeShape` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that acts as a constraint on a candidate type.  That is, you make a type like `ValidSomeShape<T>`, such that `T extends ValidSomeShape<T>` if and only if `T` is a valid `SomeShape`.  It could look like this:

```
type ValidSomeShape<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T as
  K extends `${infer P}Required` ? `${Lowercase<P>}Required` :
  `${Lowercase<Extract<K, string>>}Required`]:
  boolean
} extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never;
```

The way this works is: the compiler [re-maps the keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) of `T` to those which are valid; if the key `K` does not end in `"Required"`, then we append it.  Otherwise, we turn the part before `"Required"` into a lowercase version of itself.  And we make sure that the property type is `boolean`.

The part at the end with `extends infer O ? ...` is a [trick from the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/2887218) which encourages the compiler to list out the actual properties of `ValidSomeShape<T>` in IntelliSense, instead of showing the rather opaque `ValidSomeShape<T>` name.  You'd rather see `{fooRequired: boolean}` in an errormessage instead of `ValidSomeShape<{foo: string}>`.

---

Moving on: to stop people from having to manually specify `T`, you can make a generic helper function `asSomeShape()` which *infers* `T` from its input:

```
const asSomeShape = <T extends ValidSomeShape<T>>(obj: T) => obj;
```

So instead of annotating `const state: SomeShape = {...}`, you write `const state = asSomeShape({...})`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const state = asSomeShape({
  usersRequired: false,
  ordersRequired: false,
  booksRequired: false,
}); // okay
```

This compiles with no error.  But watch what happens when you do something incorrect:

```
const badState1 = asSomeShape({
  usersRequired: false,
  ordersRequired: 123, // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
  booksRequired: false,
}); // okay

const badState2 = asSomeShape({
  usersRequired: false,
  ordersRequired: false,
  BooksRequired: false, // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'BooksRequired' does not exist in type 
// '{ usersRequired: boolean; ordersRequired: boolean; booksRequired: boolean; }'. 
// Did you mean to write 'booksRequired'?
}); // okay
   
const badState3 = asSomeShape({
  users: false, // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'users' does not exist in type 
// '{ usersRequired: boolean; ordersRequired: boolean; booksRequired: boolean; }'
  ordersRequired: false,
  booksRequired: false,
}); // okay
```

You can see that each failure results in a helpful error message.  The `ordersRequired` property is a `number` and not the expected `boolean`; the `BooksRequired` property should probably be `booksRequired`; and the `users` property is also wrong (the compiler doesn't seem to think it's close enough to `usersRequired` to hint that you should write that instead, but it does say that it expects to see `usersRequired` in there).

---

So, this is about as good as it gets, at least as of TypeScript 4.2.

Since a generic constraint is more complicated to use than a specific type, you might want to only use `ValidSomeShape<T>` in a function which interacts with objects which have not yet been validated... like the external-facing endpoints of some library. Once you have validated the object, you can widen its type to a less precise but non-generic type like `Record<string, boolean>` or something, and pass it around inside your library as that wider type:

```
export function userFacingLibraryFunction<T extends ValidSomeShape<T>>(someShape: T): void {
  // now that someShape has been validated, we can pass it to our internal functions:
  internalLibraryFunction(someShape);
}

// not exported
function internalLibraryFunction(alreadyValidatedSomeShape: Record<string, boolean>): void {  
  Object.keys(alreadyValidatedSomeShape).filter(k => alreadyValidatedSomeShape[k]);
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMDKB7AthNALOSAHgBUoIAPYCAOxQGcoMAjAKwgGNgA+KAXigBvKAG0A0lCQ0oAawggMAMyhk49AFBQoEytTqMABgBJBUxRABOUAAoBfAEoQAjgFckFiCgNQA-FGOCADIYAO6WHGoQRNbcDs5uHl5QAFya-ibBYRYR9FEAolQWcFxEYgA0UPTAFlIA5tyxjq7ungYAuqlazBgYCBBwNOq25FS0DJI05lYA8r5CohJSsvJKUNMda+JtUMPJUDQQAG6WANzq6hwYNFVQapg4+ITQAqQjeuPwyOjYuATEJA0ABQsVh7EgASn4vBBZwuVxuVTg1H4t3o91+T0BgjSLlyFnoTQSnj2ikQuTKaQwFhQlgJ8RaKBJZIgFK6PRkdOaiSZCHJQ3BJygAHohUwZHAQOdLtdgFBmHB0MAkRAAIwou4-R6QLE4vGcomMqCk3ksynU2mEhl7FUAJgAzBUReQLBYqQBCNIigB+Pt9fr9UCIAFog8LRSRwNAAOQ0FxYZiWKOSRg0DCytT0JC1GhwZh9KDADAFyNQKPdXr9GhRtLljmW7lG5kU2wCsNiiVS+Gy+WK5U29VozV-CA6rS4i30hvGvlaKk0-H14mNk2sqAAIXZ+qty-JbcsrosHq03v9p7PXs9oumbE4suQ1CKCCgWAlTBoCBAlUgHCQik-MlTEJpDAV1IAsYAkAgegKmYFxZSjDcMDrSdPCTFAMCg-Y0xGJAbiWUBICgS9S2EccFxQw1yz6AZBTnCcuSXKjK0FWstwbJiaJ2KMADoiOPUUABFUCgBQXGfSsCyLEIamRMtN0XFAox8flBSdJCO07GU5QVNAlWoO0B3RLUR2xMc9R5XcnX3d1L3PP1iOvdguCge9LEQZ9XyuD8v04X9-0A4DQMsCCoIqAYUFLMj6DQjCU2wyhcNlfCS2IqNSL1BS9g4mhaPNciGMonpqJyuV5IorKiuYrizXnNil2nU02SQurDQa5tWzU8VJXOSgwCpWVFBcGguCQK4oDIgAxYo6kCJBmCKCwQAmoaRquV5dDGRhPlQIzh1IIF6CHJ4wXBPZDgwYTTLbQCCwIWVDoeYcoAIRgE1oKBDkQVBlRQCowigCJgIzSRZULJgXCsKQHxzJ9BuGiD4U6CZocQWb5rgRblvh0aaEBB6MUgAUhnOJ1U1lXr+s8dQ4dW6QocsGG0YWpaVoR3HEA8BUQG2lAft246oEcS5qSIKoahoWoYMqgZuFOj6Loi4Q+LWG8uG4uQQHoQEOf6FBua+3nqG+R6nnBbjFCQBAH0BGQoVuBBOb1nm+aOyARBkNoidsc4gA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define which keys should be allowed in your shape:

```
type HasSufix<Key extends string> = `${Lowercase<Key>}Required`;

type Prefixes = 'USERS' | 'ORDERS' | 'BOOKS';

type SomeShape = {
  [Key in HasSufix<Prefixes>]: boolean;
}

const state: SomeShape = {
  UsersRequired: false, // error
  ordersRequired: false,
  booksRequired: false,
};
```

If you wouldn't define which keys are allowed, i.e. if you would replace `type Prefixes = 'USERS' | 'ORDERS' | 'BOOKS';` with `type Prefixes = string;` it would no longer work because the type `Lowercase<string>` equals `string` (as can be seen in the [original PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580) or in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwMoFcBmBLAHgHgNIQhQRbAQB2AJglAsAE4bkDmAfFALxQAGAJAN4AZAPYB3CPQDGiCPkKsAvgCUIARxQZ6EStwDcAKH2hIUAApbMWCDS4ByAKpIAokqS2oAHyi2A8koAiLm6e3gBCPj54bgZG4NBIwgC2EEgAFnAmXPz6UFAA2gRETLCIqJY45hCW1qwAugBcUABGwsIANhBw5AYKhpLC5HS0wHBkjQnJaRnQWTlQ9ggSCCrqmtqNaHBtiwA0c8L0lEsrGlqUG1u7cy3CANbLaqfrUJvbEHsKMcbQ-sLWAHLCYAAdQOt04UBE4ikMhwdEYLFYQA)), therefore also non-lowercase strings would be allowed as keys.