# How to discriminate union type by checking any object key in the union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type that looks like this.

```
type Focus =
    | { sidebar: true }
    | { tabbar: true }
    | { menu: string }
```

The whole point of this type structure is the convenience of being able to do things like `if (focus.sidebar)` or `if (focus.menu == "open")` so I don't want to rewrite my code as `if ("sidebar" in focus)` and `if ("menu" in focus && focus.menu === "open")`.

This type would technically work for me:

```
type Focus =
    | { sidebar: true; tabbar?: undefined; menu?: undefined }
    | { tabbar: true; sidebar?: undefined; menu?: undefined }
    | { menu: string; sidebar?: undefined; tabbar?: undefined }
```

But this is really inconvenient to write.

I've made it this far:

```
type PartialEmpty<T> = { [A in keyof T]?: undefined }

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never

type Focus2 = PartialEmpty<UnionToIntersection<Focus>>
// {
//     sidebar?: undefined;
//     tabbar?: undefined;
//     menu?: undefined;
// }
```

But I can't figure out how to intersect and distribute that type over the union... This is pretty close:

```
type Distribute<T> = T extends any ? Omit<T, keyof Focus2> & Focus2 : never

type Focus3 = Distribute<Focus>
```

But it doesn't quite work...

```
const focus: Focus3 = {} as any
if (focus.menu) {
    focus.m
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewMYFcDOMC8MDeM0CWAJlAEYCGATgFwwiUqwC+MAPrneaRTXQ82w4BbKADsUtNPQKiA5jCbBQkWAAUqIAuQA2AUSERwAHgAqAPiwcA2gEEYMmAGsoYBADMYJgLoB+WilESNxkoIgUlcGgYAFVRAgRREwQASVEQKEo0KCRNBKNoi2wACmiYKAAPdMCMclEwGB8YIsdaaIBKLAsANwRiGFpRKC6Mjoqqogwi4ABIFvtRNwyYZOAOzG7eohnGlemBoYyIlXhkdAAmS3VKTR19QzB8uISk1PTM7NzRI0RUNDMzI5RAAiBCklAIpBQ6VMhU8ZUqYgmMFq9UaAHkhAQQKYADROFzuE6-M4WABkRPO-Rgg2GlEBsB+6AAzJYQWCIVCoN9Tn8lEgElIYG5aIy0CzsDgWOQanVgAQPEU3AA6ETiDo4GbKoTARRAA)

Comment: Maybe try adding a field to discriminate between the types: `type Focus = { type: "sidebar", sidebar: true } | { type: "tabbar", tabbar: true } | { type: "menu", menu: string };`

Comment: Check out [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) utility typing library. It has this [`MergeExclusive`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/merge-exclusive.d.ts) type that does what you need, among other utility types. If you don't prefer installing it as devDependency, you can still reference how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` in `Distribute<T>` is one of:

```
| { sidebar: true }
| { tabbar: true }
| { menu: string }
```

So you need to omit `keyof T` from `Focus2` and intersect with `T`:

```
type Distribute<T> = T extends any ? Omit<Focus2, keyof T> & T : never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewMYFcDOMC8MDeM0CWAJlAEYCGATgFwwiUqwC%20MAPrneaRTXQ82w4BbKADsUtNPQKiA5jCbBQkWAAUqIAuQA2AUSERwAHgAqAPiwcA2gEEYMmAGsoYBADMYJgLoB%20WqKgANyhKBSVwaBgAVVECBFETBABJURAQtCgkTXijKItsAAoomCgADzTRIgxyUTAYHxgCx1oogEosC0CEYhh-IJD2soqqxuAASGb7UTcQmCTgdsxO7qJxhvmxvuDKcJV4ZHQAJkt1Sk0dfUMwXNj4xJS0ygysuNEjRFQ0MzNdyIARAhSSgEUgoNKmfKeErlMQjGp1BoAeSEBBA7wOaEOABonC53J4LAAyKFbEK-WAfdAAZksAKBILBUHRnx%20wCQ8SkMDctEpaBp2BwLHI1VqwAIHgKbgAdCJxO0cONpbKUMBFGKJdLCCQePLFVKtWQqKqgA)

Comment: That works! Any ideas how to make output type a bit cleaner? It's pretty hard to interpret: `Omit<PartialEmpty<{sidebar: true;} & {tabbar: true;} & {menu: string;}>, "sidebar"> & {sidebar: true;}`

Comment: You could use something like `type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/1113002 . And `type Focus3 = Expand<Distribute<Focus>>`