# How to add additional properties to a recursive type

Tags: typescript

Suppose one has a recursive type, `A`:

```js
type A = {
  id: number
  children?: { [k: string] : A }
}
```

So an example of `A` would be:

```js
const a: A = { id: 1, children: {
  foo: { id: 2, children: { 
    fizz: { id: 4 }
  } },
  bar: { id: 3, children: { ... } }
} }
```

The type of `a` is exactly `A`, so when referencing `a` elsewhere, there is no guidance as to what the children of all the nodes within `a` are.

To solve this, one can write a function that creates an object of `A`. It simply returns the provided `a` parameter value:

```js
const createA = <T extends A>(a: T): T => a
```

`createA` now solves the above limitation. One is now both provided with intellisense in how to create an `A` (as a parameter to `createA`), *and* the output of the function will have intellisense about the children of all the nodes within `a`. For example:

```js
const a = createA({ ... })
// (alias) createA<{ <-- The intellisense for a shows the children
//   id: number
//   children: {
//     foo: {
//       id: number
//       children: { ... }
//     }
//     ...
//   }
// }>)

const childNode = a.children.notFoo // <-- Fails linting, since a.children.notFoo is invalid

const anotherChildNode = a.childen. // <-- Intellisense shows 'foo' and 'bar' as available
```

Say we modify `createA` to add on a property, say `path`, to each node in the provided `a` (the implementation is irrelevant), resulting in the following output:

```js
    const createModifiedA = (a: A) => { ... } 
    // { id: 1, path: '', children: {
    //   foo: { id: 2, path: '/foo', children: { 
    //     fizz: { id: 4, path: '/foo/fizz' }
    //   } },
    //   bar: { id: 3, path: '/bar', children: { ... } }
    // } }
```

I am wondering if it is possible, and if so, how, one would achieve the same end result as `createA` but for `createModifiedA`, keeping the intellisense for the all the children within all the nodes in the provided `a`, I.e.:

```js
const modifiedA = createModifiedA({ ... })
// (alias) createModifiedA<{ <-- Intellisense for modifiedA still shows all the children
//   id: number
//   path: string
//   children: {
//     foo: {
//       id: number
//       path: string
//       children: { ... }
//     }
//     ...
//   }
// }>)

const childNode = a.children.notFoo // <-- Fails linting, since a.children.notFoo is invalid

const anotherChildNode = a.childen. // <-- Intellisense *still* shows 'foo' and 'bar' as available
```

**Edit 1 (sno2 answer)**

Clarification: `modifiedA` should have the intellisense just like `createaA` that shows the available children at each node.

**Edit 2**

Improved wording.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in `A` where `id` is `string` but I guess it's supposed to be `number`.   And should `children` be optional instead of required?  Could you make sure the code here is a [mre]?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMxqrN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?   Note, I hope before I answer you can [edit] your example so that the value of `a` really is an `A`.  So `id` should be `string` or `number`, and `children` should either be optional or `a` should include `children` everywhere, even in that nested `fizz` property.

Comment: Great, thank you.  So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMxqrN) work for you?  Let me know one way or the other so I only spend time writing up an answer if it actually addresses your issue.

Comment: @jcalz That works! Thank you so much! This was completely wracking my brains, and I suppose I can see why. The required typing that I can see one ends up needing seems quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `createModifiedA` will take a value of generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `A`, and return a value of type `ModifiedA<T>` for some suitable definition of `ModifiedA<T>`:

```
declare const createModifiedA:
  <T extends A>(a: T) => ModifiedA<T>;
```

We want `ModifiedA<T>` to add a string-valued `path` property to `T` and recursively to all the subproperties of `T`'s `children`.  Let's use the name `ModifiedAProps<T>` to refer to this recursive operation we want to apply to `children`.  Then `ModifiedA<T>` looks like:

```
type ModifiedA<T extends A> = { path: string } & { [K in keyof T]:
  K extends "children" ? ModifiedAProps<T[K]> : T[K]
}
```

You can see that we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `{path: string}` with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  That means `ModifiedA<T>` will definitely have a `path` property of type `string`.  And it will also have a property for every key that's in `T`.  If the property key's name is `"children"`, then we want to operate on it recursively with `ModifiedAPros`.  Otherwise we want to leave it alone.

So now we can define `ModifiedAProps<T>` like this:

```
type ModifiedAProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends A ? ModifiedA<T[K]> : T[K]
}
```

Here we are just making another mapped type where each property is mapped with `ModifiedA` if that property is of type `A`, and left alone otherwise.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const a = createModifiedA({
  id: 1, children: {
    foo: {
      id: 2, children: {
        fizz: { id: 4 }
      }
    },
    bar: { id: 3, children: {} }
  }
});

/* const a: ModifiedA<{
    id: number;
    children: {
        foo: {
            id: number;
            children: {
                fizz: {
                    id: number;
                };
            };
        };
        bar: {
            id: number;
            children: {};
        };
    };
}> */
```

Hmm, that type is `ModifiedA<T>` for the proper `T`, but it's not obvious that it evaluates to what we want.  Let's convince the compiler to expand the type definition out fully (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) and its answer for how this is implemented):

```
type X = ExpandRecursively<typeof a>;
/* type X = {
    path: string;
    id: number;
    children: {
        foo: {
            path: string;
            id: number;
            children: {
                fizz: {
                    path: string;
                    id: number;
                };
            };
        };
        bar: {
            path: string;
            id: number;
            children: {};
        };
    };
} */
```

Okay, great.  That looks exactly like the type of the object passed into `createModifiedA` except that every `A`-like value also has a `path: string` property in it.  And so the compiler knows the exact shape of `a`:

```
a.id // number
a.path // string
a.children.foo.children.fizz.path // string
a.children.baz.children // error, Property 'baz' does not exist on type
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCWATAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0aUAxgBYYA2WFE+A-HklANoBrPAGdgFDPgDmAXTxwAvikUoUWCHWYBDdvQD2+UfXabgEALK6sGAGYYIWGDloAeACpQIAD1P4sw2AB8ABSaeK4AlAgBUBZWtvYwbgEA3CqgkDGWNnYObh7eHH6BCMhQYCYMImISklDyUABkpXwA0pj4UAIQILrWUK6ytG1ePkUARIwsbBxjUJyZcTkwAAoUumDCbq3S0WHbSmng0LHZCavrm67RiLyt7Z3dvf2D6K7b+aP+cPMn8blvLR2UD2gIOKhQdH0hk0JToxlMvyWQVQ6GweAAjFR6ExWOx8DxaOhrLpdAT0OTMLgoAAmLGTXEcMkU8m2ABerJ4lLwABY6oTyYoKfIaBTSNpOWioABmOk46b45D1QV8+ThVIoAD0ACo9AZgFBQgtTrkUeTJUQyJRUhT6fKmcyoMTSch+Q7UVSLeQKNa3Ta5Xj7b7mWyOS6g+GuQQSF6fRGBbGg-IE0Lk+SxRRA77zdGra63baA4rU+gk-zS-JolqNSoNRr8uVfP5dKQAFbqfXpCD+dh0QgUYQYABuEGYIBQnagAFFPA2sAAldR9gfD0dJEruEaFJut9u0eYbgqN9rWShQADyc2abQkDx6fTPsinM80vgXvf7Q5HIGcZ+20XqeD4BAw4ULQYTqhOAAaJTTrOb5Lp+q6dk8mgpJqOpQSUproOUwCVFAojiFICbZpa3r8gWjJhm6TqZm6uH4YRNTFsypExnmDqUQq2Fxo6GDsnRvFlBUVREZILFxmxuZCSWEnxhxdQsemgnMgxonMQpFJSeRcZcTwpa+gZ8n1FWKiaAAdNgUC1lGZEoBZDHWXWTFSPZ5lceZTruf6HCefxrLmY5NkuZIbkeWKAVcU5HgUGs1BQOckAUKAUAAOQRalUBYLoXYELo+peBghj6FAnYoEAA)

Comment: Beautiful answer jcalz. Have you come across this before?

Comment: It gives an error: `createModifiedA is not defined`. @jcalz I believe the problem is with the `declare` keyword. Maybe you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new recursive type alias and intersecting to override the children to match the clauses you want:

```
type A = {
  id: string
  children: { [k: string] : A }
}

const createA = <T extends A>(a: T): T => a

type ModifiedA = A & { children: Record<string, ModifiedA & { path: string; }> }

const createModifiedA = (a: ModifiedA) => a;

const foo = createModifiedA({
    id: "asdf",
    children: {
        fizz: { id: "asdf", path: "ad", children: {} },
        bizz: { id: "asdf", path: "ad", children: {} },
        lizz: {
            id: "asdf",
            path: "ad",
            children: {
                mizz: {
                    id: "asdf2",
                    path: "hey",
                    children: {},
                }
            }
        },
    }
});

foo.children.fizz.path; // no error
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I have updated the question with some feedback. This was one of my attempts, but it doesn't achieve the desired result. Apologies if I wasn't clear enough!