# Typescript group an array of a discriminated union type into a record by a discriminator property

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm trying to write the typescript signature of a generic "groupBy" function that would "spread" a discriminated type union array into a record where each field of the record is a possible discriminator value and points to an array of objects of a concrete type from the union.

Example:

```
interface Dog {
  type: 'dog'
  dogMetadata: {}
}

interface Cat {
  type: 'cat'
  catMetadata: {}
}

type Animal = Dog | Cat

const animals: Animal[] = [{ type: 'dog', dogMetadata: {} }, { type: 'cat', catMetadata: {} }]
```

Each interface has a common discriminator property and no other common properties.

Here is simple "groupBy" signature that does not spread the type union values, forcing me to downcast the values of the record:

```
function groupBy<T, K extends string>(arr: T[], keyExtractor: (element: T) => K): Record<K, T[]>

const animalsByType: Record<'dog' | 'cat', Animal[]> = groupBy(animals, it => it.type)
const dogs: Dog[] = animalsByType['dog'] as Dog[]  // Must downcast Animal[] to Dog[]
```

How can I make a "groupBy" that is aware of the concrete types of the discriminated union type? I would want something like this:

```
const animalsByType: { dog: Dog[], cat: Cat[] } = groupBy(animals, it => it.type)
const dogs: Dog[] = animalsByType['dog']  // animalsByType.dog is known to be Dog[] by typescript
```

The implementation is easy, having trouble with the Typescript part :) I'm looking for a generic solution that doesn't make assumptions, like the name of the discriminator property or the amount of types in the type union.

**Follow-up question**

Would it be possible to make the same signature work when the union is nested inside another class?

```
interface Holder<T> {
  data: T
}

const animalHolders: Holder<Animal>[] = animals.map(data => ({ data }))

const dogHolders: Holder<Dog> = groupBy(animalHolders, it => it.data.type) // Any way of doing this?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeAoZZMATwAcIAuZAcgBMtqDl7MBZCMOWuTqnAXzyC8oSLEQoAwj1xMS5KtQQ9GhZWHaduvXIOHyUAQRDAAtnAA2yALxosyAD7JpYPHgToQAZzDI4J8wsvKmMzSwBtAF0bZHCcIjJKGhZqABpmLE0uHjg%20fmR%20dPiDRXU05HUs7VzdAsi3AHoG5ABJU1ILCFMIcCIAC2AvZC9gTBAeAFcoCDwYCZAEMGBPZEwodAnSACFiAB4AFXSAaWQIAA9IEFohnyhQTAA%20AAo4KCgqfaj0gGsIYgBRC5QRBgdDvZBPCCdbrgD4AShsD2QRzhVAAShAPFBaLsjulPpEkfhCGA%20usAO7IEAQSn-N5gp5woRuDzeXz%20MJBHb7RIxNYbbbEF4BSxedLAXzWJESgB0BiZrJ8GUwwTsmCiMQ5gS83MS4ToDGiTWQAAl0JTQchzL9%20oNkOSwd8APxuPBNd0ez1e70%2031%20-0BwN%20t3NABi6AsFnNAFpNiGgwnE0nk8m3KJoPAkKaI7RoAciUxqh9me5PEqtZYzRZc1BVVWa7tQoEHhrbBWgjLzKQntVERD4r3%20HCmaW2cr69A6zm8xhHnz1psdsLORPa%20LJdKwDLqnLEgjjWaLegrXAbaS7Q6oM6gA)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question...

Let's first create some utility types:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof O];
```

This extracts all the keys of `O` that point to a value of type `T`. This is going to be used to constrain the types of discriminant to those that are of `string` type. They're going to be used as keys in your output type so we're not really interested in allowing discriminants of other types.

Let's also add [`Expand<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/14357) to make our resulting types look nicer in intellisense.

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Now, let's create a type that represents the return-type of your `groupBy` function:

```
type Return<T, K extends KeysOfType<T, string>> = 
    { [KK in string & T[K]]: ({ [_ in K]: KK } & T)[] }
```

or, optionally, liberally apply the `Expand<T>` type above for nicer intellisense for the consumer:

```
type Return<T, K extends KeysOfType<T, string>> = 
    Expand<{ [KK in string & T[K]]: Expand<{ [_ in K]: KK } & T>[] }>
```

so now we can declare the function:

```
function groupBy<T, K extends KeysOfType<T, string>>(
    arr: T[], 
    keyExtractor: (element: T) => T[K]): Return<T, K>{
    throw Error();
}
```

and call it:

```
const groups = groupBy(animals, e => e.type)
```

for full type-safety, no matter which discriminator property is selected.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeAoZZMATwAcIAuZAcgBMtqDl7MBZCMOWuTqnAXzyC8oSLEQoAwj1xMS5KtQQ9GhZWHaduvXIOHyUAQRDAAtnAA2yALxosyAD7JpYPHgToQAZzDI4J8wsvKmMzSwBtAF0bZHCcIjJKGhZqABpmLE0uHjg+fmR+dPiDRXU05HUs7VzdAsi3A2QAaQhiLwB5GAAVRIAedvSugD4Y-EJwpuRQZABrVvQYZHbIqnaJ6IgAD0gQWi9kLuQAfmbkKhAIADdoAG4hcLniBaXIu7xGgFFN0n9aXuGYoctjs9lMQDBoEtjrhYpNpo9nstVusCmdkBdrlA3o0AEocACuUBA-3Sk2BEF2+xabU6PXIJOQPigoEwQxGti+P12vXiEzhIEZYGZIGwADIDusVshOb8ebEAPpg5pSpqTfLi4ZRApDNwwfEgBBgYCeZCYKDofGkABCxAZZO2FNB1I63T6XXSTJZbIAFHAoFAqF0oulHl8hYgwOgA8hvRALBBTBSwIGAJQ2EZBpqRFNUPFgQnE93NEZjIgAC3NAHdpf6o96U0I3B5vL4zRbSPtbG3LTbfQFLF50ihrCMIAA6AwNgD0U8IhAAekcm54fBlMJ3TebLV4xyw7jO58hF8uWxUeBvux2x+p97O58e3EA)

Comment: I updated the original question with a follow-up, if you're interested :)

Comment: This is super helpful, I think you're missing some brackets in return type to make the groups arrays: `Expand<{ [_ in K]: KK } & T>[]`

Comment: @ChrisPfohl You're absolutely right. If I'd actually bothered to implement the `groupBy`, this wouldn't have slipped through . Good catch. Question + playground link updated. ✅ Thanks.

Comment: So I implemented this the naive way, with a `reduce` here: https://ity.sh/KV (links to a TS playground forked from yours). It really doesn't like indexing `ReturnType<T, K>` by `T[K]`. Trying to figure out why that would be, because I'm pretty sure ReturnType _is_ keyed by T[K] there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly simple solution that uses the fact that conditional types distribute over unions to get rid of the non-matching alternatives:

```
type GroupBy<T extends Record<D, PropertyKey>, D extends keyof T> =
  {[K in T[D]]: T extends Record<D, K> ?  T[] : never}

declare function groupBy<T extends Record<D, PropertyKey>, D extends keyof T>
  (arr: T[], keyExtractor: (element: T) => T[D]): GroupBy<T, D>
```

It works for the original example, but also for other discriminating keys:

```
interface Orange { color: 'orange', juiceContent: number }
interface Banana { color: 'yellow', length: number}
type Fruit = Orange | Banana
const fruits: Fruit[] = [{color: 'orange', juiceContent: 250},{ color: 'yellow', length: 20}]
const fruitsByColor = groupBy(fruits, it => it.color)
const yellows = fruitsByColor.yellow
// const yellows: Banana[]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gEIgDwBUoQB7AQB2AJgM5QBKEAxgnCRgCIA0UACopHKANIQgAfGya4CxclADWAhADMoWQVAC8AWABQUKAG8A2rygBLIor1MAuhYBcisYVIVqdBsza9lAfm1Y9FqLZEEABuEHAAvpqaJLQANgCGcNBySEQ0wEYIpgDmiCjo2PYSTrT0jKwcXGF8AsJQovgOkjIg8oqCmtoAFIlwtr4WbC0AogRw8en0tl0QsRAAtsTA-QCUqsq+liu28MhomFgiHRqaJoRwchPQTAjZup1QoJC2AOQkty8P79kAshDA8RI8QBth0kQ04NORHOlxo0AAwsD7lpHuAIK8aMDPijMcA-gCgSDdODIRontAAIJEIzzeKxVT1W5QAA+UERwCiGjoRDIwCg8WptNiZFsVJpdL8DL0OlRzygbw+bG++MBwPioPCUHCbBl5IxWLYuJVhPVxK1Fk53N5-MFdLI6CwaIZuT26B6tuFbCMfJUym9ADpyStNFa+d8KCobeLhQ60f7vpoAPSJ7TaAB6nk5UJhVygAHlxkRstAZXRYlN5fQBcWXmwAFZIIxw+FZBzLKBEJDzABGYS12bCsOgqAFo90UDLFZeIFm5YA7rWoHMi8AABaBLu9iKaclQABicEbPvzheLLKgI6Io5DWWtckP3pF+4fwElkelk76ldPEEXDabEAttCSy2AATAArAADNqpYIOWX7TrOCALmwy7ZGuYHQRaXK3ny95HvaIAtvBzp5PsXT4Y+Xo+n6wD+p+wY4TyfIzrE84RlAlHAIRxH0P6rHzkmKaphmmhAA)

Comment: My use case is actually a bit more complex and I was able to adapt the other solution to better suit my needs, but this was very helpful to understand. Thank you!