# Construct type information from string via template literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to construct some type directly from the string provided?

I want to create a type something like shown below:

```
type MyConfiguration<T> = {
  items: T[];
  onChange: (updated: ConstructedType<T>) => void;
}

const conf: MyConfiguration = {
  items: ['id', 'nested.id', 'nested.name'],
  onChange: updated => {
    console.log(`You updated ${updated.nested.name}(id: ${updated.nested.id})`);
  },
};
```

So it will generate a type for `updated` to be `{id: string; nested: { id: string; name: string}}`

Comment: so `id` and `nested.id` etc. should be properties of `updated` of type `string`?

Comment: the `updated` should have generated a type of `{id: string; nested: { id: string; name: string}}`

Comment: You might want to edit the question to include that. Someone voted to close because of the lack of details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution might not be perfect but the type of `updated` seems to be correct:

```
type First<T extends string> = T extends `${infer L}.${string}` ? L : T
type Nested<T extends string> = T extends `${string}.${infer R}` ? R : string

type _ConstructedType<T extends string> = string extends Nested<T> ? string : {
  [Key in T as First<Nested<T>>]: _ConstructedType<Nested<T>>
}

type ConstructedType<K extends readonly string[]> = {
  [Key in K[number] as First<Key>]: _ConstructedType<Key>
}

function createConf<K extends readonly string[]>(conf: {items: K, onChange: (updated: ConstructedType<K>) => any}) {
    return conf
}

createConf({
  items: ['id', 'nested.id', 'nested.name'] as const,
  onChange: updated => {
    console.log(`You updated ${updated.nested.name}(id: ${updated.nested.id})`);
  },
})
```

In your question you specified that you want to have a `type` called `MyConfiguration`. A `type` alone cannot enforce any constraints between properties. So we have to create a factory function called `createConf`. We can now pass a `conf` object to `createConf` and all types are inferred.

A drawback that I don't know how to fix yet, is that you have to write `as const` behind the `items` array. Otherwise TypeScript will infer the type as `string[]` and not as a tuple.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgSwE4GcQB4AqMoA8RQB2AJijGkgoQOYB8MAvDNngSWQAYAkA3lQGZQkMADIBfAHS8KVamI4wA-KJgAuZqEiwAclDRRiWHPiKlyISjXpMWJ9jG48ZNSbwFCYAJXlKva85bUwJrQMAD6AMIA9oQUAK4AxgTEmFpGrKZkznSMAbLGbGa6+oaY9MrZ-jzAMDAA2gDSUGAwVMwwAIZkiKgYxclYtLQAuuqRMfFJBqnQ6P0Gg7TAYsHgodGxFonJM1DoDQWZMEhQHcQxADYt2XXD1jDVtY3NrYQwDXWEcQC2AEZCw063WQaH2zRGYw2kx2aSaYCWK2A-DihCSCBiMASJw6BA2-H2h3s2POhCueRot1oAAoEjF+Oo+ARvih1A0ADQwGIRAAWHRoUHUVLiEGIOIM6ihWymKVhtAAlIx6HywGIFY9ascoCA4kg3rTCPxlqstMw9CBcpKkNtpmk6gByQhmgwSBLchAXYgSQgdb5QO13YJY064ulU9UIJks+p2hDEO0ch1Oz2x+MwRMlL0+v2ArqYiYgNk1TmEHl86gCmDC0XJRUPIu1fUoKIXKASC5RahUjgATSicUrIrFxBgvCrQ69SczvrEVNj6lHg+SE4zsdVHDlAG4i2JC6qgA)

---

Thanks to @jcalz for this version which fixes the issues:

```
type ConstructedType<K extends string> = {
  [P in K as P extends `${infer L}.${string}` ? L : P]:
  [P] extends [`${string}.${infer R}`] ? ConstructedType<R> : string;
}

function createConf<K extends string>(conf:
  { items: readonly K[], onChange: (updated: ConstructedType<K>) => any }) {
  return conf
}

type Test = ConstructedType<'id' | 'nested.id' | 'nested.child.name'>

const x = createConf({
  items: ['id', 'nested.id', 'nested.name', 'nested.child.name'],
  onChange: updated => {
    console.log(`You updated ${updated.nested.name}(id: ${updated.nested.id})`);
  },
})
```

He also provided an [alternative solution](https://tsplay.dev/Nlvj5W).

Comment: Error in playground! Type `readonly string[]` is not assignable to type `string[]`. Change all your types to use `extends readonly string[]`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly oops, edited

Comment: To get around the `as const` too, you could use variadic arguments like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9EoMN). It's not the cleanest however.

Comment: This is great, but would it be possible to make it recursive? so `nested.child.name` would also work.

Comment: @Jeggy it is recursive but I must have made a mistake. Let me try to fix it

Comment: @Jeggy I made another mistake, its still not working correctly

Comment: You might want to change it to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w8o9pW) instead?  For what it's worth, [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nlvj5W) is probably how I'd have approached it although I do think key remapping is neater.

Comment: @jcalz nice solution. But I am confused. What is the use of the function where you put `CT1<K>` in the parameters and then `infer I` later? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I see a familiar `Exp` type in there... Anyways I think it's got something to do with naked types? Ah wait this looks like union to intersection!

Comment: `CT1<K>` only works for a single dotted key.  Then what I do is break `K` apart into its union constituents and compute the *intersection* of `CT1<K>` for all the `K` elements.  That is enough, but the type is ugly `Record<"a", Record<"b", string>> & `Record<"a", Record<"c", Record<"d", string>>>` so the `Exp` is `ExpandRecursively` from [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) to give `{a: {b: string, c: {d: string}}}`.