# Is it possible to recursively map one JSON-like type to another in typescript?

Tags: typescript, recursion

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsDsBcFMAesBcoCSByAtqWAnATwEtoBzPSUAY33gEMFR7QAzSfXAZ1kfjfyRc9aKEgAjAFbxqsAHSgAgmw65qI0AAt6AN35cAruIC07TlwA0oLlQCwAKBB5N8OqGJdrQ-nWoH8XMQwcg4OTuhauvwsrAbQskGisNqwoGTw0K58nmbcvEysgsKiMGJSMrBW4gapEerQmKnpqcn8kDUADjV4hB38AO4cANakZCGOYOisoITtoP0iLVRc8PzElc78sfGwiTQa4lvt0AAmWq7waJqwsB1cKCBk65pGctRCwEOMImT0ZsCZHjwE6mVRcYDiAA2EghABZ4ABOE7wABM9AAbABGWEozEAVgAHHiEfQCQBmcniBEAdmoKIADOiTmTxOiyQjMWT4LDWMAuPhqMAasRIVw5LAuABiAAyDMxYTAAD1iGRoBx+K00hlXMRqO4ki42HEEqVkdRIfR8IxElZ1phPGqWi43GZmNBCKA6PQbKJDoFkZ53tBYoEYKEJptPTJ-IE9Hh6EN4J4NKQuqkJNJZFYRGc6LB-NBkyVyrJ5s9mJDIWJppquPRsPxE4QuArQNVUidiKxWBc4KAdPRIQYk+MnK6kPWOpD4LbprMDGkou4nR4UA4gzwVJwAOLaq2wDjoaBp0AAXlAAG8HKAb6BoPXLpe2MR4JCTgAVXqPgBECGQ39AABfCxr1veh0jQC9n1fD8vzQb9oAMbBDnwADgNAm9ChfU57lAABtDDbyvexb1Iu8H0g6C30-Pp4L-WA0JAkiyJvcDHyg1gX2ouDQAQpCUMYwib3Q5ibwAXSYwCAG5wycdZ5naN8o3zfADVXdcYE3XIAGV8ngXdMn3DgAHlOm6c9iJve8G0gwjOJgmjH0aJBYEwJjSNcQQAjQPCJMIgch0fRDK3coDQrY2zRKo2DaNATBEOQ1w3MIzyOFw3zQpvALhzQYLIVAkTMPwbCTnSwjLLI6z2KE297O42LnOQZKoo8-AvPSvyWtvbKgoMEKasKsiIsvGrMK4mKnISlDmpYm9Uu8-DOtm-tBxyu8+vyrrAMI7bmLEhxdtbd9DR6zxIBrQ1U26DMKmYNwYEhD1B2hfpgUoNsNRcFZeMUfAyAA2AvzFUBjq2Y1dlKbB6DuVsGGoTQfr+gGv3elhvwAMXG5G+lHSZQChjolD+zwD1ATGYM8AxAnISNvzqiaAI6QQ+nwQG13sBxSAQfBWHoah+HfFzfooCr6ccuiXO-GT7EO+wudcXn+dAAA5fjXGFkbmLFni+MS1Dpdl+Web5-htNfCoNdF8bxd4lZp1kKWDvDI3Ff4AAhSBIGnERLdA7XYu-cRPe96BHZl524AVk3QAAET4X2tetnjMBOPhMAN8NAb6ImKHPQXkA1gAfFW1fwIvQDN+3YHLj2vYYaBhelznI+NpX89gcmlIqnq0B4YryGlua2rS3uCFGXyM45uWW9dku9c7s5u9W3q9cH0B5twvvx7Eyfm+52fK4qBfNay5e0BEQg14tQ5IVH-uyDXje7+33fp-36Pa5D4+l8CtAg7rkQj9h4LS3uQCeTsp4u2jnHBA39QI93WqvUCT9FqvygUrYW75IALwALLQxPngFyaB24LzXlNVwaBVbz3GmvO2FQ0CH1kKQ0C-8Q5oE-vXZhzFU4IDQDA+AXDZZOG0lQNU-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-KYmCFiGO0tAGgTAxBQPZJloPDShYElMuCf615BGP1kdAlVSiUqJb-gNaxCC2qHI62VbKzC6qFmvgUzq78dD9WDSNSas1BmNMB1YTalT1gjD9rKlFCqpEuDzPgFAaE+BLP1WlZLOzwlMoENc+5zzHAfMTSUwxALdn9oy3tfEwprZVGEAYAjfj6z+gpCHZEDofRoCJtPd0jokAuYAEIJH1EmfAPQohI3WAyN9BpmoN7nDoOzExI6siHOkxm0pTSgVuqTZ2-D0ZCPwDMd6-lEnibCqk2Nj9gagA)

I have a function called [genWizardDefaultState](https://github.com/katangafor/nested-forms/blob/b4e9de2a614215859a8383b97c206d3b63913e4f/src/utils.ts#L201) which is used to generate a default state for a form. It's recursive so that it can support nested forms. I'm trying to make a recursive generic type so that the function actually returns a useful, typed output.

The function itself takes a JSON-like object whose values can only be *Args*, and returns an object of the same structure whose values are *Fields*. Args are defined like this:

```
interface TextArg {
    fieldType: "text";
}

interface NumberArg {
    fieldType: "number";
}

interface SelectArg {
    fieldType: "select";
}

type Arg = TextArg | NumberArg | SelectArg;
```

And Fields are defined like this:

```
interface TextField {
    value: string;
    errors: string[];
}

interface NumberField {
    value: number;
    errors: string[];
}

interface SelectField {
    value: any;
    label: string;
    errors: string[];
}
```

The more general *Field* type is generic: it takes an Arg and returns a specific Field based on the fieldType property:

```
interface ArgToFieldMap {
    text: TextField;
    number: NumberField;
    select: SelectField;
    boolean: BooleanField;
    date: DateField;
}
type Field<T extends Arg> = ArgToFieldMap[T["fieldType"]];
```

This works for flat object inputs (as long as I use as const assertion on the input type, so that typescript actually infers fieldType to be the string literal instead of just string):

```
type FormFields<T extends Record<keyof T, Arg>> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: Field<T[Key]>;
};
```

For example, this snippet does return the right type!

```
const exampleArgsObject = {
    name: { fieldType: "text" }, 
    age: { fieldType: "number" }, 
    favoriteTowel: { fieldType: "select" },
    } as const;
type formStateType = FormFields<typeof exampleArgsObject>;
```

But I'm hitting a wall when it comes to making this type recursive. I think I need to:

1. Tell FormFields that the properties of its input type are either `Arg` or `Array<FormField>`.
2. Use a conditional type as the the mapped output properties, to distinguish between `Arg` and `Array<FormField>` input properties

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
type FormFieldsRecursive<T extends Record<keyof T, Arg | Array<FormFieldsRecursive<T>>>> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Arg ? Field<T[Key]> : 'idk what goes here'
};
```

Any idea what I should be returning instead of "idk what goes here"?
I know it should be some kind of generic type that returns an array of something, but I'm getting really confused. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible!

Comment: Please check if it works for you. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/wggJ0w)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYk8dN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  ... oh I see @captain-yossarianfromUkraine got here first, never mind (unless there's some meaningful difference between our approaches that is)

Comment: @jcalz that approach looks great! I can't totally understand it, so a full answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the approach in the top comment also work for you?  I don't like to step on toes if I can help it, so if that one meets your needs then maybe @captain-yossarianfromUkraine would like to write an answer.  If there's an issue or if he declines then I am happy to do it.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine your approach _looks_ good, but when I try it with a [test object](https://shorturl.at/qzH47), it looks like the output type has Arg properties rather than Field properties (though I don't really understand how that's happening)

Comment: Either way @jcalz, I’d love to get an explanation of your solution since it looks like it uses mutually recursive types, which is super interesting

Comment: All right, I'll work on writing up an answer when I get a chance. Might be a little while though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's dispense with the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `FormFields<T>` of the form `T extends Record<keyof T, Arg | Array<FormFieldsRecursive<T>>>`.

That version doesn't work because `FormFieldsRecursive<T>` is the *output* of your type transformation.  If you we really want to give the *input* a name, it could look something like this:

```
type ArgsObj = { [k: string]: Arg | ReadonlyArray<ArgsObj> };
```

Here I'm saying that an `ArgsObj` has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) so we don't care about its keys.  (This will actually fail to match interfaces without explicit index signatures, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)).  And then the properties are either `Arg` or an array of `ArgsObj` elements.  Well, a [read-only array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), since you are using [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and those produce read-only arrays.  Regular arrays are subtypes of readonly arrays, so this doesn't limit anything.

So we can, if we want, define `type FormFields<T extends ArgsObj> = ...` so that you can't pass in a "bad" `T`.

But I'm not going to bother.  It only makes things more complicated.  If you actually have functions somewhere that need to be sure a type is of the `ArgsObj` type, you can put the constraint there.

---

Okay, so how can we write `FormFields<T>` in such a way as to work recursively?  I find the following approach where we break the operation up into two types to be easiest. One type, `FormFields<T>`, maps the entire object type, while `FormField<T>` will map a single property of that object type. At its core, it looks like this:

```
type FormFields<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormField<T[K]>
}

type FormField<T> =
  T extends Arg ? Field<T> : { [I in keyof T]: FormFields<T[I]> };
```

So `FormFields<T>` is a simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which maps each property of `T` with `FormField<>`.  And `FormField<T>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks to see if the property is an `Arg`.  If so, it does `Field<T>` as before.  If not, then we know it must be an array type holding types appropriate for `FormFields<>`, in which case we use the support for [mapping arrays/tuples to arrays/tuples with mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to turn each element of `T` at numeric-like index `I` to `FormFields<T[I]>`.

We can check that this works:

```
const exampleArgsObjectRecursive = {
  name: { fieldType: "text" },
  age: { fieldType: "number" },
  favTowel: { fieldType: "select" },
  likesKanye: { fieldType: "boolean" },
  subForms: [
    {
      shoeColor: { fieldType: "text" },
    },
    {
      shoeColor: { fieldType: "text" },
    },
  ]
} as const;

type GeneratedRecursiveExampleFieldsType = FormFields<typeof exampleArgsObjectRecursive>;
/* type GeneratedRecursiveExampleFieldsType = {
  readonly name: TextField;
  readonly age: NumberField;
  readonly favTowel: SelectField;
  readonly likesKanye: BooleanField;
  readonly subForms: readonly [FormFields<{
      readonly shoeColor: {
          readonly fieldType: "text";
      };
  }>, FormFields<{
      readonly shoeColor: {
          readonly fieldType: "text";
      };
  }>];
 } */
```

So that looks good, except that the type display leaves things in terms of `FormFields<>`.  If we want the compiler to actually expand out the type fully, we can use the approach [shown in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) of taking the mapped type and doing an extra `infer` and mapped type.  The general form is we take a type `XXX` and convert it to `XXX extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never`.  Like this:

```
type FormFields<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormField<T[K]>
} extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

And now we get

```
type GeneratedRecursiveExampleFieldsType = FormFields<typeof exampleArgsObjectRecursive>;
/* type GeneratedRecursiveExampleFieldsType = {
     readonly name: TextField;
     readonly age: NumberField;
     readonly favTowel: SelectField;
     readonly likesKanye: BooleanField;
     readonly subForms: readonly [{
         readonly shoeColor: TextField;
     }, {
         readonly shoeColor: TextField;
     }];
} */
```

As desired!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFFJICWwALhAE4BmCyAKhAB5UCCtA5nqWST1yEDABNmATxgQAXEgBENDgoDcAgL4lCZSjQZMkAOQCuYAEZ1ufAjsHDRE6XMXAzl2ms3bd1Oo0QkAGVRCHguXn47MgdxKRl5BShQ8K87LWI7PX9DACEAe3yMCBBgayjBIRE450TzQuLStLIMgWyDQIAREBpy20rYpwSkAHIxHogR9XSfJCpnJHKAXiRWDnKAH2N3K0itkOLwzaQCopKy3mm2vw6WdioAMWqxCsEAN0wTFygqWkoeaaVOi0fK0KDyH5-YA8ADaAF1AUhWlkbgFkKYLHQno5XmQPhgvvI3JjaIiyMDQeCkJD-vDEcjfPo0cEUo9nrikPjCUhSpIyUgMCBLBgIb9-vyKWDRVDYQjvJlGTlAqdGsBseIOVyXPUzqUJbQQVLqWLoXT5dcmYZujR1S9+u9Pi5iR59YaqWaZgqKKjDNZmPlbQBZEAwDnKKjyNZsxz8510eQYjy2-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-JCeJ2hSaO8nTouzGubeuECpYpAZqofkuIAcUfOhj1W9bNogXiZMi0SVjRyLr0kpDiPmiBFo05bpbBWXX35GsACpQqQcXgElmgxH1ja+3lrXFYWSiquXEALOAKz3P21Z7irYH3c973rpcISA8qIPLMkd63k+76M2WiPBCjr2Y9B8HIeASQXALUpk7IVPveR1HwqpIuY5hFWRuvbGcYr6l8aJjASfpunC-M6OYaGFwKZUfkcdcqqNFfc7MqG1W68Dzu08bpnm9bqf24b37e9OgfgaHt6R4gzekBNmtZmRWY9s8q1yFgQUY+C4titKxxRoqtuEqSlK0oy6vHFvBK8v5h86u9PQOgSAACqSAmrtUSl1N+SEQEZRAT-JESAiQQD7KSWYSkFif3ENFSqb07z-2fLOPgTVsqtTwLpTqM4YGrA-vfcQo0OoTS3iFIWc0BI6z1mEGWW1XZvVPmzWGa9KY8xxqHQRPdEgMSpjjRgcdWwJzumTP6qZloyOBhnaAWcc4SOOgoeGTRRHAxLmjDG1M26VEZszFurMKGr0SJzF63MnHmKXoIKxC9bFKPZn9RxtNB7+MEHzYsGgBZCxFgsS21sIC224QbB2fEBLOwXMrehz41bOCkprDhvA1JLXCHbQ2xszZiwlrZG2hSEkKxGkrCxHcPZdwEX7DgBdI4zxDjdBMclWkp3aTHOR8cRSJ3CD0+pwd05gy0VDfMDRCzPA3r0hps8TFl3kA3GEbjp5LOLk3FmkZ-bzO5hdOpWzxlz2sa3KMoykS70EKEg+R9tACFPrAQwRNCK2UoDE9s9AACa+QTAAHVShBRCnfCeNcCEcEfEQnWT8p4v2gT1d+A00nf1yvlEJNUYWbkoEA2goDwEUMRdQ5FsD4GINCSgtBqgkBQWvAAWgZchC+SBzDkFHKyjSJhZpUEbGACcyBhxCoWGIC+cE7JNnIIgWgGDzbYLELgqqULaqwsas1L+5VkFVXalQ7qvVaGoohQ-a8vFfgICoN-caY84UuSmnS+s2T4JSWFTyeoW1MK0GwtCXCxY2FOu1rkpyy1to4yad4oRDiREuLEZ0uxyje7SKMQMD6CihkRskYoVRqRk2CE0RDaZ8afG9wMcAdRLQwkER+Pa8FYAghUAmLUhVUV1bsIWkG-JVAjYhVNvK8K9bG0uzqQ3JpVzDnmIbuI7YJJRkr1TV9IZBwk7juXn0gUkyC3Z1zrM-OK67n70PpkVhVaiKJPbTwPJusClxPtsgPhYaPK6I5tGwJZAp0Zr0UmmNwMBlpqfSogGuaQYbu0dDexihS3lvcSjUx8gYTc02eczx-7hEqCA3c19ghEMeL2UWyNJ0X3OMw8EyooTdyCxPTWyJZSpY3tlo7JJNSh3NoyTILJZ7A0XuDdeta8SIDduLL20pVtykxMqXLDjyS73DrXaOg5MZuaTrjeHPd9c12-oXfIJdIzVOnK7vm0DMzdRql0207ZMcVlDXLmujZRzFlnJwzY-ZLTTMYZOfZrujnLnyfEAsm5tKHmeiIBkIAA)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic write up!! Extra thanks for being so thorough, stepping through your thought process and including all of these links. This is amazing, I'll be coming back to this for a while