# How to expand TypeScript unions in intellisense?

Tags: typescript

Let's say these are the basic types I'm working with:

```js
type MyUnion = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type MyType = {myKey: MyUnion}
```

Hovering over `MyType` doesn't expand `MyUnion`:

[image]

So I created a helper type that recursively *expands* deeply nested types:

```js
type Expand<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
} & {}
```

Let me show you `Expand` in action. Here's some types I'll play around with:

```js
type SomeObj = {
  a: number,
  b: string
}
type TopLevel = {c: SomeObj}
type TopLevelExpanded = Expand<TopLevel>
```

Hovering over `TopLevel` shows the "before":

[image]

And hovering over `TopLevelExpanded` shows the "after", with the nested types *expanded*:

[image]

Putting it all together, I had hoped that using this `Expand` type helper would also expand *unions*, but it doesn't:

[image]

Is there a way in TypeScript to expand union types in Intellisense when hovering? I can't figure out what's wrong with my `Expand` helper type.

Comment: A union type isn’t an object so your `Expand` utility function wouldn’t work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get helpful intellisense when using a type alias for a string union type as a property of an object or interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588194/how-to-get-helpful-intellisense-when-using-a-type-alias-for-a-string-union-type)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/WKpoDw) of a technique I've used for expanding unions. If that's satisfactory as an answer to your question, I can write it up as one. If not, can you update the question to explain what it doesn't address?

Comment: @vr. That's the same question I'm asking! And that solution seems to work if you hover over individual destructured arguments, not the object type itself. I'm trying to see the union expanded why I hover over the object type itself.

Comment: @jsejcksn As soon as I [put the type in an object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgjFAvFA1hEB7AZlAEgFQFkAZAUQBsIBbCAO2HwEMBzAOUZsMbAG4AoKIID0QgHoB+PiKiBeDcAke3z4BjDLQDOwKAFdaASwCOWiAGUQVJFFNUARhnIAKAJT9QkWACYLpAB5LyWgBMIAB40TBwCEgpqOgYWdk5uABooVwhsbT1DEzMAPn5BKBEJKSEoQD4NwEpdxTSoAHlrACsLAG8BYTFJQsYALg8+AF8+IA), the expanded union goes away :(