# Generic index signature only for specific sub types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Every of our database tables has an identifier (id) and version. Which means every concrete Entity extends from the Entity interface in order to have those two attributes.

```
interface Entity {
  id: number;
  version: number;
}
```

Here is a multi-level entity for example purposes.

```
interface Address extends Entity {
    street: string;
    hno: string;
    zip: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
}

interface Department extends Entity {
    name: string;
}

interface User extends Entity {
    name: string;
    birthday: string;
    address: Address;
    department: Department;
}
```

Now I want a generic type which replaces all appearances of id and version (even the fields in the sub-objects) into optional. Which means from

```
User {
    dbid: number;
    version: number;
    name: string;
    birthday: string;
    address: {
        dbid: number;
        version: number;
        street: string;
        hno: string;
        zip: string;
        city: string;
        country: string;
    };
    department: {
        dbid: number;
        version: number;
        name: string;
    };
}
```

into

```
User {
    dbid?: number;
    version?: number;
    name: string;
    birthday: string;
    address: {
        dbid?: number;
        version?: number;
        street: string;
        hno: string;
        zip: string;
        city: string;
        country: string;
    };
    department: {
        dbid?: number;
        version?: number;
        name: string;
    };
}
```

As I said as a generic type, because I have a lot of different entities where I want to perform the same.

Something like

```
export type NewEntity<T extends Entity> = {
  // remove id and version fields
  [K in keyof Omit<T, 'dbid' | 'version'>]: T[K] extends Entity ? NewEntity<T[K]> : T[K];
};
```

but this removes only the two attributes but lacks the redefinition of

```
id?: number;
version?: number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a *recursive* generic type like this one:

```
type NewEntity<T extends Entity> = ({
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof Entity ? never : K]: 
    T[K] extends Entity 
      ? NewEntity<T[K]> 
      : T[K]
} & {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, keyof Entity>]?: T[K]
}) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
```

It creates an *intersection* of two [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

The first one is including all properties which are *not* in `Entity` (`id` and `version`). If a property type `T[K]` extends `Entity`, we can call the type `NewEntity` recursively with it.

The second type includes the properties of `T` which are also in `Entity`. Those are made *optional*.

The `extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never` is only for aesthetic reasons and makes the resulting type readable. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type) for more information)

---

Here is the result:

```
type NewUser = NewEntity<User>

// type NewUser = {
//     name: string;
//     birthday: string;
//     address: {
//         street: string;
//         hno: string;
//         zip: string;
//         city: string;
//         country: string;
//         id?: number | undefined;
//         version?: number | undefined;
//     };
//     department: {
//         name: string;
//         id?: number | undefined;
//         version?: number | undefined;
//     };
//     id?: number | undefined;
//     version?: number | undefined;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbkOQDdoBnYAexAuvpN8AX3z5QkWIhQBBEiSgQOHZBAAekECRXowmHASJEOYRRDAUTUUAHNmR5AAsQ3APyXTt+0YBewAA4e1iB2LEQI+kFeYcgI3FTgUFhRIcyi4uDQ8EjIACIQ-nBQYDQQ4KoaZdpoGNh4MSBwpSmh6RJZ0sgAqhzQFZrVuvr1Do3NyFbRDnTAxY4kcMkTnqkxcPKKyhRyCkoc3kQkBUUlZRZ5x8Wl4Gli+Nj+KAByEADuQ9gAPAAq-VU6tSwAD5kABeZAACkMyAA2gBpYggZAAawgWG4MGQvzgKgR6gGKlR6MxHxwrkoEHYUGQFDhAF0KDFvvC6X8tAC9HUYkRyS93oCfiyQdyaViWSJkAAyEawhGgNAaKCIMCfIkYrEAGhRaPVpKBdPcYvpIgAlGzqqAYH0APLIcm4WWI7XE5DWhmulnIYSikCU6B3B7PN49Prgvmkz4hqBA-AAeljyEDyD5UbB9XjDkoTQgLWYGemszA80WubjCYc612W3T5czxlMEHMpfzdacLmbtbrfkCy2CoRbdYi2A7rfC8USS0mqwHmdIhoEDGpAB9kAkjjBQBASHnO5mqVxePPaIvkCu1xAN77t2XM8Id5mjoUrmcKAQZ6NsyPR3P+Me+metAvTdr3fIx9x4EAj0EZdV0Ay8t3vBw7xvBwf0oP8YPPeCQN3cDD1-aDT1g9dgPvYQgA)

Comment: But what if e.g. address.hno is optional in the base interface: hno?: string; In NewEntity<User> it will be hno: string | undefined but not hno?: string | undefined. Is there a generic way for adopting the exact same type in this case?

Comment: @user2622344 - good point :) I edited my answer.