# View / print end result of union type in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```js
type A = {
    a: string
}

type B = {
    b: string
}

type C = A & B
```

When I hover over `C` I get

[image]

How can I see the end result literal, ie how can I see something like this

[image]

Additionally even if the type C has thousands of properties I want to see all of them. VSCode's Intelli Sense often hides all those extra properties behind `... 27 more ...;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type)

Comment: You could do something like this: `type C = Readonly<A & B>;`

Comment: What if both types contain a member variable called `a` for instance? What do you expect to be shown then?

Comment: @TobiasS. the Expand generic helps but it's not great for large types as it just says `... 27 more ...;` over a certain threshold

Comment: Quick tip if you want to see the "thousands" of properties. You can kinda mimic this by using another type, `type X = C[""]`, and trigger intellisense inside the quotes. You'll be able to browse the properties there and see their types (if it's small enough).