# Get the type info of hovering cursor in Typescript Playground

Tags: typescript-compiler-api, typescript-playground

When I hover my cursor over a Typescript type in Playground, its type info is displayed correctly.
This suggests that the compiler parses the source codes correctly and generates my desired output.
However, .D.TS does not get (display) the same full expanded Typescript type info.
How to get (or generate) the same type info displayed by a cursor hover in Playground?
Do the Typescript compiler has an option to get (or generate) the same type info?

e.g.

```
type SecondArg<F> = F extends (a: any, b: infer B) => any ? B : never
// Get the type of Array.slice
type F = typeof Array['prototype']['slice']
type A = SecondArg<F> // number | undefined
```

.D.TS show:

```
declare type A = SecondArg<F>;
```

My desired output is:

```
declare type A = number | undefined;
```

I tried this, but it does not get the full expanded Typescript type info in .D.TS.

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
type ExpandedA = Expand<A>;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGB7AdgEwIICcDmAeAYgHxQC8U+UEAHsBGgM5QAUAhgFxQvIgA0UARhwCWyAGYRMUAEIBKUsS4goAfmlQOyCADcJAWABQAekNQA4hGBRgAC2ihIURKKhZMLEADp6AGyHwIBvbQFGRBTi6YbiAA2gDkYJiIwEngELEAunE+fmnpgakupLAIKBg4BMQGBsbWwMBg9GzG9MAs8ADWiDqYot6IAO4eSAC2hgCOAK4QLUIo9IYArADsAGwAHADMGwAMG4bWAwC08FyHQof0EBCHNteiE97eh9RgXKgQqMcowG7wwIdOQ4sG6pejwTBCMD-IL5BwAUSorzQuAAKsQyCjKDQ6KhGCJxJIAPIqKAAbyg0QA0lARFB2hAQOFCekOISqekoABfdRQTTdADcsOgCKR7wwRRFb1w6EI-KAA

Please note that this is a follow up question of:
[Get the full expanded Typescript type info in Typescript Playground .D.TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74073919/get-the-full-expanded-typescript-type-info-in-typescript-playground-d-ts)