# Flatten down a object type

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I would like to flatten down an object. This works well on the js side, but ts is a bit tricky to convert the object correctly.

I created a js method which converts a objects like this:

```js
const from = {
  red: '#red-val',
  green: {
  200: '#green-200-val',
  300: '#green-300-val',
     DEFAULT: '#green-default-val',
  },
}
```

to this:

```js
const to = {
  red: '#red-val',
  green: '#green-default-val',
  'green-200': '#green-200-val',
  'green-300': '#green-300-val',
}
```

On the js side, this works fine, but obviously Typescript doesn't understand this conversion, which is why I need to create a custom type for it.

So I created a couple of generic types, which are a bit hacky, but seems to work at first glance.

```js
type HEX_VAL = `#${string}`;

type Props = {
  [K in string]:
    | HEX_VAL
    | {
        [IK in string]: HEX_VAL;
      };
};

type ConvertChildKey<K extends string, P extends string> = K extends 'DEFAULT'
  ? P
  : `${P}-${K}`;

type FlatColorKeys<P extends Props> = {
  [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends Props
    ? //@ts-ignore
      ConvertChildKey<keyof P[K], K extends string ? K : never>
    : K;
}[keyof P];

type FlatColorsSettingsT<T extends Props> = Record<FlatColorKeys<T>, HEX_VAL>;
```

**But here is the problem:**

```js
// this works fine. Hovering over this type, shows the correct result.
type ExampleConversion = FlatColorsSettingsT<{
  red: '#red-val';
  green: {
    200: '#green-200-val';
    300: '#green-300-val';
    DEFAULT: '#default-color';
  };
  blue: {
    300: '#sddsf';
  };
}>;

// does not work fine. Hovering over this const just shows the generic type and not the result of it.
const ExampleMethodConversion = flatColorsSettings({
  red: '#red-val',
  green: {
    200: '#green-200-val',
    300: '#green-300-val',
  },
});
```

Link to [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgogDQPoDUCCAZKBeKADAYgBIBvAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfPAbgCg3RIoAFSgezBkcUEmyhQA2gGkodKBRoMAugC5xEqAB9YiVJg0SdYzaakBJWfMV16a3cnQZ2ZqI3buOXaAGF+tADcISmAfAAtqABsAE2kIEAAeWQgAD2AIWmjhGwYAGl4oVPTM7KpbAD4RZLSMrKgAcgAROAAxNABVDAAVeo0Afl4NVXxSHkYAWlJpZnZOcGgWyIBDUP5I-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-TDJ-WKMmCah5S07glkyKAVo06BLI61THmoWyTtNBynJciAu35PTonc4JPKuXAzwjPzoydYCNGCzKIqi8jYvi2ghtMfKKpxvL0sKyJ6ixiRqsJnLaHGarSfJjQSzYKiWCAA). It includes also the js part.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result? And to get the converted type and not the generic type when executing the method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one more case where the tooling surrounding TypeScript is *lazy* and does not show the fully expanded type. The output type is correct, but not really useful to a human reader. We can resolve this problem by using the [`Expand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/8613630) utility type which forces a re-evaluation of the object type.

```
type FlatColorsSettingsT<T extends Props> = Record<FlatColorKeys<T>, HEX_VAL>;
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

export const flatColorsSettings = <P extends Props>(
  colors: P
): Expand<FlatColorsSettingsT<P>> =>
  Object.assign(
    /* ... */
  );
```

Which leads to a readable type hint.

```
const ExampleMethodConversion = flatColorsSettings({ /* ... */ });

/*
const ExampleMethodConversion: {
    red: `#${string}`;
    "green-200": `#${string}`;
    "green-300": `#${string}`;
}
*/
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgogDQPoDUCCAZKBeKADAYgBIBvAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfPAbgCg3RIoAFSgezBkcUEmyhQA2gGkodKBRoMAugC5xEqAB9YiVJg0SdYzaakBJWfMV16a3cnQZ2ZqI3buOXaAGF+tADcISmAfAAtqABsAE2kIEAAeWQgAD2AIWmjhGwYAGl4oVPTM7KpbAD4RZLSMrKgAcgAROAAxNABVDAAVeo0Afl4NVXxSHkYAWlJpZnZOcGgWyIBDUP5I-ko4kDIEnkKakt4BIUrcEykrWigAa3j+ADNeex4ZZX3iur5BMkMoAYB6f4AAWAZHG1HotA2EF+Ej8gWCoQiMS2CVuIAevFe+WqH1KSnofygsmGtAgQUo5V+w2kHkk6MxPGUs28UEWKz860oZAAyhBgMBbGQugkuu9asIvicRAAlCAAYw20QS7NWXK2Oy65Xy8EcmHK7FZcBSYCWmVFpygYqKErktHuwSgAHkiSQLnabndHk77E7Xm4oKTycFZqkwBtgFBFbQKFB7ss1RtefzBQxhLhduLDlKyOUABQaRVcsjDHhsACUw2NpvNqs5Sb5AqFIp45VOVIkToARgArBXAAB0SzIZAhtALphIjFyvwHc+7fflg4yZQgZDzRaTfwGU-LA-jKwAskswHm85JN5R8gElpEAK5r5TlnAdszeTE3+9rnC4er8Xv9r0rgSAMC79gOK40GueYHom3KNqm9Drp+D5kOWe4ALYnhOwGmOel5bPkYSpCgt5Pi+UB5ucuGmBeawbFAADUlEEfEP6-s0bSdD0RL1PUgb4JMJCsSAzDlvYxEpKRkQzjRmiMOWsJmIpuHDJIbqSHgpCXsw9god+jDKL8KlQOWsxsICUDABEwgAO4bNcwj3HQEADrA-AUrYUAeY61nUMI3j5GQYT8LZAXEVGGyUP2UDRWQd6RIOczcMaSwYWAkQQPCFKjv4Ih1vR8Eps2CTnNF0TDPUBDleMn71C4UD0NFGTDNRUAAEwAAydZVBBNRAGTjF1nW1be9W-AAzN1vX9YNU0jXVDUSJxHTdL10QQPcSwJcA4yXuNEieBIXZfq1k3TQ0BBkNEWT3AdbgeAaHCWdE-DflCkb2ZQ1xxi5bkwD5BLeRSVk2ZFMaRj2d6xsFoXhdA9AZME1DylZ8xQGa0RQB9oPQHFO3eY81BJdGsapelmWHvyIXRNlwS5VcuCwfWRVNmmVEaOVvU1XVsmNc1tBnaYw0zQLQ3daNkT1HzEjzaLA20OM82S9LGjTmwCksEAA)