# What are the technical differences between these two methods of "resolving" an intersection type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

As in the title.
"Resolving" as in converting `{ a: string } & { b: string }` to `{ a: string, b: string }`.

This is @jcalz's one, from [his answer to "How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type/57683652#57683652):

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

And this is his summary:

> Those use conditional type inference to "copy" a type T into a new type variable O and then an identity-like mapped type which iterates through the copied type's properties.
>
> The conditional type inference is conceptually a no-op, but it's used to distribute union types and to force the compiler to evaluate the "true" branch of the conditional (if you redefine `Expand<T>` without it, sometimes the compiler will just output the mapped type `{[K in keyof RelevantType]: RelevantType[K]}`, which is not what you want to see).

And this is the one Gabriel Vergnaud uses in his Type-Level Typescript workshop:

```
/**
 * Compute is a helper converting intersections of objects into
 * flat, plain object types.
 */
type Compute<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown
```

As to the methods of the types, @jcalz's one uses the conditional type inference to force the evaluation of the type, while Gabriel's one uses an intersection with `unknown`.

EDIT

To clarify:
What are the technical differences in the output of these two methods?
And are there any cases where their output will differ?

Bonus points for info on things like performance.