# Typescript create a type from generic nested keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I'm teaching myself how to use typescript generics by recreating a CSS class builder function similar to the CVA library. However, I'm stuck with how to extract keys out of the generic. I have the below code (simplified for brevity):

```
type TConfig = {
    base?: string;
    variants?: Record<string, Record<string, string>>;
};

type TInput<T extends TConfig> = Record<keyof T["variants"], string>;

export const classBuilder = <T extends TConfig>(config: T) => {
    ///...
    return (input: TInput<T>) => {
        // return ...
    };
};

const builder = classBuilder({
    base: "text-white rounded-sm",
    variants: {
        color: {
            red: "bg-red",
            blue: "bg-blue",
        },
        size: {
            sm: "text-sm",
            lg: "text-lg",
        },
    },
});

// this should then take an object using the variant keys provided in the config
const classes = builder({ color: "blue", size: "sm" })
```

I'm expecting the type of the return function to be:

```
const builder: (input: {
    color: string;
    size: string;
}) => string
```

However when hovering over the builder function in VS code I get the following:

```
const builder: (input: TInput<{
    base: string;
    variants: {
        size: {
            sm: string;
            md: string;
            lg: string;
        };
    };
}>) => string
```

This seems to be outputting the generic without actually extracting the variants and I can't for the life of me work out why.

If anyone has any guidance on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this just a type *display* issue?  Those are the same type and you are probably just wanting to know how to convince TypeScript to display the type the way you want.  If so then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxa77W) might meet your needs.  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Apologies, I've just removed the second question.

Comment: @jcalz That worked, thanks! Although I'm not sure I understand what the difference is. How come using a Record produces a different displayed type?

Comment: After playing around it seems to be the "& {}" part that's (mostly) changing the displayed type, if you know why this is I'd be very interested to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the type `TInput<{ base: string; variants: { color: { red: string;  blue: string; }; size: { sm: string; lg: string; }; }; }>` is the same type as `{color: string; size: string}`, in much the same way that (5×3)+2 is the same number as 17.  Your problem isn't that the compiler isn't computing the types properly; it's just that it isn't *displaying* the types the way you expect via IntelliSense's Quick info.

TypeScript uses a bunch of heuristic rules to determine how to display a type.  There's a tradeoff between preserving type aliases for display and eliminating them for display, and there's not a "correct" way to do it that would make everyone happy, especially because sometimes two people will use structurally analogous code and want different things.  As mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#50941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50941#issuecomment-1258744439):

> Quick info does not have a contractual obligation to show one particular form or the other, nor to *always* show one form or the other (and indeed it's possible to write types that *can't* be shown in certain forms).

So if you don't like `TInput<...>` being displayed, you can tweak the usage and definition to try to get different behavior, but keep in mind that this behavior is just heuristic.

---

By far the easiest thing to do is not to introduce any type aliases you don't want to see in your display.  Replace `TInput<T>` with its definition.  Replace the use of [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) with its definition also, if you don't want that in your display.  It's not unreasonable for the compiler to assume that you defined `TInput<T>` because you want to see it, and in any case, the compiler is certainly not going to use something that it doesn't even know about.

That gives you this:

```
export const classBuilder = <T extends TConfig>(config: T) => {
  ///...
  return (input: { [P in keyof T["variants"]]: string }) => {
    // return ...
  };
};
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
const builder = classBuilder({
  base: "text-white rounded-sm",
  variants: {
    color: {
      red: "bg-red",
      blue: "bg-blue",
    },
    size: {
      sm: "text-sm",
      lg: "text-lg",
    },
  },
});

/* const builder: (input: {
  color: string;
  size: string;
}) => void */
```

---

If you want to keep the `TInput<T>` definition then you can start tweaking the definition.  Some of this is covered in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) and in [microsoft/TypeScript#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508#), but one easy way to do it is to add a "no-op" [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to the type which doesn't change the actual output type, but encourages the compiler to evaluate the type more completely.  For example:

```
type TInput<T extends TConfig> =
  { [P in keyof T["variants"]]: string } & {};    
// or { [P in keyof T["variants"]]: string } & unknown;
// or { [P in keyof T["variants"]]: string } | never;
```

Here we still aren't using `Record` (because we don't want to see that), but now we are intersecting with the empty object type `{}`.  Any object type intersected with `{}` will reduced to the object type.  The same thing would happen if you intersect with [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) or union with [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  The compiler often prefers to eagerly collapse an intersections/unions like this rather than leave it as as `TInput<{...}> & {}`.  So you get the behavior you're looking for here also:

```
/* const builder: (input: {
  color: string;
  size: string;
}) => void */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#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-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-a4QDFE-kajLwxCjbWvmgrdilEFzxc5CDSO4GzL+MYkFLctK2rZE5Is+smEbZtSlbDd1y7ZBe37Id4BHMcZA3aGppna550XZdRp4knkp3Zr2vxQ9vq6klUTmy8NWvMHzofJ833It8EiAA)

Comment: Very well explained, thanks for your help!