# Enforcing type aliases

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

We've built a type generator for Typescript that outputs types as follows:

```
type Def$9f45cffb = {
    'title': string,
    'subtitle': string,
    'cta': Def$3f75f612,
};

type Def$3f75f612 = {
    'variant': 'primary' | 'secondary',
    'label': string,
    'link': string,
};

type Def$46b580bc = {
    'title': string,
    'subtitle'?: string,
    'cta': Def$3f75f612,
};

declare module 'component' {
    type VerticalBannerV1_0 = Def$9f45cffb;

    export interface VersionedComponentMap {
        'vertical-banner': {
            latest: VerticalBannerV1_0,
            '1.0': VerticalBannerV1_0,
        };
    }
}

declare module 'slot' {
    type HomeBannerV1_0 = Def$46b580bc;
    type HomeBannerV2_0 = Def$9f45cffb;

    export interface VersionedSlotMap {
        'home-banner': {
            latest: HomeBannerV2_0,
            '1.0': HomeBannerV1_0,
            '2.0': HomeBannerV2_0,
        };
    }
}
```

Notice that types are reused between the two mappings to avoid duplication. This works pretty well, except that the aliases are expanded, making debugging a nightmare:

[image: Type expansion]

I know that TypeScript doesn't offer guarantees about preserving type aliases. I'm looking for a workaround for this issue to provide a better developer experience.

My goal is to prevent aliases from getting expanded so `HomeBannerV2_0` would not become `Def$46b580bc`, for example.

This is what I get currently for     `type example = VersionedSlotMap['home-banner'][keyof VersionedSlotMap['home-banner']]; }`:

```
Def$46b580bc | Def$9f45cffb
```

And this is what I want:

```
HomeBannerV1_0 | HomeBannerV2_0
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking... but does the [`ExpandRecursively` type described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/14357) help? https://tsplay.dev/wXOQ9W

Comment: It's exactly the opposite. I've edited the question to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I found that tagging the type using a recursive utility and then removing that tag works:

```
const Complicated = Symbol();

type Complicated<T> = Omit<T & { [Complicated]: Complicated<T> }, typeof Complicated>;
```

Usage:

```
// Hovering over types with `IWantToSeeThis` only displays `IWantToSeeThis`
type IWantToSeeThis = Complicated<IDontWantToSeeThis>;
```

However, this only works with primitives and objects. Arrays and tuples will not work and functions will just get reduced to `{}`.

You could get around this by *keeping* the tag:

```
type Complicated<T> = T & { [Complicated]: Complicated<T> };
```

but then you would have problems when trying to assign values to this type.

[Playground for the simple example above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIgewHbAOoEMUBUEGUIRYAWAlgM5QC8UA3gFBSNQBu6ATiZsAFxQBEYDgFt2IPlAA+-MhADGyACai+AbgZMANugBGEDbzLAOSAOZqmUDSSQBrA0etm6AXzV15SQ1ADCCIWCtZdGAIBSooXBAhbQQNAAoASjdQSB8-AJIgkIUAHiwAPnCAeSESYDyoADJaKABtX39A4NCAXV4GjKzQvMLnABooFIgEADM0xszmhXzk8GgYDGw8AmJycI6m7Jz4ZDQuHHxCUjIZujoFOS02aA8vEMNeBf3lo-I1AHp3i2+mAD0AfjoQA)

[Playground for your code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgBwDYEtgEMoFMAmMAvDAMoCeiARiKgBQCUA3AFAtTnK7xJqY4EAPABUAfMRgB5ROigiYAMhgBvGAG0EKDNjz4AugC4eW-rpHiAvgBoYHLiABmxvjoKjW7TtwAiuBwBIATgcAFgBWYAcHKgllFhgEmAByKFlUXCSjaAAndDAAcyt4xKSIAFcqVKh0zJgcvMLihKTgKCxa3wCAZgcAdjCHADYARgAmIosPOx8-fx7+obHYpuSANyxcrDAoWqTkXMQN8iSYAB9kiFxQMHwjpKLE5NQsKlxUWvqCh5KMMABrD5QXJfFiTNjTGCdfwhQZUMIADgADFRgMtHik0hkskCGt9muVKpikgB+bHAxro1rtIxQ+YDEbjUEefBXZ7ZbiIED4MrpZKgFDgXDbE5xR4QgBquGyqWwqAAQlswFLxcMAPqIiRQ4LhSLRDyPXAAD2QIGlMDyeGyDiwwG4kuyEHQgvwmhNSu2AFksMgVCt0aspTKsKgALRURVS2qix4xhLPPDQIz2oPyiPZFXqvGxkrDAB0iNqyf4qbASvTasRWceYOroLYLOAbI5XJ53FKqBAO19Yq8MAAEkhcArS8qKxJXdoBPhBFCYXCkSj3CsIQPEEO0+LRurx7xJ2YtaEIlEqEuVkaTWaLVLrbaYPbHc7SB2oF6fdHY0kABaDsNpqN+7N41wRN+0HYcy03TMAI-PMCyMVd1xHcsoOzGMklGfNagQ8DlS3StoJgGtEgsNgey4GAjSwLRuBIe8nSVfAn07V81C-H9wyQpI9DUP5cHIRw7ylB8GKYl9vVY7811-Ti9D0VhHgAegUxIAD1iTrIA)