# Unable to view the argument types

Tags: typescript

Assume I have an interface

```
interface Types{
  name?:string,
  age?:number
}
```

When I call the below function why does Intellisense not show the options of interface Types that I can pass?

```
function display(options: Types) {
    console.log(options.name);
}

display({name: "hey"})
```

Is there a way Typescript shows the values that I can pass to the function? Example:

```
function display(options: { name?: string, age?: number}) {
}
```

when I call the above function, it shows me that I can pass an object with name and age to it. Is there a way to achieve the same with using interface as the argument type as shown above?

Comment: Maybe you should tag this with your specific IDE. If I try [on the TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzGV4w) and use the IntelliSense features there, including autocompletion prompting, I get what looks like the information you're saying is missing (see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/Xxed9rW.png) too).  Are you doing something or seeing something different?

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks, seeing the options after re-starting VS Code. Also, is there a way Typescript shows the values that I can pass to the function? Example: function display(options: { name?: string,   age?: number}) {}, when I call this function, it shows me that I can pass an object with name and age to it. Is there a way to achieve the same with using interface as the argument type as shown above?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N557MN)? But that seems to be outside of the scope of the question as asked; if you want to ask that could you [edit] the question post so it explicitly asks that?  Or should we close the question as irreproducible (because it seemed to do with some temporary issue with VS Code)?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer. Exactly I am looking for. Edited the question. Pls post it as the answer. Will accept it.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses various heuristics to determine how to display a given type; often [`interface`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) are displayed as-is by name and not expanded out to properties.  IntelliSense-enabled IDEs should give developers the option to [go to the definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition) of a given symbol, so those who see an `interface` name like `Types` and don't know what it is should be able to find out themselves.

But it is possible to represent a type in a form that TypeScript will tend to evaluate further, as discussed in  [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218), so as to display its properties inline.  For example, a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) type:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never;
```

For types `T` that are plain object types without [call](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) or [construct](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) signatures, `Expand<T>` is essentially an identity function; we take the type parameter `T` and copy it into the type parameter `O`, and then perform an identity mapping over `O`.  So we're not really changing the call signature of `display()` when we write this:

```
function display(options: Expand<Types>) {
    console.log(options.name);
}
```

But now when you write `display` followed by an open parenthesis, you should be prompted with the following IntelliSense hint:

```
display(
// display(options: { name?: string | undefined; age?: number | undefined; }): void
```

Which is what you want.  Of course this isn't magic, and if you hover over the definition of `display` itself, you will get the definition as-written, which is potentially more confusing than the original version:

```
// function display(options: Expand<Types>): void
```

So it's up to you what you want to do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDOyDeAUMiciHALYQD8AXMjmFKAOYA0xpcLN9IArhQBG0QgF9ChMFhQBRAB6Y4IACYAeVAD5kAXjTII8yKrygY0ZAHlk1AsgDaAaWShkAawjoA9jCsBdeksnP2QxZD4IADdoAG5JGH4QBDBgLxBkFWAcTAAbOHQACi9MFLScegUlVQ0ZHE0ASgJOEgQyrxyIADocrxYiktSQHE7yKnq4iQB6SeQEpNL0zOy8wuKF8uRK5XUMbDr6+kivYBVJJdz8gvwxesJpjKyL1YGy+nwySl4GJlZkAB9kIkVBAYKAICoYshuF8BMILACgSCwRDQgdkEcTkA)