# Make all object properties of a type optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a type `T` how can I make all the properties that are `object` optional?

So for a type:

```js
interface MyObject {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   favorites: {
     color: string
   }
}
```

```js
type MyNewObject = ObjectPropertiesOptional<MyObject>;
```

it returns

```js
interface MyNewObject {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   favorites?: {
     color: string
   }
}
```

Comment: Something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP1eYw) might be what you want, but there are bound to be lots of edge cases (e.g., what do you want when the property is a union of an object type and a primitive? what about index signatures? arrays? etc) so it would be helpful if you'd test against your intended use cases and [edit] to include anything that goes wrong with the version shown here.  Or, if it works for you as-is, let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz for my current use case that works for me, I would like you post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation:

```
type ObjectPropertiesOptional<T> = (
    Partial<T> & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? never : K]: T[K] }
) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

The whole thing is wrapped in `(`...`) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never` which is a trick to make the compiler convert a relatively ugly [interesection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like `{foo: string} & {bar: number}` and turn it into a single object type like `{foo: string; bar: number}`.  This is the same technique as `Expand<T>` as described in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218).

The actual implementation is to intersect `Partial<T>` (using [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to make every property [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)) with a [remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) version of `T` that only includes non-`object` properties.  (By remapping a key to `never` we suppress it).

So for `{foo: string, bar: object}`, it would become `{foo?: string, bar?: object} & {foo: string}`, which is equivalent to `{foo: string, bar?: object}` (and converted to it by the `extends infer O` trick).

---

Let's test it out:

```
interface MyObject {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    favorites: {
        color: string
    }
}

type MyNewObject = ObjectPropertiesOptional<MyObject>;
/*
type MyNewObject = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    favorites?: {
        color: string;
    } | undefined;
}
*/
```

Looks good.  The `name` and `age` properties are still required, but the `favorites` property is now optional.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHkBGAraBjUAFATgextqAJbQDO8kxuAdgIYA2APACoB8sAvLABTCz+xMtQkQYt2AMlgBvWAG0A0rCLVYAa2jhcAM1jNYtUnsUBdWNAAeoaNQAmR3CnShYAfljVoAN2jZYALlgFE0DmU1gAX2AASnMrG3tlam1fBDcZeSUVdU0dBBCEcIiAj29fAG4QCBhYAFlwADloAHckVAxOBCcMHHxfYjIKKjomerbnVkrgFWtsbVo0ODHul2k+AToAW2hA0lBsFQBzSoEDQ52PAFdNxAr1-nmvXAPrUkC109O0XHpn3f2jvdIsAogB6ABUYCgS0aLXGHS4Hw2tG2-wO1GOQNo50C1Gut2wJwEj2eRFerneQK+Pz+sD26Mxp2KAB9YJc7NBtCpoLZKlFwaCgA)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this is not *yet* possible in Typescript.

Here's the [Github discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44261).

Comment: And yet [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WP1eYw) does it.  It would be nice if there were some simple way to map properties to optional/required in a single mapped type, but you can get the same effect by combining multiple mapped types.