# Extending single part of discriminated union

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a discriminated union that looks like so:

```js
type Union = {
    // This is important! The value to discriminate over can itself be a union!
    type: "foo" | "bar"
} | {
    type: "baz"
} | {
    type: "quux"
}
```

I would like to extend the type that extends `type: "baz"` with an additional property, for example `value: string` so that the final result is similar to this:

```js
type ExtendedUnion = Extend<{
    "baz": { value: string }
}> /* {
    type: "foo" | "bar"
} | {
    type: "bar"
} | {
    type: "baz"
    value: string
} */
```

The exact signature of `Extend` is not important at all, that is just an example, but if it can extend several types in the union at the same time that would be very useful.

In the case where the value is a union, and the parameter is a value of that union (for example, `Extend<{ "foo": { value: string } }>`) the result should be `{ type: "foo" | "bar"; value: string }`. If the extended type includes both types in the union, e.g. `Extend<{ "foo": { value: string }, "bar": { other: number } }>` the result should be `{ type: "foo" | "bar"; value: string; other: number }`.

I have created a utility type that does this, **except it does not handle the case `type: "foo" | "bar"`**, it will simply omit this entire type from the result. My type looks like so:

```js
type Extend<TTypeOverride extends { [key in Union["type"]]?: unknown }> = {
    [key in Union["type"]]:
        // This Extract is the failing point, if "key" is "foo" for example, it will not extract
        // { type: "foo" | "bar" } but I can not figure out an alternative
        Extract<Union, { type: key }> &
        (TTypeOverride[key] extends undefined ? unknown : TTypeOverride[key])
}[Union["type"]]

// Will not contain { type: "foo" | "bar" }
type ExtendedUnion = Extend<{
    quux: { value: string }
}> /* {
    type: "baz"
} | {
    type: "quux"
    value: string
} */
```

As I have noted, the `Extract` is the reason why, it does not handle the `"foo" | "bar"` case. Any pointers?

Comment: ① I'm interpreting this question as "how can I implement this" and not "what is wrong with my approach"; if that's not correct then please [edit] the question to clarify. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3BrAN) meet your needs? Note that you haven't stated what should happen if you `Extend<{foo: X, bar: Y}>`; does the `"foo" | "bar"` union member get intersected with `X | Y` or `X & Y` or something else?  Since you didn't say, I did the easy thing. If you want something else, what is it?  Anyway if that works I'll write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz Yes that looks close, but unfortunately for my needs it would have to be `X & Y` which does complicate it a bit :/

Comment: Then please [edit] the question to explicitly state this requirement, if you're not inclined to accept an answer that doesn't meet it.

Comment: @jcalz Also I'm very curious why `T extends any` is needed, so if you end up writing an answer it would be nice if you could include some info on that :)

Comment: After you do the [edit], then could you check if [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJVa5W) meets your needs? (Note how it's significantly more complicated.)  If so I'll write an answer (and yes, I'll explain the seemingly useless `T extends any` or `T extends unknown`).  If not, what am I still missing?

Comment: @jcalz Edited! And that latest one seems to work perfectly for my case :) I'm very curious about why the is a seemingly random intermediate function in the type though, is there something magical about `infer I` that is needed here?

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining when I get a chance; it's close to my bedtime now so it might not be until 8 or 9 hours from now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to write a more general utility type, let's call it `ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<T, K, M>`, where `T` is a discriminated union type, `K` is the discriminant property key, and `M` is a mapping from discriminant value to the piece you want to add.  Then your `Extend<M>` would be written as:

```
type Extend<M extends Partial<Record<Union["type"], object>>> =
  ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<Union, "type", M>;
```

---

We want `ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<T, K, M>` to act on each union member of `T` independently and then unite the results back together.  So, for example, `ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<A | B | C, K, M>` should be equivalent to `ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<A, K, M> | ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<B, K, M> | ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<C, K, M>`.  That means `ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<T, K, M>` should be *distributive* over unions in `T`.  The easiest way to do that is to make it a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of the form:

```
type ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<
  T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T,
  M extends Partial<Record<T[K], object>>
> = T extends unknown ? ⋯T⋯ : never;
```

That *looks* like it doesn't do anything, but when `T` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, then `T extends unknown ? ⋯T⋯ : never` will distribute over unions in `T` automatically, so that the operation in `⋯T⋯` acts on union members of `T` and not the whole union at once.

---

If we didn't have to worry about the complication where multiple keys of `M` apply to the same member of `T`, then we could write it like this:

```
type ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<
  T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
  K extends keyof T,
  M extends Partial<Record<T[K], object>>
> = T extends unknown ?
  T & (M[T[K]] extends object ? M[T[K]] : unknown)
  : never;
```

For each member `T` of the union, the output will be `T` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `M[T[K]] extends object ? M[T[K]] : unknown`. `T[K]` is the discriminant property value for `T`, which we look up in `M` to get `M[T[K]]`.  If that's an object type then we want to keep it to get `T &`  that type; otherwise (if it's `undefined` or not present or something) then we want to replace it with `unknown` so that the intersection `T & unknown` is just `T`.

This works for your main example:

```
type ExtendedUnion1 = Extend<{
  "baz": { value: string }
}>;
/* type ExtendedUnion1 = 
  { type: "foo" | "bar"; } | 
  {  type: "quux"; } | 
  ({ type: "baz"; } & { value: string; })
*/
```

but unfortunately it gives you a *union* when multiple keys of `M` correspond to the same member of `T`:

```
type ExtendedUnion2 = Extend<{
  foo: { a: 0 },
  bar: { b: 1 },
  baz: { c: 2 }, quux: { d: 3 }
}>
/* type ExtendedUnion2 = 
     ({ type: "foo" | "bar"; } & ({ a: 0; } | { b: 1; })) | 
     ({ type: "baz"; } & { c: 2; }) | 
     ({ type: "quux"; } & { d: 3; })
*/
```

So we need to make it more complicated.

---

When looking up `T[K]` in `M`, we want to get the *intersection* of the results, not the *union*.  In order to do this we need to play some TypeScript type system *variance* tricks (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) ) as done in the `UnionToIntersection<T>` type described in [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) :

```
type ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<
  T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
  K extends keyof T,
  M extends Partial<Record<T[K], object>>
> = T extends unknown ? (
  { [P in T[K]]: (x: M[P] extends object ? M[P] : unknown) => void }[T[K]]
) extends (x: infer I) => void ? T & I : never : never;
```

Here we use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) walk through each member `P` of `T[K]` and look up `M[P]`.  Then we put the result (either `M[P]` or `unknown` depending on whether it's an object, like before) in a *contravariant* position, and then use [conditional type inference via `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to ask the compiler to infer a single type `I` from each of those types.  Inferring from multiple contravariant-position types results in their intersection (as documented in [the conditional type inference section of the TS2.8 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)).  And then we return `T & I`.

Let's try that:

```
type ExtendedUnion1 = Extend<{
  "baz": { value: string }
}>;
/* type ExtendedUnion1 = 
  { type: "foo" | "bar"; } | 
  {  type: "quux"; } | 
  ({ type: "baz"; } & { value: string; })
*/

type ExtendedUnion2 = Extend<{
  foo: { a: 0 },
  bar: { b: 1 },
  baz: { c: 2 }, quux: { d: 3 }
}>
/* type ExtendedUnion2 = 
     ({ type: "foo" | "bar"; } & { a: 0; } & { b: 1; }) | 
     ({ type: "baz"; } & { c: 2; }) | 
     ({ type: "quux"; } & { d: 3; })
*/
```

So that's exactly what you wanted, I think.

---

Still, it's kind of ugly.  Intersections of object types are equivalent to single object types (e.g., `{a: 0} & {b: 1}` and `{a: 0; b: 1}` are equivalent) so we can use a trick described in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) to just map over the keys of `T & I` with an identity mapping:

```
type ExtendDiscriminatedUnion<
  T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
  K extends keyof T,
  M extends Partial<Record<T[K], object>>
> = T extends unknown ? (
  { [P in T[K]]: (x: M[P] extends object ? M[P] : unknown) => void }[T[K]]
) extends (x: infer I) => void ? {
  [P in keyof (T & I)]: (T & I)[P]
} : never : never;
```

And now we get:

```
type ExtendedUnion1 = Extend<{ "baz": { value: string } }>;
/* type ExtendedUnion1 = 
    { type: "foo" | "bar"; } | 
    { type: "baz"; value: string; } | 
    { type: "quux"; } 
*/

type ExtendedUnion2 = Extend<{
  foo: { a: 0 },
  bar: { b: 1 },
  baz: { c: 2 }, quux: { d: 3 }
}>
/* type ExtendedUnion2 = 
   { type: "foo" | "bar"; a: 0; b: 1; } | 
   { type: "baz"; c: 2; } | 
   { type: "quux"; d: 3; }
*/
```

which is about the best I can imagine doing here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgMoCWYMGEATnvoUUgC4CeMyAogB7sIwACYARKlHgMaVUEJEBVYFQD2wADys2SACpIIg4SKhIAShHiqGIjQGkANEgAKDVTwZc7ETgD4H2mx2BkaipgDWPqoAZnoBOkQAsiFCYS4gnlSYGhZWNhq6ANp2ALpOqgBGAFaW7L6+gb5IALx6KcamAK7A4cCqAO7ASAD8gUT6AGRIABSJhUWlJe1plTXw7CNIcwslSwBcSN29A8AAlGNIB8AQAG6MANwsgVw8SMpqQ60ECRzcEAcAImiqlUAKQAB8kACKhkAYEAL4Q5g-F7-KEwrBwnSIyHfBKowEAR06nX4WLY8JYOlRSAEqVsyUM9NMzgy7CyGBylmstne6kKANRALKSFWtXqTWaFzpxgkUhkYDkIAUfM0qqcgr+AKciV8j2ef1poREECUKnUAEYWkb6Ro8TpoSBMQdcEgbphOmioOwZMAAOZISnYvWBAD0ACpfq8ZaJTaqra0Lq6CVDgaCkY6GAD7oGkUmiCmAcTSdnc5CLtNk39ARjS4ipq73RhPQdvb6-Tn4ecdOHQ1S2DSYyazR8AEzWod2i5pl1IEAHAAMgfiCRhDFnFQOVvhK50GNn8AO453SGL-FnIgOAGZAwiGjoI1G+Ma4+bgOPEz82JWn4C02DIUzOskCmH95yQBdOyRV1NyQC1O1OU48y-Igf0LWsoIbJBDyQUcEOQlC0OrKEz2ArDLyQK8EMCXsniISl+xIaA4EQJAAHVrHCUwCANaNjTlaRZHkV8Pi0H59CZDpzG5fJHBcNwPC8Hx-AuYJJLSSJOBiOILkZY0WTZDkuTyWwdnKapxXvNhJTadSTEOHo+kGTZpnzQpnCQOQ9GKXYDmmc8tncpY7NMMV1k2OZnH2BzjkGJDmiaG5VCoERA3mHySkCJCQpmAK5GiRgkAASXixLktS4Y2imIrLmIW5CqueqGH1alDVVa17QHYigRBAD0VhBFoIudCnXJeihpRbrSIRfsC0NSc9OZdJMmyXIeQ0VUBSFEUwrqeoWmlfjJEExVhJHdQNrfDUhR1ENZqfG1jBEy0J2NKcfkdZ08DdD0vR9OQAyDCkQwfSNBxfc7gATJB80Lf8MzXYDyx+V1fxIkkySg5GEiInga1GzDvqbFskDbAHqJ7PteOfelnvfV7bU6ogZ2+8Clx3C41w3Ldl05p0DyPZdTwxi9r1vYMwzB+aIdVD8YZQmYqzx1NeoR2FCddNmNaQWD4MDJDsa-XG0U+sjvpwvD9YIo2lZN0jtYoqj9ZoqnWCBpiyFYgAxJUMGYanHtEASFSVFU3zEhIJP06STPsJxXHcRglL8XcgmWezNO03RU6SdODJWzk1vyMzRQs9Z6kaa0o6Wo4nKGSrXJRpB3M8oYdhKPyAsi4Lo92iKgtq2uTlKt1yrS9usrz3KDnywqSpaMqUs2Jnm48rzM9iaZJmK04O5mbeSqCwbGruJgT4eOiutedqvmG7r4cAxHBtxO-ldN5-kXxKaMbG28A4WqerIC7GXWptTUPBhTmTWHtSUh16TByEsqOml0PjXS1LdFqV8aZPUhtDScrpTazmJn9dsuZ4QgzYI+cGtNcHWguEQW2f5VaP3VmWeWX5GH9UxDmYhrZ-r+ixuwpuhZ7a5hdvdahODZYM2MO9BILNNaLl5j8Lm31dbKNXPzc2gsTxnlFpRcWwNJYPSHHTOW9DOE9XTCwrMOYtY6y3IIixaNTY5gtk4jhLjRGO07OIp4bt8DwiAA)

Comment: Very clear explanations about the seemingly random `T extends unknown` and intermediate function. I had no idea one could exploit co/contravariance like this :D