# TypeScript: partial sum of discrete number of interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to construct a type `S` which is a (partial) sum of a discrete number of interfaces (in the example below, `A` and `B`) i.e. satisfies `{} | A | B | (A & B)`.

I've attempted the following (with expected values) which does not do what I would expect (most likely because I don't know how to represent an empty interface other than `{}`, which I believe is not really the case).

```
type A = {
    readonly a1: 1
}

type B = {
    readonly b1: 1
    readonly b2: 2
}

type Maybe<T> = T | {}

type S =  Maybe<A> & Maybe<B>
// algebraic type: C = ({} & {}) | (A & {}) | (A & B) | ({} & B)

const value1: S = {} // should type-check (value1 contains neither A nor B)
const value2: S = {a1: 1} // should type-check (value2 contains A)
const value3: S = {b1: 1, b2: 2} // should type-check (value3 contains B)
const value4: S = {a1: 1, b1: 1, b2: 2} // should type-check (value4 contains A and B)
const value5: S = {d: 1} // ideally, should NOT type-check (`d` is an extraneous key)
const value6: S = {a1: 2} // should NOT type-check (value6 does not satisfy A)
```

Can this be achieved?

Note that I have considered using `Partial` but it does not exactly solve my issue as `(Partial<A> & Partial<B>) !== ({} | A | B | (A & B))`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG8yXw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This does seem to work (as far as matching my expected output)! Do you want to post it an answer so I can accept it (and maybe explain how it works, I am not sure to understand)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are, generally speaking, *open* and *extendible* and allow values with extra properties.  They are not *closed*, *sealed*, or *"exact"* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  This openness is often quite useful and allows [`interface` hierarchies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) and [`class` hierarchies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#extends-clauses) to form *type* hierarchies.  It's nice that sub/super-interfaces and sub/super-classes are also sub/super-types and it would be annoying if you couldn't add properties in sub-interfaces or sub-classes without breaking the types.

So, for example, the empty type `{}` doesn't mean "an object with no *allowed* properties"; it means "an object with no *known* properties".  So  `{}` will accept *just about anything*, (even primitive types since they are [autoboxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing)), except for `null` and `undefined`.

(To complicate matters, TypeScript performs [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) on [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), for reasons largely unrelated to type safety.  So `const a: {x: number} = {x: 0, y: 1}` will give you an error, but `const b = {x: 0, y: 1}; const a: {x: number} = b;` will *not* give you an error.  There's also [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) which does similar things for types with all-optional properties.)

So, technically, to implement what you're asking for, the language would need support for exact types.  Until and unless that happens, we have to try to simulate or approximate it.

---

In general, the closest we can get to "an object type without *extra* properties" is "an object type without *a specific set of* properties".  Well, even that is not quite possible.  The closest you can get is more like "an object type where each property in this specific set is either missing or present-but-`undefined`".  This can be done with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that takes all the keys `K` you want to prohibit and makes them [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) properties of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), like

```
type ProhibitKeys<K extends PropertyKey> = { [P in K]?: never }
```

So given

```
type Test = ProhibitKeys<keyof B>;
/* type Test = {
    b1?: undefined;
    b2?: undefined;
} */
```

we have a type that prohibits any defined property at the `b1` or `b2` keys.

---

Back to `Maybe<T>` then.  Instead of `T | {}`, we can say `T | ProhibitKeys<keyof T>`:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | ProhibitKeys<keyof T>;
```

So `Maybe<T>` either has *all* of the (required) properties of `T`, or *none* of the properties of `T`.  So now if we define `S` as

```
type S = Maybe<A> & Maybe<B>;
```

and inspect its structure using a technique described in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) :

```
type Expand<T> = T extends unknown ?
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never;

type ExpandS = Expand<S>;
/* type ExpandS = 
     { readonly a1: 1; readonly b1: 1; readonly b2: 2; } | 
     { readonly a1: 1; b1?: undefined; b2?: undefined; } | 
     { a1?: undefined; readonly b1: 1; readonly b2: 2; } | 
     { a1?: undefined; b1?: undefined; b2?: undefined; } */
```

You can see that `S` has the four valid combinations of properties, and results in this behavior:

```
const value1: S = {} // okay, neither A nor B
const value2: S = { a1: 1 } // okay, A
const value3: S = { b1: 1, b2: 2 } // okay, B
const value4: S = { a1: 1, b1: 1, b2: 2 } // okay, both A and B

const value6: S = { a1: 2 } // error, this is a broken A
const value7: S = { a1: 1, b1: 1 }; // error, okay A but broken B
```

Those all behave the way you want, I think.  You also get the desired error here:

```
const value5: S = { d: 1 } // error
```

but this is because of weak type and excess property detection, and is fragile.  You might be surprised with something like

```
const value5a = { d: 1, x: 2 };
const value5b: S & { x: number } = value5a; // no error
```

which defeats both weak type detection (because `x` is required) and excess property checking (because `value5a` is not an object literal).  But this is really the best we can do; when it comes down to it, TypeScript *does not have exact types*, so approximations like this should hopefully suffice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQwFxwN5wB4ogVwLYBGApgE5wC+cAvGpigAwA0cAnigIwWiSxwHW0scJqw4UA3HHDR4CAEwp0Q3IVIUBBccGAwWAByJwAggNTA4cEkQQATSABsWidh2Dltug3ABCp85es7CEc+Fzh2fytbBycCBTg5N20dfUMABRIwAAsASwIcmABpIhYoAB5CuCIMGCIIGyg4DLADEl1ilgA+UzgAbTS4HIg4QoBdAH5sIgA3NXcUrwAVIl4aZtz8opLygGsSsAAzH06tAHoAKjhPQ2XVtH8LAnZJuBx6ogOhohstC0e5F5vGwfL4-Nxwc6nDypOAAWQQLGIZUW3RoizgAB8mpkNgUOrt9kcUVoFoYAMoCeGIohlIzdABkcIRSO8J200l40wQ9hwRDCFJoqEop1OcDAOwR3BkcC5PKI8QFtAQYU4wtF4slHPgst5AGYUIr0E8OMw4ig5OoRWKJSwpZzubyACwGnrKk2hd1mhKW9U2u3ah1EACsLsFcBsYjVVRImRI-plgYAbKGlWELVHSLH4zqiAB2FPoN3hU0qiRwK2ZsAkACEyVJcAAohg9Ah6sjUXB0dVavVGm8dhAwAB3YbjfzoXqVIZwPYsQ6d0YoRaT0bqKazEhaa6N5utmyKpstttktkXK4ww97w0PALRYJOIvsX5-KJBELG8LPiyvmJ8eJyLRKCxMw-lvN8HxVL9QkBd5Pggb4oLiGDgTghDwWAm9lWQkF4LBUCf3vD1PxvAj33-QDMXuUCsJQIEcLQ0Cnmw1C8L+JDaNg0EKMhOstQTOUgwQHoI2LOhvXcPicyDAgXUZJRsHwYgyEoGgpIQEkgA)