# Typescript type extension

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I try to define a custom interfaces like this :

```js
export interface IAPIRequest<B extends any, P extends any, Q extends any>
{
  body: B;
  params: P;
  query: Q;
}
```

This type is supposed to be extended in a lot of other types for each request mu API is supposed to handle.

For example :

```js
export interface ILoginRequest extends IAPIRequest<{ email: string; password: string; }>, undefined, undefined> {}
```

It works a little but everytime I use this interface, I must provide all the properties even if they are undefined.

Example:

```js
const login = async ({ body }: ILoginRequest) => 
{
  ...
}

const response = await login({ body: { email: 'mail@test.com', password: 'verystrongpassword' }, params: undefined, query: undefined });
```

It doesn't work if I don't provide the undefined properties.

How can I define an abstract type for IAPIRequest that would avoid me from providing undefined values ?

PS : I've tried this as well

```js
export interface IAPIRequest<B extends any, P extends any, Q extends any>
{
  body?: B;
  params?: P;
  query?: Q;
}
```

Even for IAPIRequest<B, P, Q> where none of B, P, or Q allow undefined, I still get that the properties might be undefined

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgOQgNwgJwDwBUB8UC8UA2lgLpQQAewEAdgCZzG0rrkD8UwaArtAFxQAZgEMANnAgBuALAAoeVTAB7NMC7hoMAIIAFGACUIARz5xgGAEIAaKLoJQWqNLYCKDp+jyEA3vKhQAEbK9CCClrJyAL5QAGRQABTwSM4YunhUNAxM3HxQnD4xgj5QYCJoIgC2cIL2UQCUcf6JyayYrhnUdIxcvNAFRVAlpuhhUO4NkYqUKmoakLAAMsoA5gCWtEYj5g46+ltmFiUQlSJrYoLmaBsrUqUicHAA7qr0l9w3UFE4U3IAxspaDsxKsNg4HiBaH9EiVgqEvoIYMt1psTIdGvg8IVfgCgeo0BA4CogdBCCCUQk-HIAnCxsdTudBAAiBliAACNHMADoAZUmbYyo8Xmg3lAmc4QFdAStBc9XkyvtZ5JN5EA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame I still have the same error with your approach. `Argument of type '{ body: { email: string; password: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ILoginRequest'.Property 'params' is missing in type '{ body: { email: string; password: string; }; }' but required in type '{ params: undefined; }`

Comment: You might be looking for [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wj897m) which turns all properties accepting `undefined` optional.  Does that work for you? I could write up an answer if so.  If not, what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @T00rk can you include the code when you get the error? Because it's okay in the playground

Comment: If you want field to be empty you should pass `never`, not `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't automatically treat properties that accept `undefined` to be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) (although the converse, treating optional properties as accepting `undefined`, *is* true, unless you've enabled [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)).  There is a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#12400](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12400) (the title is about optional function parameters, not object properties, but the issue seems to have expanded to include object properties also).  Nothing has been implemented there, although the discussion describes various workarounds.

Let's define our own workaround; a utility type `UndefinedIsOptional<T>` that produces a version of `T` such that any property accepting `undefined` is optional.  It could look like this:

```
type UndefinedIsOptional<T extends object> = (Partial<T> &
    { [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K] }
) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
```

That's a combination of [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) which turns all properties optional, and a [key remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) that suppresses all `undefined`-accepting properties.  The [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of those is essentially what you want (an intersection of an optional prop and a required prop is a required prop) but I use a technique described at [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) to display the type in a more palatable manner.

Then we can define your type as

```
type IAPIRequest<B, P, Q> = UndefinedIsOptional<{
    body: B;
    params: P;
    query: Q;
}>
```

and note that this must be a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) and not an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) because the compiler needs to know exactly which properties will appear (and apparently their optional-ness) to be an interface.  This won't matter much with your example code but you should be aware of it.

Let's test it out:

```
type ILR = IAPIRequest<{ email: string; password: string; }, undefined, undefined>
/* type ILR = {
    body: {
        email: string;
        password: string;
    };
    params?: undefined;
    query?: undefined;
} */
```

That looks like what you wanted, so you can define your `ILoginRequest` interface:

```
interface ILoginRequest extends IAPIRequest<
    { email: string; password: string; }, undefined, undefined> {
}
```

Also, let's just look at what happens when the property *includes* `undefined` but is not only `undefined`:

```
type Other = IAPIRequest<{ a: string } | undefined, number | undefined, { b: number }>;
/* type Other = {
    body?: {
        a: string;
    } | undefined;
    params?: number | undefined;
    query: {
        b: number;
    };
} */
```

Here `body` and `params` are optional because `undefined` is possible, but `query` is not because `undefined` is impossible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgggBRgJQgRwK4QM7ADwBCANFAiQIoB8UAvFAKoB2AJhAGYCWjEzM2A8mGAcA9owCGAGzwBvAFBRFUAEYjmIAFxQCAbgVKw4gE7iAtti0I9SqJghHNUcnoC+lOXNCQGLdlx58gsJiUngAKlAQAB7AECzYUCLKAFYQAMbA1HQAFAjGwqFh1ABk+ooyUADaANJQXFAA1hAgImxQEeIJGL6c3MyRMXHMCWE1ALpQAPxQ3ABu9lBa1WNao8tQLnIAlAOx8XWMbAv0U1AVNQeNza0MKwzjG4szEPNGHp7g0DAAMsi0sIgUOgsLhZJFTOIOJItLgjFwAOY6KCGbDYADuIiMzBhwDhjERGxI3VYvR4RJ6-mY7gA9AAqKBeL6-f7yGyqdRaVk2JQQCFQnF4xFlbko9GY7FQWEI6xKFwyxSGEzmSZaYl+Pry2xYBwqqBq0nMVxQWnUjyMqD8YAACwWdHgSFQdlBFXEAoRjwAPnqKX0SIwMKZlAsvfrKSQKsotP7Aws3Ho6QzPhbrbazsL2SBdVzuVBXZLcdLhS4oCGfTxNYqzNhddGg0YS96SZTNXYHJzhWyowG65q5XJiyaPFxYkY2OI0kyRPCuI6QcBdkMEvagU78MKKrzIdD84KkaKMVi3fikS5yU3fY31TxqPJNnIgA)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to extend your generic types for that case, you can set default values instead.

```
export interface IAPIRequest<B , P = undefined, Q = undefined> {
    body: B;
    params?: P;
    query?: Q;
}
```

Then you don't have to provide the default when using it:

`export interface ILoginRequest extends IAPIRequest<{ email: string; password: string; }> {}`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking; it's not about the *type arguments* being optional, but the *properties*; OP wants `IAPIRequest<undefined, string, undefined>` to only require the `params` property.

Comment: Here body is mandatory. I have requests where I don't provide a body.