# How can I create this recursive arbitrary object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this object:

```
export const cypher = {
  Foo: {
    get Bar() {
      return 'Foo_Bar';
    },
    get Baz() {
      return 'Foo_Baz';
    },
  },
  get Qux() {
    return 'Qux';
  },
  Lan: {
    Rok: {
      get Saz() {
        return 'Lan_Rok_Saz';
      },
    },
  },
};
```

You can see the pattern: this is a "tree" where each leaf would return a string of the concatanated names of its entire branch, i.e.

```
console.log(cypher.Lan.Rok.Saz) // Lan_Rok_Saz
```

This manual object is strictly typed, so I get intellisense nicely.
I would like to now create some constructor, that accepts an object of a type such as:

```
interface Entries {
  [key: string]: (string | Entries)[];
}
```

And returns an object with the structure as the above `cypher`, such that TS would be able to intellisense.
The internal implementation isn't necesarrily important, but the usage of `X.Y.Z` is definitely a priority.

So far I've tried a recursive function that defines properties based on values:

```
interface Entries {
  [key: string]: (string | Entries)[];
}

const mockEntries: (string | Entries)[] = ['Gat', 'Bay', {
  Foo: ['Bar', 'Baz', { Cal: ['Car'] }],
}];

function buildCypherFromEntries(entries: (string | Entries)[], parentName: string, cypher: Record<string, any> = {}) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (typeof entry === 'string') {
      Object.defineProperty(cypher, entry, {
        get() { return (parentName ? `${parentName}_${entry}` : entry); },
      });
    } else {
      Object.entries(entry).forEach(([key, furtherEntries]) => {
        cypher[key] = {};
        const furtherParentName = parentName ? `${parentName}_${key}` : key;
        buildCypherFromEntries(furtherEntries, furtherParentName, cypher[key]);
      })    

    }
  })
  return cypher;
}

const c = buildCypherFromEntries(mockEntries, '');
console.log(c.Gat) // Gat
console.log(c.Bay) // Bay
console.log(c.Foo.Bar); // Foo_Bar
console.log(c.Foo.Cal.Car) // Foo_Cal_Car
```

This works, but does not give any intellisense.
It's also not perfect as it does not support top-level leaves that turn into getters.
I also tried doing this in class form but again the typing confounds me.

Comment: Oh... I guess I broke it... Thanks :(

Comment: @jcalz example fixed.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9QKqN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

Comment: This is actually perfect! Do you think you could also support top-level leaves? I.e. that in the first level there would also be getters that would just return one word.

Comment: I need to see a [mre] of the use cases to support before I'd say one way or another (I don't know what you mean exactly).  You might want to [edit] the question to show what you're looking for.  But I'm not very excited about seeing the scope of the question expand in response to a potential solution.  How should I proceed?

Comment: I have edited the question, what I did was reverse the if/else to allow the function to receive an array, so that I can make top level leaves. Thank you for your patience with this!

Comment: Like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WobEPm) perhaps?  If not, what am I missing? If so, I truly hope you will not further modify the scope in response, so that I can write an answer.  Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work, you can't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `mockEntries` as having type `(string | Entries)[]`, since that completely throws away any more specific information the compiler might infer from the initializer. Instead you should use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get the most specific information about the value as possible, especially the `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
const mockEntries = ['Gat', 'Bay', {
  Foo: ['Bar', 'Baz', { Cal: ['Car'] }],
}] as const;

/* const mockEntries: readonly ["Gat", "Bay", {
    readonly Foo: readonly ["Bar", "Baz", {
        readonly Cal: readonly ["Car"];
    }];
}] */
```

Now we can proceed.  Note that the arrays are [`readonly` tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types); we don't care much about the ordering or the `readonly`-ness (although it's probably for the best that you don't alter that information), but that does mean things will be easiest if we allow `readonly` arrays in our types.  To that end, let's redefine `Entries` as:

```
interface Entries {
  [key: string]: readonly (string | Entries)[];
}
```

---

One approach looks like this:

```
declare function buildCypherFromEntries<T extends readonly (string | Entries)[], U = {}>(
  entries: T, parentName: string, cypher?: U
): U & BuildCypherFromEntryElements<T>;

type BuildCypherFromEntryElements<T> =
  T extends readonly any[] ?
  BuildCypherFromEntries<UnionToIntersection<StrToObj<T[number]>>> :
  string

type StrToObj<T> = 
  T extends string ? { [P in T]: undefined } : T;

type UnionToIntersection<T> =
  (T extends infer U ? ((x: U) => void) : never) extends 
  ((x: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type BuildCypherFromEntries<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: BuildCypherFromEntryElements<T[K]>
} extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

We need `buildCypherFromEntries()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the `entries` argument, plus I guess the type `U` of the `cypher` argument which we'll default to the empty object type `{}`.  The return type of the function is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the `cypher` type `U` with the type `BuildCypherFromEntryElements<T>`.  The `U` part just keeps any other properties that might be in `U`, while the main work happens inside `BuildCypherFromEntryElements`.

So `BuildCypherFromEntryElements<T>` takes a `T` which is expected to be an array but might also be "empty" if we've recursed down into a single string instead of an object.  If it's not an array we just output `string` as the value type. If it *is* an array, then we first apply `StrToObj<>` to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its elements, so that strings are turned into something with the right key and a value we don't care about (e.g., we turn `'Bar' | 'Baz' | { Cal: ['Car'] }` into `{Bar: undefined} | {Baz: undefined} | {Cal: ['Car']}`).  This works via [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  Then we apply `UnionToIntersection<>` to that (see [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) for implementation information), to turn the union into an intersection (e.g., `{Bar: undefined} & {Baz: undefined} & {Cal: ['Car']}`.  And finally we apply `BuildCypherFromEntries<T>` to that.

And `BuildCypherFromEntries<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over its input that just applies `BuildCypherFromEntryElements<>` to each property.  Well I also use a trick to turn the resulting nested intersection type into something pretty (see [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) for implementation info).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const c = buildCypherFromEntries(mockEntries, '');
/* const c: {
    Foo: {
        Cal: {
            Car: string;
        };
        Bar: string;
        Baz: string;
    };
    Gat: string;
    Bay: string;
} */
```

That looks like what you wanted!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCeAHAFgUwE4wLwwN4CgYYAxEEALj0KJgHNVYAhAQ3QAoBKKmm9BgV3RgYAclIgA+i3QiA3NSIBfADQK6DGCwBenbjxh8og4WLJTmWuWpXUbRerACK-AB66CPQ8dHOXVpapEADLMYJQeNABKIADW4Wr2GgDKFu4JvAJCoiFgEtExEimW8vowdjTlNory+ACWYFAYAGbMwKgwAKIN6LWoEHoA2jGo8JTQPWC0ALqUfMwAJuAANvAwbOP1tDAAPp3dvRAcA1Pyivj4UEjtjPy1S-MAwkho6MToIAC2XVA9fQA8ABUAHzYPQAWjmizAKxgAwA0jB6jBhvAQE0YACZppbvcnigMG9Pt90PAOktUB9UA0IID4VMgfhFDBUC5GmB5v16k0MDAAPIwAD8eFhCKRKLRfKxvLpZRglDAqAAbhgapdENccY9ngT3l9uqTyZTqYCQVhqADmayqRyDKgFstVqF4MdBdQbnctfjXrriQc-gBVMC1cAAkAASQaGAgqGAUGDYD+SR+od5ACMAFa0sD8D6pjD0oEg8jUDaTc5q9qB+OhiONdDR2Pxk3YahsC0stk2rk8-2CtZsFyUf1cLAgxUgWrzLjypUYLgd60QVsDyjdzBhkdjidTvthuUwBXK9Cqq4wJPoFMZ5tmojtq3s-qlrZC3CwgAKiOEmMo-HZqCa9SoPMsqUACNRNL+jbgDAqaaniLyEnqPx+nenb9JCDprE+Ox7MhfRHFMygwL2OC4IoQJsNQVJ4RAoFEYgrDUQAcswlJjMhkxEQgXoCkO+AcEOMAAGTYh68E6kS+pkhS1E0sC4GQXG0GwWJ2repJNGUUQ1G-LRtr2tCqzrBxWy7L6+HHIEMAMXwDQsWxMBPlZ3EvJQkQxiA6DzH8TkwE6pp4GcXARDpBwAHRNJ5HStMgbA6aso56EQtTomwFYSvF2BYDgIhPiIwXpAA9IVMBQMgtScv0yCsMBUAgDA8yoLBWwQPVYYiB8MDpvw0C2ogSytJsiKwAA7rUZXWe86roJcjkMFZPDFQeICwMA5KsDAI3IKsqL8CIwGzsIiyleVEBERA9RtCdfTtIxjkmf0W21MAyANfVYArXA1WTKgRUAFRpumMZQGFjUAQqb5TRglxsC5GBEfFRERKUDjuLaRhZGwNnMax7RCgABgAJLg2N2bjigSMT8WKPj+7xRwshlAtFQM39hXpHD6ADPFUygqTUD2XjMBEyTjFk5SFNU-qNN0-qJQVMySzRklNCA8DYWhX0cX6hwEVRTFbBsEMIxERBM0vOZEBTJuKs8JzxvwLzpHVOkRCgJAsBm2VGBvmLAu43zfuC32Iv84Lku4CiMuUCi8ulCpuJqYhltsF7Fv7H0puCN76C+7Z-uUlxakO9bccs+cPBnEoHDUF4WSc6c5zu71HwgMAMSW6CAwiAA4swUAiERIgsPAg96OIlDd9IY-DxYY+vg8zBLJPIiLzIvOKIRjK88w-TN1ANSFX9cDgC3bcdxnekYYZsIAER91At9EbfI9Pyr18whP+lQjCAwv6wb9-5aDfsjfQH9ViL2Xt-TCf8163xONYBBm8YBsybqfVaoIE6egQj6S+bBW7t0tkPfK8gj4nw9nAeIPAv6gJ4JAqhpR9Br3YhMWgZdK7sJoNIFhmxOFEG0DwyYZcXY8AfoIthagR7iNOCg9mzcQDkjCksEAtBYZhXEGFaQDMYBLXEOYdA+B5GKOUao4AHAgA)

Answer (score 1):

[jcalz already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76807262/6567275) all the why's way better than I can.

I just want to add a slightly different implementation:

```
interface Entries {
  [key: string]: readonly (string | Entries)[];
}

/** {foo: 1} | {bar: 2} -> {foo: 1, bar: 2} */
type Merge<T> = (T extends object ? (x: T) => void : never) extends ((x: infer R) => void) ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;

type CypherFromEntries<
  T extends string | Entries | Entries[string], 
  Prefix extends string = ""
> =
  T extends string ? { readonly [K in T]: `${Prefix}${T}` } :
  T extends Entries ? { -readonly [K in string & keyof T]: CypherFromEntries<T[K], `${Prefix}${K}_`> } :
  T extends Entries[string] ? Merge<CypherFromEntries<T[number], Prefix>> :
  never;


// sadly I have to use excessive Force (any) so that TS doesn't 
// get hung up in its "excessively deep and possibly infinite" typings.
function cypherFromEntries<
  const T extends string | Entries | Entries[string],
  const Prefix extends string = ""
>(value: T, prefix: Prefix = "" as Prefix): CypherFromEntries<T, Prefix> {
  const _ = (acc: any, item: string | Entries) => {
    if (typeof item === "string") {
      acc[item] = `${prefix}${item}`;
    } else {
      for (let key in item) {
        acc[key] = (cypherFromEntries as any)(item[key], `${prefix}${key}_`);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }

  return Array.isArray(value) ?
    (value as Entries[string]).reduce(_, {} as any) :
    _({}, value as string | Entries);
}
```

Example:

```
const c = cypherFromEntries(['Gat', 'Bay', {
  Foo: ['Bar', 'Baz', { Cal: ['Car'] }],
}]);
/*
const c: {
    readonly Gat: "Gat";
    readonly Bay: "Bay";
    Foo: {
        readonly Bar: "Foo_Bar";
        readonly Baz: "Foo_Baz";
        Cal: {
            readonly Car: "Foo_Cal_Car";
        };
    };
}
*/
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLisCBnZBvAKGWQG0BrCATwC5lsxMQBzAXVqgjgBMB7EAG0rIAFPUZNkAHzQYs2AJQkWAbgIBfAgQD0AKh34YPHrQCMaqfgBGcKLQBM5gLQA+A0dMAaZNdvIHyHS0CMEoABxQAWWgmCAAeABVXAF4ReOQIAA9IEC5cHksAKwgEMGQAfhEM2nj5ZCTXADceYC5kWhAIBuhazOzckWEq5FAYaGQAJVr65CaW2oq8UgBpYZBkCkoeGAm2CZIllmRzds7oVW0tZBDw5ABhMIALaAAxKB4AW3QGOQT0rIgcrgxKAJNIvpgcBZwXISMDmCxkhdiMg0r0Af04RIFsgONw+IJlqsUbtMUc2kjiKj-oCZN9IdjHLjeAIhPsiRstsTaPdQk8oK8PtCcAl9giydQKSi-n1cELsLDvvDysgolAYrEeXyBZ9ZML4iQQABXd6WaAI1y0SUdLpQc66HREfQAOR4YGASFoAElkIbsCg4MgAAahDgwYAZQOreicVqcsBPIOhGwAsBOuDvCCBgB0yAAQnBsO64PxBBKAsgEHx6MgQxAwxk6jXk+A0xnlYGACR4JMcFvpiBqAD6kdoACJR6py46UQ84KUAO5wITe5kAclKs66Vx4FaeCDI6RtlHnfJQwG2webqf7yp7KdbKAA1MhR4PR8hnxs2usqJG4DkK3-ZACl9UpKxABA5yuBMwHnHdMWwWhg1DcMPx-Shs0dIJgjCFBNReN4dTpbBfjRGlSTBXVcEo4iFXEFgvAABRQhsyIxRUJBScdEUpaV0SBDjlUWJl8VZFZQC5IMu2YutwzULt4jUSNjiIKU2NlKihOQRkY1EwkJNJAAydDOXiXZ8P5Qi5RFA4vE7PAZPreS8CWIdA1cFTePU2kIXlTFDgqVV1Qs7VrP1I0TTNJiWOcC1VOtM5NC0S5sG4AlvU3FAwB3X0UEyJBsELLdnh4KAkBEf9KFqbAd3jKD4gAZWQXgcBAddkBiDdDWYH1QiJYAwFwUd8pwIqIAJLgIAgPr-1aUIeEK4BLAJEZQAGiB32uEFsCzAgYG6kpgD4CtHgIwUqNiVTwOrKkZToQSaN8qEqLokEGKuqtSkc1DvNJLjRwIZxhAaYtDQgaovFretaG+ht-uQAtkFh+RuVOyzzuIhJotkjJXEIYhrtKQdG2ERAEFoSqvHW95aAony5CmPHVOIc8RGuCBOWpuoki4zFR1qfHkWIMmSGpw4UnsqG5K7amlMnZFzHGv18GZ5FDCgER+AgUovwk6mBdVoWRY2cWRAQNHQs0xHKvkYRqfIKgGKk7sWOcjY3PkeWhY0b3VY4MBDSgNYyfljRVP9wO1gAQSgKAlyzYBsBjuPKGB0GIHmVW0-4MGEY02j-PkLMOC4Q0kGEQcvDwcxrZAKrySFwdhGrrwQZz-0BPEZ7iM99RNBBjXzd5aATEbIetSsqjm9UkrjFIVd8ygVcvAXuAAC9l-wO5i1oEhV1uGxV0ONQq7zGw7F30cTFHY-3pPl9+FKiB3kHYBQmwY031766eC1rNH6YMIUc48R6ji8CAqAJhe4EEJidYeUA7BjwtpPYiwgSCjgAOpzjAS+KO2AuAwBvt-Ksv8ID-x4IA4BaM7A4IgXYaBsCIEAGYkHwMtqg0c8QcBgH5qoH+f8AFAOYbQtGTDoFAA)

One important difference to your code: I use a `prefix` where you use the `parentName`. Basically

```
prefix === parentName ? `${parentName}_` : "";

// that way I can replace 

parentName ? `${parentName}_${key}` : key

// with

prefix + key
```