# Inference of a nested recursive type from a flat configuration

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to properly type the return value of a function that converts a flat configuration of a tree-like structure into the tree-like structure itself, e.g.:

turning this

```
{
  key1: { property: "value1" },
  key2: { property: "value2" },
  key3: { property: "value3", parentKey: "key2"},
  key4: { property: "value4", parentKey: "key3" }
}
```

into

```
{
  key1: { property: "value1", ... },
  key2: {
    property: "value2",
    key3: {
      property: "value3", ...,
      key4: { property: "value4", ... }
    }
  }
}
```

in a way that captures key names and not just allowing nested string indexing (with potentially non-existent keys).

I was trying to start with typing the configuration (first code snippet above) without much luck to make Typescript properly infer they keys union type while restricting "parentKey" to available values, e.g.:

```
type Config<T extends string> = Record<T, Properties & { parentKey?: T }>;
```

does not work because Typescript narrows T to be only union of values specified in parentKey. Not tying parentKey to other keys (e.g. specify it as `string` instead of `T`) make TS infer T as union of all the keys but lets putting nonexistent values as parents.

---

Reason behind trying to do something like this is to embed some default property values/behaviors into each node of the tree without need in specifying them manually repeatedly.

---

Appreciate any pointers as to whether this is possible to express at all, if yes, then how to approach it. Also, maybe there is a better form for representing the config and resulting tree that would allow better inference while still letting some augmentation of each node - would be nice to see any other ideas.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1yvm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yes, it is. Quite concise and elegant solution! Thank you for looking into this, I have quite a few of your answers bookmarked and find them very insightful as to what's possible with TS!

Comment: @jcalz, I notice, however, that your solution seems to rely on narrowed type of Flat. I.e., if `Flat` was not a type but inline object `flat` of same shape, passing simple `typeof flat` as type parameter to `DeepTree` does not work (as keys are inferred as `string` rather then union of exact values, making it infinitely recursive), and `flat` has to be declared `as const`.
This leaves me still puzzled as to how to declare a function that accepts `flat` as input, along with typing the configuration in a way that restricts `parentKey` values to ones present as keys.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do about that and frankly feels out of scope here.  You do have to tell the compiler you care about string literal types.  You either use `as const` or you do something else like a `const` modifier, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wO2RMW).   Do you want me to write that up in my answer?  Or should we just worry about the type transformation?

Comment: Original suggestion is fine! I’d accept it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only going to consider the type-level transformation and not issues about type *inference* or any sort of *implementation*.  My goal here is to write a utility type `toTree<T>` such that given a "flat" data structure like

```
type Flat = {
  key1: { property: "value1" },
  key2: { property: "value2" },
  key3: { property: "value3", parentKey: "key2" },
  key4: { property: "value4", parentKey: "key3" }
};
```

the transformed type `ToTree<Flat>` is the corresponding tree structure:

```
type Tree = ToTree<Flat>;
/* type Tree = {
    key1: { property: "value1"; };
    key2: {
        property: "value2";
        key3: {
            property: "value3";
            key4: { property: "value4"; };
        };
    };
 */
```

This is necessarily going to be a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), which tend to have interesting edge cases.  And if the edge-case behavior of a recursive conditional type isn't desirable, it sometimes requires significant refactoring to account for it.  So be warned.

---

My approach looks like this. First I'm going to write an intermediate utility type `ToTreeInner<T>` that assumes every property in `T` has a `parentKey` property which is either a key or `undefined`.  So instead of `{ key1: { property: "value1"  }}`, it would need `{ key1: { property: "value1", parentKey: undefined }}`.  This just makes it a lot more straightforward to implement, since we can always just grab the `parentKey` property without having to write logic for dealing with missing keys every time.  Then if we have `ToTreeInner`, we can write `ToTree` like this:

```
type ToTree<T extends Record<keyof T, {
  parentKey?: PropertyKey, [k: string]: any
}>> = ToTreeInner<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] & (
  "parentKey" extends keyof T[K] ? unknown : { parentKey: undefined }
) }>;
```

That allows each property of `T` to *optionally* have a `parentKey` property (and I've added a catch-all [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) so as to not run into [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection)).  It then adds an `undefined` value for `parentKey` to any property that doesn't have such a property, before passing it to `ToTreeInner`.

So now let's implement `ToTreeInner`:

```
type ToTreeInner<
  T extends Record<keyof T, { parentKey: PropertyKey | undefined }>,
  P extends PropertyKey | undefined = undefined
> = { [K in keyof T as P extends T[K]["parentKey"] ? K : never]:
    (Omit<T[K], "parentKey"> & ToTreeInner<T, K>) extends
    infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
  };
```

This type function takes two type arguments.  The type `T` is the full flat structure, while `P` is the name of the parent key for the current node in the output tree.  This can be `undefined` if we're at the root of the tree, and it [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `undefined` so you can leave out that type argument to get the full tree.

Then we have a [key-remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) `{ [K in keyof T as P extends T[K]["parentKey"] ? K : never]: ⋯ }` which uses that `as` clause to filter the keys.  The output object will only have a key `K` if `P extends T[K]["parentKey"]`, meaning that it will only have a key `K` if the corresponding property in `T` has a `parentKey` of `P`.

And the value at key `K` is essentially `Omit<T[K], "parentKey"> & ToTreeInner<T, K>`.  We use the [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to strip the `parentKey` property out (since we don't want the output to have `parentKey` properties).  And we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with the recursive call `ToTreeInner<T, K>`, meaning that we will also add a new tree right here, rooted at the current key `K`.

That's basically the whole thing, but if you use that directly and display the output type you'd get an awful mess with nested `Omit`s and intersections and `DeepTreeInner` types.  So I use a trick described at [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) to expand the type to a single property type.  Instead of `PossiblyUglyType`, I write `PossiblyUglyType extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never`, which "copies" `PossiblyUglyType` into a new type parameter `O`, and then walks over the properties of `O` without modifying them.  This is essentially a big no-op more or less, but it affects the display.

---

So let's try it:

```
type Tree = ToTree<Flat>;
/* type Tree = {
    key1: { property: "value1"; };
    key2: {
        property: "value2";
        key3: {
            property: "value3";
            key4: { property: "value4"; };
        };
    };
 */
```

Looks good.  Let's just try something else:

```
type Test = ToTree<{
  a: { b: string, c: number },
  d: { e: boolean, parentKey: "a" },
  f: { g: Date, parentKey: "a" },
  h: { i: any, parentKey: "d" }
}>
/* type Test = {
    a: {
        b: string;
        c: number;
        d: {
            e: boolean;
            h: {
                i: any;
            };
        };
        f: {
            g: Date;
        };
    };
} */
```

Also looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUD28BO1oB562gD1NAHYAmAzrAErQDGiKxGA1tOIgGYIA0sA3sLLEgBDNIVABpFgH4AXLAAKKRDBQRJ4bgG1Gc0qBQBLQgHMAunKGFwwAL4A+O7AC8CZGmgBJQoWgoMPWE1xWCNYZlYOeHMEINNYADJYAAp+WAAiYVEJFjScfCIyMJZ2GPE4qVgAV0JGQkQAd0JYOQDMomzwOWriaDYjaGJYG2AASiG7AG4QMCg4JFR0Lx8-VOw8AhJyKlp6JmLI7laRdvU5RWVfNRZYAB8qkl7+wftOVPk8jcLzlSvwW-uen0fIMXN1HsDgI4XAEgiEmuEStghOR3usCuR4LFNBljmJ1GlyrBgnIfAA3XzmVICJIAeQAtgZQFhYtwcVl8Y5EvN3EtfFhuOI7GM0ZsqXC2L5YDTYBUYcFQgiODTojTYkNmrAyb5UjYpjMYLAAGIAGyEoGcvFS4QAjC1BEofp10qShMbKtBrbkbK8BOEAEx2yAOy5OtIut3QP1en1FcAAZkDwdUofD7rjaW4bTxLDkaX90atLAALImLsnc6noEWM4JcR1c+F00NbHqIAaFnAXNz0BgTWbJsAAPQAKlgbbm7gtfAEvpYtstM8X9rLEArrvdnqmi91Yv9LTFi6DK5T68jaS3S9n8f3l8vR8da4j6Yvt5n4RLC9ft-vIcf7urL5fjur7ATOO42LAw6DiA44INAegWt2mDTrAQh2gARro+hGMY3DUCSlR0uhkreqkxB2tAcjoYgiDGtAliZnWpzpEIBYCGwdrGHIAAiZrQIx7I5ixbGwAAFnaBgWFYAknEJaTEF6th2EOo6wfA8HmtCYpoZ+l6YbAeiGCYgGLvhmqEcRKAmTO5G6V+lGwNRtH0YQ1mXuJdlfjOkmoVYblLqBl6BUuHGebeXGwLxBD+cF4GQYOQA)

Answer (score 1):

This is a start. Not very pretty, and doesn't work recursively:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

type ParentKeys<T> = keyof T extends infer K
  ? K extends keyof T
    ? T[K] extends { parentKey: any; }
      ? K
      : never
    : never
  : never;

type GetChildren<T extends {}> = keyof T extends infer K
  ? K extends keyof T
    ? T[K] extends { readonly parentKey: infer U; }
      ? U extends string ? { [u in U]: { [k in K]: T[K] } } : never
      : never
    : never
  : never;

type Convert<T extends {}> = {
  [K in keyof Omit<T, ParentKeys<T>>]: K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<GetChildren<T>>
    ? T[K] & UnionToIntersection<GetChildren<T>>[K]
    : T[K]
};

const test = {
  key1: { property: "value1" },
  key2: { property: "value2" },
  key3: { property: "value3", parentKey: "key2" },
  key4: { property: "value4", parentKey: "key3" }
} as const;

type Result = Convert<typeof test>;
```

Comment: How would you enforce `as const` inference for an argument of a function? I.e. which signature would function that accepts `test` object have to preserve narrowest type (with all strings as literals)?

Comment: Found that TS 5 now has const generic modifier https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865, however, object needs to be declared inline at function call for it to take effect, it seems. Or I don't get how to properly use it :)