# how to implement `RecursiveReadonly <T>` with a "caveat" that if `T` is primitve return `T` instead of `RecursiveReadonly<T>`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

just like in the question, is there a way to create a recursive `Readonly <T>` utility type which:

- checks whether type `T` is primitive or extends `{}`
- if type `T` extends `{}` recursively apply `RecursiveReadonly <T>` to its properties

pseudo code:

```
type RecursiveReadonly <T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: 
    T === object ? 
      RecursiveReadonly <T[P]> :
      T[P]
};
```

---

PS. normally this should work

```
type RecursiveReadonly <T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: RecursiveReadonly <T[P]>
};
```

however... `type FOO = RecursiveReadonly <{ foo: boolean }>;` creates type: `type FOO = { readonly foo: RecursiveReadonly <boolean>`, and in some obscure cases (which I am unable to provide right now) `tsc` throws error `RecursiveReadonly <boolean> is not assignable to boolean`. I think this applies only to primitive types, hence `boolean` type used in this example is a placeholder for all primitive types.

Comment: "which I am unable to provide right now" hmm, well without that it's hard to proceed, since `RecursiveReadonly<boolean>` will come out even if you fix it with a conditional type.  If you move the conditional to the top level of your utility type [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/wQqLGw) then it should work. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what should we do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `T extends U ? X : Y` (so `extends` and not `===`).  You can make that change and your code will work, but when you inspect `RecursiveReadonly<{ foo: boolean }>` it will still display `{ readonly foo: RecursiveReadonly<boolean> }`.  This really is equivalent to `{ readonly foo: boolean }`, even in your original unconditional version, but I'll take your word that you've run into some situation where the compiler balks at it.

To get the type you want, I'd move the conditional type to the top level of your utility type, like this:

```
type RecursiveReadonly<T> = T extends object ? {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: RecursiveReadonly<T[P]>
} : T
```

That gives the type checker a hint that you want to see `RecursiveReadonly<T>` displayed as an "expanded" type (see [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) ).  Now you'll see the type you expect:

```
type FOO = RecursiveReadonly<{ foo: boolean }>;
// type FOO = { readonly foo: boolean; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcJwIYBMB7AOwBsQAeAFQD4oBeKKqCAD2AmP1SkICMAVgmBQA-FADeAKChRkEAiXJQA2gAUo6YlADWEEIQBmTALoAuWAhQZseImUpV1JmlIC+UC1SlTQkKABiAPJBDJZIaFg4CvbkFBJQhoSEFnzJpArabjQA3FIA9PlQftDBoYwJ8ooOicmp6Zk5UG5SQA)