# Is it possible to produce Output<T>, which _visually_ omits some keys in T?

Tags: typescript

I am typing a query engine of sorts. Here's what things look like so far:

```
type WhereClause = { [key: string]: string | number | boolean };

type $Option = { "$"?: { where: WhereClause } };

type Subquery = { [namespace: string]: NamespaceVal };

type NamespaceVal = $Option & Subquery | $Option;

type Query = { [namespace: string]: NamespaceVal };


type InstantObject = {
  id: string;
  [prop: string]: any;
};

type Responsify<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object
    ? (Responsify<Omit<T[P], "$">> & { id: string; [k: string]: any })[]
    : T[P][];
};

function queryResponse<T extends Query>(q: T): Responsify<T> {
  return 1 as any
}

const resOne = queryResponse({users: {$: {where: {"foo": 1}}, comments: {}}});
```

This works, but the output type is quite verbose:

```
declare const resOne: Responsify<{
    users: {
        $: {
            where: {
                foo: number;
            };
        };
        comments: {};
    };
}>;
```

This can make it hard for end users to read through intellisense.

#### Question:

Is there some way, where I could produce a "cleaner" looking output type?

A clear win, would be if I could omit the $ altogether:

```
declare const resOne: Responsify<{
    users: {
        comments: {};
    };
}>;
```

Comment: You want the type display for `Responsify<T>` to be of the form `Responsify<F<T>>` for some appropriate `F`?  There's only so much control you have over this kind of thing.  The closest I can imagine getting is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlzAlW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes this does! Thanks @jcalz please answer : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want IntelliSense to take a type like `Responsify<T>` and display it as `Responsify<{⋯}>` where the type inside is some version of `T` with any properties named `"$"` starting at the second level down removed.  (I say second level because your original definition of `Responsify<T>` wouldn't remove a top-level property with a key of `"$"`.  Not sure if that matters, but it's a little wrinkle.)

You can't really do this; it would be hard to imagine writing `Responsify<X>` and having the compiler somehow evaluate it to display `Responsify<Y>` for some other type `Y`.  That would mean presumably that sometimes `Responsify<T>` does expand the definition and other times it doesn't. And I don't think this is possible. Or at least I haven't found a way.

The closest thing I can imagine is to define `Responsify<T>` in terms of some other type named, say, `_Responsify<T>`, so that the former will always display the latter.  And so that means I want this:

```
type Responsify<T> = _Responsify<{ [K in keyof T]: DeDollar<T[K]> }>
```

So here `_Responsify<T>` is more or less your original definition, and `DeDollar<T>` is a type that recursively removes the `"$"` key from all levels.  We could write that like this:

```
type DeDollar<T> =
  T extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof T]: DeDollar<T[I]> } : 
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "$">]: DeDollar<T[K]> } :
  T
```

This is very similar to using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) but by writing out `{[K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "$">]: ⋯}` we avoid seeing the word `Omit` in the type display.

That's mostly it.  Of course if you only call `Responsify` on types that have already been `DeDollar`ed, then `_Responsify` doesn't have to worry about `"$"` anymore:

```
type _Responsify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object
    ? (_Responsify<T[P]> & { id: string;[k: string]: any })[]
    : T[P][];
};
```

That shouldn't change anything.  Okay, let's test it out:

---

```
const resOne = queryResponse({ users: { $: { where: { "foo": 1 } }, comments: {} } });
//    ^? const resOne: _Responsify<{ users: { comments: {}; }; }>
```

That's what you wanted. And you can verify that this type expands to the same as your original version, possibly by using something like `ExpandRecursively` as described at [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218):

```
type ResOne = ExpandRecursively<typeof resOne>;
/* type ResOne = {
    users: {
        [x: string]: any;
        comments: {
            [x: string]: any;
            id: string;
        }[];
        id: string;
    }[];
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=63&pln=23&pc=62#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-QG0EHrXFdRiGczWeyoMgMC9zGhYiDtVA7LrnQd3Z7KdTaDHAxhg7SDmG-PqUyy2RyuVcboXi2Q3SwPVQvcmMByAKKM9JoLAvCBol0AGigNisWN9-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-6ASBYFqj52W6nx9AZvZyGYyA2OYVAzl4foBGuMs1ikdI5FQJRKg0dIdGBS5LGQyaur7ephCjWV404ZVRnoqZlLmUhlm6mxNnKw5lhpY8vMnbFYVebQIJJTbUABQxLkWzbpDhcDaz2z5jtO+lKr+7FOXB6FQOrJ87uh9l+WFZoyhAA)

Comment: You rock, thank you jcalz!

Comment: Idiomatic TS question @jcalz: What if I used `ExpandRecursively` _in_ my `queryResponse` function. This looks great actually; I just worry that this may be "against typescript idioms". So in case I am missing something: What if I type it as `QueryResponse = ExpandRecursively<_QueryResponse<{ [K in keyof T]: Remove$<T[K]> }>>`

Comment: It's up to you what to do; there's sometimes a tradeoff between complicated types that display nicely and simple types that display poorly, so in my opinion this comes down to your use cases.  I would worry less about idioms and more about what happens if the more complicated type has undesirable edge case behavior.