# Recurse through TypeScript type and output final “materialized” version

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

Is there a library or CLI tool which can be used to emit TypeScript types “expanded” as far as the compiler can infer. For example, for:

```
type MyString = string;

export type MyObject = {
  str: MyString;
};
```

…is there a way I can get to a declaration file with:

```
export type MyObject = {
  str: string;
}
```

Ultimately I have some [zod](https://zod.dev/) schemas and would like to output a declaration file with “materialized types”.

eg. for the following:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const Foo = z.object({
  bar: z.string(),
});

export type Bar = z.infer<typeof Foo>;
```

The .d.ts file would contain:

```
export type Bar = z.infer<typeof Foo>;
```

Is there a method by which I can “expand” the type to output a version like:

```
export type Bar = {
  bar: string;
};
```

**Edit** - my question was marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type), but I’m specifically looking to output a `.d.ts` file with these expanded types that I can consume in other projects. That question just allows me to hover over the type in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://tsplay.dev/W4JeAN but it's not perfect in the slightest. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: See other question/answer

Comment: @jcalz I’m specifically looking to output these “expanded” types in a .d.ts file, where that other question just appears to allow hovering over the definition in VSCode?

Comment: No, it calculates a new type.  You can either use the new type, or, if the declaration file doesn't expand the way you want, use IntelliSense and copy and paste it manually.  There's not really a lot more you can do here, unless you want to start using the compiler api to programmatically process code, but that would be out scope for the question as asked (since the compiler api is not part of typescript the language and has its own tag)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the pointer - I retagged my question accordingly.

Comment: All right I voted to reopen, but you should make it clear in the question that you want to use the compiler api to get that behavior.  And then hopefully someone who knows about it will help, since I don't have any experience with it.