# Type aliases in type definition file are "translated" into original type in vscode hints

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I created a file named `types.d.ts` in my `src` folder, which is included in the `"include"` key in `tsconfig.json`.

If I create a type alias in the `types.d.ts` file as follows:

```
type money = number;
```

And in a `.ts` file in the project I use it as follows:

```
let total: money = 100.00;
```

When I hover my mouse over "money" VS Code describes it as

```
let total: number
```

Is that correct? Shouldn't I see it as "let total: money"? Is my TypeScript configuration, or my alias types usefulness comprehension, wrong?

Comment: The types `money` and `number` are equivalent and one is an alias of the other. It is the prerogative of TypeScript to choose which one to *display* and when. Neither one is "incorrect". TS uses all kinds of heuristics to determine what to display, and for every person who says "it should display `money`" there'd be another person in the alternate world where it works that way who says "it should display `number`". TS simply doesn't give users clear handles on how types are displayed, so it is what it is. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: (BTW I'd end up saying the same thing as in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78167637/2887218), more or less. I'm not saying this is necessarily a duplicate, but if I do write an answer it'll probably look the same: here are various feature requests that might help, [here's a trick](https://tsplay.dev/wed5gW) that sometimes works, good luck)

Comment: I defined `money` for "semantic" clearness. What are aliases for if the type assigned to a variable is not preserved and gets translated? I could have assigned `number` directly and get rid of `money`. 
Sorry, I'm new to TS

Comment: They're not for anything. You _can_ write `type X = Y`, it's perfectly "legal", just useless. TypeScript is _structurally_, not nominally, typed - if you want to distinguish one kind of number from another you need something like _branded types_.

Comment: "I defined `money` for "semantic" clearness." But TS doesn't know *why* you defined it, and sometimes people define things and prefer the type to be displayed as its definition and not as the alias. Type aliases are for [what it says in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases): to make an alias. You can use the alias as much as you want, but TS is under no obligation to do so. As I said, TS unfortunately doesn't give clear handles to make it do what you want, so you get what you get. Have I missed anything?

Comment: No everything's fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Money` and `number` types are completely equivalent. A [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) doesn't create a new type, it just gives another name to an existing type. That lets *you* use `Money` wherever you want.  But TypeScript isn't obligated to use that alias itself when displaying a type.

And there is no documented surefire way to get IntelliSense to display a type exactly the way you'd like it to.  There are various open feature requests to allow more user-configurable type display, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508), [microsoft/TypeScript#31940](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31940), and [microsoft/TypeScript#45954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45954), but I don't see any indication that this is being worked on.

There are various tricks to try to influence this behavior. One possibility is

```
type Money = number & {}
```

which turns `Money` into a pseudo-[branded primitive type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `number` with the empty type `{}`.  This doesn't change the values that are assignable to it (`{}` matches everything except `null` or `undefined`, so `number & {}` is equivalent to `number`) but it does change the representation (`number & {}` *could* be aggressively reduced to `number`, but this is avoided specifically to support branded primitives).  And that's enough for the compiler to display it differently:

```
let total: Money = 100.00;
//  ^? let total: Money
```

That works. For now.  It still isn't *required* that TypeScript use your alias. So for all I know, in the next version of TypeScript, the above type will be displayed as `number & {}`, or maybe even as `number`.  This sort of thing is always going to be an art and not a science, at least until and unless one or more of the GitHub issues listed above are implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwiKBeKCCuBbARhAJygDIoBvAXygHpqpA+DcHZdwWAJAhMkHg-gKG4BsJgowOMACGPAFyxEyNFACMABgUA6JQG5OtKFAB6Afk5A)