# How to insert variable string into link tag using react & typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to using javascript and typescript and have a link that needs to be generated based on some other variables. I'm now just trying to stick that link into

```
<a href="Some Link"> Some Text </a>
```

Both the "Some Text" and "Some Link" values come from variables.

I can successfully get the "Some Text" from a variable

```
<dd><a href="{thisDoesNotWork}">{someText}</a></dd>
```

but I can't get the href to work, as it just takes the string in as a literal. How do I get the href to work with a variable string?

As requested, here's a bit more detail:

Current typescript:

```
return (
   <div>
      ....
      <dd><a href="hardCodedSomething">{someText}</a></dd>
   </div>
)
```

Want:

```
var someDynamicUrl = "somepath.com" + someId

return (
   <div>
      ....
      <dd><a href="someDynamicUrl">{someText}</a></dd>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Please post the code that is and the code that isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your issue is more related to react than typescript.

You're close to make it work:

- `val` should be `var`
- `href` attribute value should be defined with curly brackets also

Here is the corrected code:

```
var someDynamicUrl = "somepath.com" + someId;
var someText = "your text";

return (
   <div>
      ....
      <dd><a href={someDynamicUrl}>{someText}</a></dd>
   </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you typed the value as 'String', then try with 'string'.
For reference: [What is the difference between types String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string)