# ReferenceError: number is not defined in MEAN

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am creating CRUD operation in **MEAN** , i have created  **dataScehema.js** file to defined model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: number },
      country: { type: number }    
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('country', countrySchema);
```

And in my **index.js** to define node js server code

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var app = express();
var appRoutes = require('./routes/appRoute'); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var model = require('./model/dataSchema');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanDb')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',appRoutes);
http.createServer(app).listen(port);

console.log('Backend is running on port:',port);
```

And the third file i will create for route **appRoute.js**,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Country = require('../model/dataSchema');

router.post('/create', (req, res, next) => {
   var newCountry = new Country({
       name: req.body.name,
       capital: req.body.capital
   });
   newCountry.save((err, country) => {
      if (err)
          res.status(500).json({ msg: err });
          res.status(200).json({msg: country});
    })

});
```

So anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your schema type should be Number instead of number

```
var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: Number },
      country: { type: Number }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you it's work.there is a difference between String and string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string
here is difference between Number and number