# Error when concatenating String[] in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to concatenate two Strings in typescript as follows:

```
//This array is declared as a class variable 
testArray: String[] = ['first', second', 'third'];

concatArray(): void {
    var testString = new String("");
    this.testArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        testString = testString.concat(item);
    });
    console.log(testString);
}
```

When run the console.log will output the correct value: 'firstsecondthird'

However i get a compile error which says:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
  Prefer using 'string' when possible.
```

I don't understand this error as both the testArray and the testString both seem to be of type String?

I'm new to typescript. Could somebody point out what is problem here?

Comment: Have you tried to use the lowercase `string` type, i.e. `string[]` instead of `String[]` and to then not use `new String(...)` syntax.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: ideally you should use - var testString = testArray.join();  rather than looping/iterating over string array.