# Different background colors in flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` with objects, and every object has a certain color. I want to pass that color to the style of the items of the `FlatList`.

PlayList class:

```
class Playlist {
  id: number;
  name: String;
  color: String;
  songs: Song[];
  constructor(id: number, name: String, color: String) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.songs = [];
  }
}
```

Playlists Component:

```
class Playlists extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playlists: [
        new Playlist(0, 'Favorite Songs', 'purple'),
        new Playlist(1, 'Rock', 'green'),
        new Playlist(2, 'Pop', 'blue'),
        new Playlist(3, 'Electronic', 'yellow'),
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.playlists}
        renderItem={({item: playlist}) => (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.namePart}>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: playlist.color,   //Here I want to pass the color of the Playlist object to the backgroundColor property, but it does not work
                }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.name}>{playlist.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.count}>{playlist.songs.length}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I get en error on that: `No overload matches this call. Type '{ backgroundColor: String; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'`

I have also tried the following:

```
<View
    style={StyleSheet.create({
        backgroundColor: playlist.color,
    })}
/>
```

But here it shows the following error: `Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle'.`
But when I create a style in `const style = StyleSheet.create({})` and pass for example `backgroundColor: 'blue'`, this works. Is `'blue'` not a String in this case? I don't really get this.

How do I have to change my code that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `String` and `string` in Typescript, `String` is a [Javascript string object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string) whereas `string` is a Typescript string value and what your style type is expecting.

Just change your `Playlist` class to this:

```
class Playlist {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  color: string;
  songs: Song[];
  constructor(id: number, name: string, color: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.songs = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This brings clarity.