# Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have such kind of code:

```
function Child( { name: string } ) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name ? (
        <h3>
          The <code>name</code> in the query string is &quot;{name}
          &quot;
        </h3>
      ) : (
        <h3>There is no name in the query string</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I got:

[image]

I was trying in many ways to pass name `name` literal but TypeScript always complays, any idea how to make happy TypeScript?

The code is taken from: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: Your component expects `name` to be of type `string` but the value you are passing is of type `string | null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function Child(name: { name: String}) { ...
/// ^ this is not typing the props, 
/// it's typing the first parameter called name
```

To properly type the React props, you gotta do this.

```js
function Child({name}: {name: string}) { ...
```

You might also want to use the type `string` instead of wrapper `String` as they are not the same thing. It is recommended to use `string` when possible. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string) out for more info on that.

Also according to the error, the `query.get("name")` function is returning a nullable `string`. You might want to cast it before using it to make sure it's not null.

```
<Child name={query.get("name") as string} />
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also cast to a string like this: `query.get("name")!` by adding an exclamation mark. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator