# TypeScript - Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add extension method to String in typescript. Please help me to solve the below compile error.

I have added the below code in string-extensions.ts file in reactjs project.

```
declare global {  
    interface String {
        toNumber(): number;
    }
}  

String.prototype.toNumber = function() { return parseFloat(this);}

export {};
```

I am getting the error:
*Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.  TS2345*

I tried the below code on typescript compiler. It runs and display the output but it also gives the compiler error:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error mentions that `String` is a wrapper object by TS and that `parseFloat` accepts the first parameter as `string`.

As for workarounds, you can do one of the following;

```
String.prototype.toNumber = function() { return parseFloat(this.toString());}

// or
String.prototype.toNumber = function() { return parseFloat(this as string);}
```

Comment: Not sure why I escalated my edit to ESLint, thanks for pointing that out @AluanHaddad

Comment: Thanks Choz. It's working. I was in assumption that string and String are same. Well explaned on difference between string and String. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string