# React typescript - Gettting type error when trying to assign React's key prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have simple code as follows:

/types.ts

```
export type TodoType = {
  id: String
  task: String
  completed: Boolean
}
```

/components/Todo.tsx

```
import { TodoType } from '../types'

type TodoProps = {
  todoData: TodoType
}

const Todo = ({ todoData: { task } }: TodoProps) => {
  return <div>{task}</div>
}

export default Todo
```

/pages/index.tsx

```
import Todo from '../components/Todo'
import {TodoType} from '../types'

const Index = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery('todos', todosQuery)

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading ...</p>

  return (
    <div>
      {data.todos.map((todo: TodoType) => (
        <Todo key={todo.id} todoData={todo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Index
```

I keep on getting this following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmYoo.png

> (property) Attributes.key?: Key | null | undefined
>
> Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
>
> The expected type comes from property 'key' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TodoProps'

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `String` and `Boolean` should be `string` and `boolean`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between types String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14727044/283366)

Comment: It fixed my problem. Thanks!